# How to find all the local minima/maxima in a range

Tags: mathematical-optimization, peak-detection

I want to find :

- all local maxima in range
- all local minima in range

From those points I can interpolate and combine functions upper and lower boundary. What I am really interested in, is the mean function of those boundaries.

[image]

Data model for this plot:

```
GetRLine3[MMStdata_, IO_: 1][x_: x] := ListInterpolation[#, InterpolationOrder -> IO,
    Method -> "Spline"][x] & /@ (({{#[[1]]}, #[[2]]}) & /@ # & /@ MMStdata);
data = Transpose[{# + RandomReal[]*0.1 & /@ Range[-10, 30, 0.4], 
    Tanh[#] + (Sech[2 x - 0.5]/1.5 + 1.5) /. x -> # & /@ Range[-4, 4, 0.08]}];
xLimits = {Min@#1, Max@#1} & @@ Transpose[data];
f = D[GetRLine3[{data}, 3][x], x];
```

Edit:
As my effort:

```
minimums = DeleteDuplicates[Round[x /. Last[FindMinimum[f, {x, #}]] & /@ Transpose[data][[1]], 0.0001]]
minimumvalues = (f /. x -> #)[[1]] & /@ minimums;
minimumData := Transpose[{minimums, minimumvalues}];
maximums = DeleteDuplicates[Round[x /. Last[FindMaximum[f, {x, #}]] & /@ Transpose[data][[1]], 0.0001]];
maximumsvalues = (f /. x -> #)[[1]] & /@ maximums;
maximumsData := Transpose[{maximums, maximumsvalues}];

maxf = Max[{GetRLine3[{maximumsData}, 3][x], f}]
minf = Min[{GetRLine3[{minimumData}, 3][x], f}]
mf = Mean[{maxf, minf}]
```

This was what I was trying to make:
[image]

I still get quite few warnings and I'm sure it's not the best solution. I don't like the  `DeleteDuplicates@Round@` part, but it was necessarily to get the interpolation function working.

Comment: There's always a maximum in between two minima. So if you have found all minima (I don't know how to be sure of that, though), you can just look for a maximum in each of the intervals between subsequent minima (and for possibly two more on the left/right of the first/last minimum).

Answer (score 83, accepted):

This can be done using event location within NDSolve. I start off as below (note f is slightly modified from what you have, mostly to rescale it).

```
GetRLine3[MMStdata_, IO_: 1][x_: x] := 
  ListInterpolation[#, InterpolationOrder -> IO, Method -> "Spline"][
     x] & /@ (({{#[[1]]}, #[[2]]}) & /@ # & /@ MMStdata);
data = Transpose[{# + RandomReal[]*0.1 & /@ Range[-10, 30, 0.4], 
    Tanh[#] + (Sech[2 x - 0.5]/1.5 + 1.5) /. x -> # & /@ 
     Range[-4, 4, 0.08]}];

xLimits = {Min@#1, Max@#1} & @@ Transpose[data];
f = First[100*D[GetRLine3[{data}, 3][x], x]];
```

We'll recapture f using NDSolve, and locate the points where the derivative vanishes in the process.

```
vals = Reap[
    soln = y[x] /. 
      First[NDSolve[{y'[x] == Evaluate[D[f, x]], 
         y[-9.9] == (f /. x -> -9.9)}, y[x], {x, -9.9, 30}, 
        Method -> {"EventLocator", "Event" -> y'[x], 
          "EventAction" :> Sow[{x, y[x]}]}]]][[2, 1]];
```

Visual check:

```
Plot[f, {x, -9.9, 30}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Red, Point[vals]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Unbeatable simplicity (+1).

Comment: I assume you forgot `{Take[val, {2, -1, 2}],Drop[val, {2, -1, 2}]}` and to differentiate maximum list from minimum list, we just need to compare first element. Not bad at all actually +1. (Not sure however, if this would work, if function has a segment with a constant growth of 0)

Comment: Very very cool!

Answer (score 38):

Sounds like a job for Ted's [`RootSearch`](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4482/) package.

```
Clear[f];
SeedRandom[1];
GetRLine3[MMStdata_, IO_: 1][x_: x] := ListInterpolation[#, InterpolationOrder -> IO,
  Method -> "Spline"][x] & /@ (({{#[[1]]}, #[[2]]}) & /@ # & /@ MMStdata);
data = Transpose[{# + RandomReal[]*0.1 & /@ Range[-10, 30, 0.4], 
  Tanh[#] + (Sech[2 x - 0.5]/1.5 + 1.5) /. x -> # & /@ Range[-4, 4, 0.08]}];
xLimits = {Min@#1, Max@#1} & @@ Transpose[data];
f[x_] = First[D[GetRLine3[{data}, 3][x], x]];
```

Note that I changed the way yo defined `f` slightly.

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];
Needs["Ersek`RootSearch`"]
{{a, b}} = InterpolatingFunctionDomain[Head[f[x]]];
criticalPoints = x /. RootSearch[f'[x] == 0, {x, a, b}];
mins = Select[criticalPoints, f''[#] > 0 &];
maxs = Select[criticalPoints, f''[#] < 0 &];
```

Well, I get an error so I'm not certain how well it worked, but it does look good.

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -9, 30}, Epilog ->{PointSize[Medium],
  Blue, Point[{#, f[#]} & /@ mins],
  Darker[Red], Point[{#, f[#]} & /@ maxs]
}]]
```

[image]

Some comments

- I didn't actually notice the importance of separating the maxima from the minima right away and have edited accordingly
- Of course, it's feasible that $f'(x)=0$ without a max or min occurring at $x$, although I think that the random nature of your function makes the probability of this occurring zero.
- Not sure we can really prove we've got all the extremes.

**Edit in Response to Artes**

If you use `FindMaximum` from two different  starting values you will likely get two slightly different approximations to the same root.  Here's an example with exactly one max.

```
g[x_] = Exp[-(Cos[x] - x)^2];
x1 = x /. Last[FindMaximum[g[x], {x, 0.8}]];
x2 = x /. Last[FindMaximum[g[x], {x, 0.7}]];
x1 - x2
```

8.35447*10^-9

Comment: Evaluating e.g. `FindMaximum[f, {x, #}] & /@ {-5, -4.5}` we got 2 maxima, where the difference between them : `Subtract @@ (#2[[1, 2]] & @@@ %)`is about `1.33227*10^-14`. Does `RootSearch` treat them as two different ones or as the only one local maximum ?

Comment: @Artes  Due to the random nature of the function, I can't reproduce this behavior.  I think it is more likely, though that your `FindMaximum` code is finding two slightly different approximations to the same max.  See my edit for an example.

Comment: Indeed, it seems to be the same maximum. In your example we can set appropriately `WorkingPrecision` etc. to ensure the issue, however for some experimental or interpolated data it could be difficult do decide.

Answer (score 26):

Since you're fitting your data with a cubic spline, and defining $f(x)$ as the derivative of the interpolation function, then if we solve for $f'(x)=0$ for the critical points, the resulting function is a piecewise linear function. We can pull the interpolation x-grid data and use it to construct linear functions which are easy to solve for the roots without resorting to the FindMinimum, etc...

```
Clear[f];
SeedRandom[1];
GetRLine3[MMStdata_, IO_: 1][x_: x] := 
ListInterpolation[#, InterpolationOrder -> IO,Method -> "Spline"] & /@ 
(({{#[[1]]}, #[[2]]}) & /@ # & /@MMStdata);
data = Transpose[{# + RandomReal[]*0.1 & /@ Range[-10, 30, 0.4], Tanh[#] +
(Sech[2 x - 0.5]/1.5 + 1.5) /. x -> # & /@Range[-4, 4, 0.08]}];
xLimits = {Min@#1, Max@#1} & @@ Transpose[data];
f = First[GetRLine3[{data}, 3][x]]

Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];
grid = First@InterpolatingFunctionCoordinates[f];

Show[{Plot[f''[x], {x, -9, 30}, PlotRange -> All],ListPlot[Thread[{grid,  
f''[grid]}], PlotStyle -> Red], 
Graphics[Map[{Dashed, Line[#]} &,Partition[Thread
[{grid, f''[grid]}], 2, 1]]]}]
```

[image]

The dashed curve is the reconstruction from the interpolation grid points shown in red. Next, $\it{eqn}$ defines the linear parameterizations where we have an intersection with the $x-$axis if $0<t<1$ when $y=0$. Since the interpolation function is a polynomial, the minima and maxima alternate and can be pulled from the zeros list in order.

NB: The dashed curve is not exactly $f''(x)$ here, as the red interpolation sample points don't lie exactly on the critical points in the first figure. According to the documentation, taking the derivative of an InterpolatingFunction returns a new InterpolatingFunction, however, it seems the grid values are the same for both. I guess you can always find $f'''(x)=0$ to get those.

```
pts = Thread[{grid, f''[grid]}];
eqn = Map[#[[1]] (1 - t) + #[[2]] (t) &, Partition[pts, 2, 1]];
zeros = Select[
Flatten[Table[{x, t} /. Solve[eqn[[j]] == {x, 0}, {x, t}], {j, 
   Length[eqn]}], 1], 0 <= #[[2]] <= 1 &][[All, 1]];
zerosM = zeros[[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]];
zerosN = zeros[[2 ;; -1 ;; 2]];

Plot[f'[x], {x, -9, 30}, 
Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Red, Point[{#, f'[#]} & /@ zerosM], 
Blue, Point[{#, f'[#]} & /@ zerosN]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: What a great answer. At first, it did not work with my real data and I assumed your code was improperly written - it was not the case. The bug was that I attached `[x]` at the end of a interpolation function and it messed up further computations. I can only imagine how much time you saved me, it's pity that I can +1 only once.

Answer (score 22):

I just come to sell my new [`MeshFunctions` powered "golden hammer"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46532/17) :)

```
GetRLine3[MMStdata_, IO_: 1][x_: x] := 
        ListInterpolation[#, InterpolationOrder -> IO, Method -> "Spline"][
                    x] & /@ (({{#[[1]]}, #[[2]]}) & /@ # & /@ MMStdata);
data = Transpose[{# + RandomReal[]*0.1 & /@ Range[-10, 30, 0.4], 
                Tanh[#] + (Sech[2 x - 0.5]/1.5 + 1.5) /. x -> # & /@ 
                    Range[-4, 4, 0.08]}];
xLimits = {Min@#1, Max@#1} & @@ Transpose[data];

f = Function[x, Evaluate[D[GetRLine3[{data}, 3][x], x][[1]]]];

funcline = Plot[f[x], {x, ##}, PlotStyle -> GrayLevel[.8]] & @@ xLimits;

maximapts = Plot[f[x], {x, ##},
                    PlotStyle -> None,
                    PlotRange -> All,
                    MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y}, f'[x]],
                    Mesh -> {{0}},
                    MeshStyle -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[4], Red],
                    RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, f''[x] < 0]
                    ] & @@ xLimits;

minimapts = Plot[f[x], {x, ##},
                    PlotStyle -> None,
                    PlotRange -> All,
                    MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y}, f'[x]],
                    Mesh -> {{0}},
                    MeshStyle -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[4], Blue],
                    RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, f''[x] > 0]
                    ] & @@ xLimits;

Show[{funcline, maximapts, minimapts}]
```

[image: styled minima and maxima on line]

## Update

To extract the found extreme points, we can do it like this:

```
Cases[maximapts,
      GraphicsComplex[ pts_, body__ ]:>(
                    pts[[#]]& /@
                         Cases[{body}, Point[idxes_]:>idxes, ∞]
                                       ),
      ∞]
```

> ```
> {{{{1.43947,0.041135},{4.75921,0.130593},<<30>>,{21.4528,-0.000886152}}}}
> ```

Comment: your method works very well for me. Can you please tell me how to obtain a list of the coordinates of the maxima and minima?

Comment: @Pincopallino Thanks! To extract the coordinates, you might want to check the `InputForm` of the graphics for clues. (e.g. `Cases[maximapts,GraphicsComplex[pts_,body__]:>Column[Short/@{pts,Cases[{body},Point[idxes_]:>idxes,∞]},Frame->All],∞][[1]]` -- you might want to re-enter the `Point` because of SE's formatting on linebreaks in comment. )

Comment: @Pincopallino Please see my update in the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt response!

Comment: @Pincopallino No problem! But I should add a warning that this method will work only where the points are differentiable.

Answer (score 10):

Just for the record, if you are willing to (re)sample your function to have `{x, y}` pairs instead of a regular function or `InterpolatingFunction`, there are multiple methods available (see for example [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23828/89) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54757/how-to-find-local-minima-of-data-using-peakdetect)):

Original function:

```
getRLine3[MMStdata_, IO_: 1][x_: x] := 
  ListInterpolation[#, InterpolationOrder -> IO, Method -> "Spline"][
     x] & /@ (({{#[[1]]}, #[[2]]}) & /@ # & /@ MMStdata);
data = Transpose[{# + RandomReal[]*0.1 & /@ Range[-10, 30, 0.4], 
    Tanh[#] + (Sech[2 x - 0.5]/1.5 + 1.5) /. x -> # & /@ 
     Range[-4, 4, 0.08]}];
f = Head@First@D[getRLine3[{data}, 3][x], x];

(* sample function at regular times *)
times = Range[0, 30, .01];
vals = f[times];
```

Using `FindPeaks`:

```
{maxP, max} = Transpose@FindPeaks[vals];
{minP, min} = Transpose@FindPeaks[-vals];

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 30}, Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[5],
  Green, Point@Transpose@{times[[maxP]], max},
  Red, Point@Transpose@{times[[minP]], -min}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using `MaxDetect` and `MinDetect`:

```
{minD, minD} = {MinDetect@vals, MaxDetect@vals};

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 30}, Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[5],
   Green, Point@Pick[Transpose@{times, vals}, maxD, 1],
   Red, Point@Pick[Transpose@{times, vals}, minD, 1]
   }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`MaxDetect+MinDetect` is at least an order of magnitude faster than `FindPeaks` but of course the latter offers smoothing capabilities and further methods to finetune detection.