# Find all points that have the same minimum?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find all the local minima/maxima in a range](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5575/how-to-find-all-the-local-minima-maxima-in-a-range)

`Sin[x]` have two points ($3\pi/2,7\pi/2$) where the same minimum ($-1$) is achieved at the range from $0$ to 4 $\pi$. I don't know how to get two points at once, if using `Minimize`, only only one point can be got.

```
Minimize[{Sin[x], 0 <= x <= 4 Pi}, x]
```

the output:

> `{-1, {x -> (7 \[Pi])/2}}`

And the last sentence of the information about `Minimize` gives a definitely declaration, which almost cut off this road:

> Even if the same minimum is achieved at several points, only one is
>   returned.

Other similar function like `FindMinimum` seems to be helpless either,so are there any methods to help achieve that goal?

Comment: Have you tried using `Solve`? For example: `Solve[Sin[x] == -1 && 0 <= x <= 4 π, x]`? If you don't know that `-1` is the minimum, use the value from `First@Minimize[...]`

Comment: @R.M Thanks for your comment, which provide a good approach.Would you like to post your answer and then I can accept it.

Comment: I would, but I think this is a duplicate (seen a few like this and I might have answered it) and I'm too sleepy now to search for it. Feel free to write it down as your own answer and add a couple of words of explanation :)

Comment: Have a look at the method by Daniel in the dupe question linked to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Minimize` always looks for global minimum. One way to find all minimums is to use random application of `FindMinimum` which looks for local minimums. I will intentionally use more complicated function:

```
fun[x_] :=Cos[x] + 2 Sin[5 x]
```

The following code produces 100 random points to use as seeds for `FindMinimum`:

```
sol = {#, fun[#]} & /@ Union[Round[x /. (FindMinimum[{fun[x], .5 < x < 8 Pi}, 
{x, #}] & /@ RandomReal[{.5, 8 Pi}, 100])[[All, 2]], .00001]]
```

> {{0.95887, -1.41884}, {2.21512, -2.59426}, {3.44969, -2.95199}, 
>      {4.69236, -2.01001}, {5.96272, -1.04992}, {7.24205, -1.41884}, 
>      {8.49831, -2.59426}, {9.73287, -2.95199}, {10.9755, -2.01001}, 
>      {12.2459, -1.04992}, {13.5252, -1.41884}, {14.7815, -2.59426}, 
>      {16.0161, -2.95199}, {17.2587, -2.01001}, {18.5291, -1.04992}, 
>      {19.8084, -1.41884}, {21.0647, -2.59426}, {22.2992, -2.95199}, 
>      {23.5419, -2.01001}, {24.8123, -1.04992}}

where above are the pairs of minimums and their function values. Separate those minimums that have the same function value:

```
pts = GatherBy[Round[sol, .00001], #[[2]] &];
Framed /@ pts // Column
```

[image]

Now, you can see all minimums were found and same ones are distinct with the same color:

```
Plot[fun[x], {x, 0, 8 Pi}, 
     Epilog -> ({Hue[RandomReal[]], PointSize[.02], Point[#]} & /@ pts)]
```

[image]

The more minimums you have the more seeds you need to use.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use [`RootSearch`](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4482/); using the same example as Vitaliy Kaurov for comparison.

This finds all roots of the derivative (candidate minima):

```
all = RootSearch[fun'[x] == 0 , {x, 0, 8 π}]
```

then we select the true minima:

```
good = Select[all, fun''[#[[1, 2]]] > 0 &]
```

A quick comparison :

```
Length[good] == Length[sol]
(* True *)

Max[Abs[#] & /@ (good[[All, 1, 2]] - sol[[All, 1]])]
(* 0.0000448352 *)
```