# Find all roots of an interpolating function (solution to a differential equation)

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

I'm trying to find all the roots of the solution to a differential equation. 
Using NSolve or Reduce I don't get the roots, so I'm using an iterative method which I found in physicsforums.com. 
This method solves my problem, but you have to choose the increment and thus in some cases it might give headaches. I wonder if there is any more general approach.

Following is a sample code:

```
data = NDSolve[{1.09 x''[t] - 0.05 x'[t] + 1.1759 Sin[x[t]] == 0, 
        x[0] == Pi/3, x'[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 50}]
```

> {{x->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,50.}},<>]}}

First attempt with no success:

```
sol = NSolve[x'[t] == 0 /. data , t]
```

> NSolve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by NSolve, so some solutions 
>   may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>
>
> {{t->InverseFunction[InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,50.}},<>],1,1][0.]}}

Second attempt with no success:

```
sol = Reduce[x'[t] == 0 /. data , t]
```

> Reduce::inex: Reduce was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present in the system. Since many of the methods used by Reduce require exact input, providing Reduce with an exact version of the system may help.  >>
>
> Reduce[{InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,50.}},<>][t]==0},t]

Third attempt, works fine, but manually choosing `dt` could cause problems with some equations:

```
dt = 0.1; 
tmin = 0.; 
tmax = 50.; 

Union[Table[t /. FindRoot[x'[t] == 0 /. data ,{t, tInit, tmin, tmax}], 
   {tInit, tmin + dt,tmax - dt, dt}], SameTest->(Abs[#1 - #2] < 10^-2&)]
```

> {0., 3.26812, 6.58301, 9.95657, 13.4054, 16.9538, 20.6403, 24.533, 28.7857, 34.2571}

Is there any more elegant method to find all roots in a range?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5575/121

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm slightly surprised nobody's already mentioned the [event location capabilities](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveEventLocator.html) of *Mathematica*, as it's the most compact way to find the roots of an interpolating function that came from `NDSolve[]`. I don't have *Mathematica* on this machine I'm writing in, but I'd do something like this:

```
Reap[NDSolve[{1.09 x''[t] - 0.05 x'[t] + 1.1759 Sin[x[t]] == 0, x[0] == Pi/3, x'[0] == 0},
             x, {t, 0, 50}, Method -> {"EventLocator",
                                       "Event" -> x[t], "EventAction" :> Sow[t]}]]
```

which should yield the interpolating function and the list of roots.

At least, that's how its done in version 8. Version 9 has the [`WhenEvent[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WhenEvent.html) function, which can be used like so:

```
Reap[NDSolve[{1.09 x''[t] - 0.05 x'[t] + 1.1759 Sin[x[t]] == 0, x[0] == Pi/3, x'[0] == 0,
              WhenEvent[x[t] == 0, Sow[t]]}, x, {t, 0, 50}]]
```

Comment: I did mention this method in my answer above by referring to Daniel's answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5575/how-to-find-all-the-local-minima-maxima-in-a-range/5591#5591), of which this answer is a variation.

Comment: Jens: Well, since the Brent algorithm used by the event locator can take options, you can still easily leverage the abilities of `FindRoot[]`: `Method -> {"EventLocator", "Event" -> x[t], "EventAction" :> Sow[t], "EventLocationMethod" -> {"Brent", AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, "SolutionApproximation" -> "CubicHermiteInterpolation"}}`. There should be an equivalent way of tweaking such options if you're taking the `WhenEvent[]` route.

Comment: (I'm quite sure a question like this has been asked before on this site, but I suck at searching for dupes.)

Answer (score 30):

Here is a function aptly named `findAllRoots` that is based on idea published a long time ago in the *Mathematica Journal*, I believe. I'll try to find the article again, but in the meantime here is my version of it. I added the option handling, in particular the possibility to show the plot of the function while finding its roots. The idea to extract data from a `Plot` (thereby leveraging its analysis of the curve) and to then use `Split` in this non-standard way is the main thing that I remember from the article.

```
Clear[findAllRoots]
SyntaxInformation[
   findAllRoots] = {"LocalVariables" -> {"Plot", {2, 2}}, 
   "ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, _, OptionsPattern[]}};
SetAttributes[findAllRoots, HoldAll];

Options[findAllRoots] = 
  Join[{"ShowPlot" -> False, PlotRange -> All}, 
   FilterRules[Options[Plot], Except[PlotRange]]];

findAllRoots[fn_, {l_, lmin_, lmax_}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[
  {pl, p, x, localFunction, brackets},
  localFunction = ReleaseHold[Hold[fn] /. HoldPattern[l] :> x];
  If[
   lmin != lmax,
   pl = Plot[localFunction, {x, lmin, lmax}, 
     Evaluate@
      FilterRules[Join[{opts}, Options[findAllRoots]], Options[Plot]]
     ];
   p = Cases[pl, Line[{x__}] :> x, Infinity];
   If[OptionValue["ShowPlot"], 
    Print[Show[pl, PlotLabel -> "Finding roots for this function", 
      ImageSize -> 200, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 8}]]],
   p = {}
   ];
  brackets = Map[
    First,
    Select[
     (* This Split trick pretends that two points on 
     the curve are "equal" if the function
     values have _opposite _ sign. Pairs of such 
     sign-changes form the brackets for the subsequent
     FindRoot *)
     Split[p, Sign[Last[#2]] == -Sign[Last[#1]] &],
     Length[#1] == 2 &
     ],
    {2}
    ];
  x /. Apply[FindRoot[localFunction == 0, {x, ##1}] &, 
     brackets, {1}] /. x -> {}
  ]
```

**Added note:**

You can specify `PlotPoints` as an option to `findRoots`, in order to increase the resolution of the initial search for zero crossings which are then used as brackets for `FindRoot`. This way, if you initially don't find all roots with the default settings, you can improve the completeness of the result at the expense of longer execution time.

**End note**

Here follows the interpolation function from your question, and the application of the above function:

```
data = NDSolve[{1.09 x''[t] - 0.05 x'[t] + 1.1759 Sin[x[t]] == 0, 
    x[0] == Pi/3, x'[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 50}];

f[t_] = (x /. First[data])[t];

findAllRoots[f[t], {t, 0, 50}, "ShowPlot" -> True]
```

[image: plot roots]

> `{1.59975,4.88823,8.22838,11.6339,15.1242,18.7282,22.4934,26.5081,30.9882,37.4065}`

I've used this successfully before, and I've also compared it to Daniel's solution in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5591/245). I prefer the above method because his `NDSolve` approach ended up being less accurate in my applications.

**Edit: IntervalRoots**

One of the standard add-on packages that disappeared during the upgrade from *Mathematica* version 5.2 to 6 was `NumericalMath`. If you had a notebook that started with

```
<<NumericalMath`IntervalRoots`
```

then you could call a function like

```
IntervalNewton[Sin[t], t, Interval[{10, 20}], .1]
```

> `Interval[{12.5661,12.5664},{15.6503,15.7438},{18.8495,18.8506}]`

Now if you want to try replacing the root bracketing in my function `findAllRoots` by this bracketing routine, you have to do get this package manually at [MathSource](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/6779/). I thought I'd mention this for completeness. However, these old bracketing functions apparently can't handle `InterpolatingFunction` properly, so this is purely a historical footnote.

Comment: Very nice, thanks a lot for your effort!

Comment: Do you mind if I include your function in a package? (for finding eigenvalues of 1D boundary value problems)

Comment: @KraZug Go ahead and include it - I'm glad it proved useful.

Comment: Hello, Jens. Thank you for making this! If a function `F` is complex-valued, is there a better way than checking both `Re@F` and `Im@F` with `FindAllRoots`, given that `Abs@F` looks incompatible with your algorithm? I ask this because I want to avoid doing the same calculation twice as `F` might be a heavy calculation.

Comment: @Jens In the End Note code, if you define `g[t_]=f[t]-Pi/3`, then 0 should be a root, but when I run your code it doesn't show 0 as a root.

Comment: This is actually more accurate than the method using sow and reap functions.

Answer (score 12):

Using `RootSearch.m`  (mentioned in the above link given by MrWizard)

http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4482/

download the .m file, put it in my current folder and did:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
Get["RootSearch.m"];

eq = 1.09 x''[t] - 0.05 x'[t] + 1.1759 Sin[x[t]] == 0;
ic = {x[0] == Pi/3, x'[0] == 0};
sol = First@NDSolve[Flatten[{eq, ic}], x[t], {t, 0, 50}];
Ersek`RootSearch`RootSearch[Evaluate[x[t] /. sol] == 0, {t, 0, 50}]

(*  {{t -> 1.59975}, {t -> 4.88823}, {t -> 8.22838}, {t -> 11.6339}, 
    {t -> 15.1242}, {t -> 18.7282}, {t -> 22.4934}, {t -> 26.5081}, 
    {t ->    30.9882}, {t -> 37.4065}}  *)
```

ps. on console I see this warning message

```
$MinPrecision::precset: Cannot set $MinPrecision to -\[Infinity]; value 
must be a non-negative number or Infinity. >>
```

But the package has options. So these things migthbe possible to configure. see the notebook for more information

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I found this as a possible cure for the `MinPrecision` error: [set it to `+Infinty`](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2012/Apr/msg00444.html).

Comment: I am truly overwhelmed by the responses and their quality. Thanks. It has helped me a lot and I hope they will also help more people. Not only because of the answers but studying the submitted codes I'm discovering new possibilities of Mathematica. Thanks.

Comment: @Jens The warning is caused by a silent incompatible change of `$MinPrecision`. See MORE INFORMATION section of the legacy document: https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v6/ref/$MinPrecision.html https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v7/ref/$MinPrecision.html

Answer (score 5):

You can extract values for the roots directly from the the `Plot` by using the `MeshFunctions` option.

```
f = x /. First@NDSolve[
  {1.09 x''[t] - 0.05 x'[t] + 1.1759 Sin[x[t]] == 0, x[0] == Pi/3, x'[0] == 0}, 
  x, {t, 0, 50}
];
```

The default plot options give reasonable approximations to the roots:

```
plot = Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 50}, 
  Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, 
  MeshStyle -> PointSize[Medium], PlotRange -> All
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Sort@Cases[Normal@plot, Point[{x_, y_}] -> x, Infinity]

(*{1.59974, 4.88815, 8.22838, 11.6334, 15.1239, 18.7279, 22.4934, 26.5078, 30.9879, 37.4064}*)
```

You can get better approximations by increasing the `PlotPoints`:

```
plot = Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 50}, 
  Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, 
  MeshStyle -> PointSize[Medium], 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 2000
];
Sort@Cases[Normal@plot, Point[{x_, y_}] -> x, Infinity]

(*{1.59975, 4.88822, 8.22838, 11.6339, 15.1242, 18.7282, 22.4934, 26.5081, 30.9882, 37.4065}*)
```

Comment: and if the accuracy is not sufficient, the found roots can be used as successive initial conditions in `FindRoot`.