# Finding parameters for first positive root of solution to differential equation to be equal to a desired value

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

I have a differential equation with parameters. The objective is to vary the parameters such that the first positive root of the solution is equal to a desired value `obj`.

As the equation is very involved, I decided that I'd use `user1084363`'s question in [Find all roots of an interpolating function (solution to a differential equation)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16439/find-all-roots-of-an-interpolating-function-solution-to-a-differential-equation), which inspired the first part of my solution.

Currently, my solution is to manually manipulate the parameter `k` to obtain the desired solution. For example, if I'd like the first root of the equation to be `1.6`, I would use the following line of code

```
obj=1.6;
Manipulate[Flatten[Reap[NDSolve[
{1.09 x''[t] - k* x'[t] + 1.1759 Sin[x[t]] == 0,  x[0] == Pi/3, x'[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 50}, 
Method -> {"EventLocator", "Event" -> x[t],"EventAction" :> Sow[t]}]]][[2]]-obj, 
{k, 0.01, 0.1}]
```

and manually vary the value of `k` till I obtain a value of zero.

However, this is quite time consuming and I was wondering whether there was a way to automate the process. My first thought was to use `Root`, with `k` as the variable, but this doesn't work as of now due to the presence of the differential equation.

Comment: Would `ParametricNDSolve` help ?

Comment: I don't think it would work directly, but I'm trying to do a parametric sweep using `ParametricNDSolve` as suggested here http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html

Comment: As a clarification, what I mean that it would not work directly is that the `Reap` function behaves differently with `ParametricNDSolve`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do :

```
auxSol = ParametricNDSolve[{1.09 x''[t] - k  x'[t] + 1.1759 Sin[x[t]] == 0, 
                             x[0] == Pi/3, x'[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 50}, {k}]

data = {#, FindRoot[(x[k][#] /. auxSol) == 0, {k, 0.01, 0.1}][[1, 2]]} & /@ Range[1, 2, 0.05]

ListPlot[data, Filling -> Axis, AxesLabel -> {"obj", "k"}]
```

[image]