# Finding all zeroes - mysterious missing roots

Tags: equation-solving

Finding all the roots of a function of one real variable has been discussed extensively in e.g. [Find all roots of an interpolating function (solution to a differential equation)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16439/find-all-roots-of-an-interpolating-function-solution-to-a-differential-equation) (answer no. 2 by Jens provides a function `findAllRoots` that works without modification for some simple functions I tried). I'm dealing with quite a complicated function, however, and I am certain that `findAllRoots` is not finding all the roots. I have also tried the well-known [RootSearch.m](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4482/) package and Stan Wagon's `FindAllCrossings[]` (e.g. [About multi-root search in Mathematica for transcendental equations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5663/about-multi-root-search-in-mathematica-for-transcendental-equations) answer no. 3 by J. M.), but to no avail.

My general question is if anyone else has had a missing roots problem before, and, if so, how you solved it. I've tried playing with the `WorkingPrecision` `AccuracyGoal` `PrecisionGoal` and `MaxIterations` options in the `FindRoot` function but again this made no difference.

To be concrete I should mention the function who's roots I'm after:

[image: equation]

Here $T_N$ and $U_{N-1}$ are the [Chebyshev polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials), $d_B$ is a parameter to be varied in the interval $[0,5]$ and $E$ is the unknown. I am interested in this function because it appears in a published physics article, [this one](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs100510050731), but background in physics is not necessary to solve the problem I'm having, I believe. Unless that the region of interest is $E \in (-\infty,0)$, but with the parameter choice I mention $E \in (-1,0)$. Here is my code:

```
Clear[findAllRoots]
SyntaxInformation[
findAllRoots] = {"LocalVariables" -> {"Plot", {2, 2}}, 
"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, _, OptionsPattern[]}};
SetAttributes[findAllRoots, HoldAll];

Options[findAllRoots] = 
Join[{"ShowPlot" -> False, PlotRange -> All}, 
FilterRules[Options[Plot], Except[PlotRange]]];

findAllRoots[fn_, {l_, lmin_, lmax_}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
Module[{pl, p, x, localFunction, brackets}, 
localFunction = ReleaseHold[Hold[fn] /. l :> x];
If[lmin != lmax, 
pl = Plot[localFunction, {x, lmin, lmax}, 
  Evaluate@
   FilterRules[Join[{opts}, Options[findAllRoots]], 
    Options[Plot]]];
p = Cases[pl, Line[{x__}] :> x, Infinity];
If[OptionValue["ShowPlot"], 
 Print[Show[pl, PlotLabel -> "Finding roots for this function", 
   ImageSize -> Large, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 8}]]], p = {}];
brackets = 
Map[First, 
Select[(*This Split trick pretends that two points on the curve \
are "equal" if the function values have _opposite _ sign.Pairs of \
such sign-changes form the brackets for the subsequent FindRoot*)
Split[p, Sign[Last[#2]] == -Sign[Last[#1]] &], 
Length[#1] == 2 &], {2}];
x /. Apply[FindRoot[localFunction == 0, {x, ##1}] &, 
brackets, {1}] /. x -> {}];

Subscript[k, A][e_] = Sqrt[Subscript[V, 0] + e];
Subscript[k, B][e_] = Sqrt[-e];

Detf[e_, n_] := 
Exp[-n*Subscript[k, B][e]*Subscript[d, 
 B]] (ChebyshevT[n, 
  Cos[Subscript[k, A][e] Subscript[d, A]] Cosh[
     Subscript[k, B][e] Subscript[d, B]] - (
    Subscript[k, A][e]^2 - Subscript[k, B][e]^2)/(
    2 Subscript[k, A][e] Subscript[k, B][e])
     Sin[Subscript[k, A][e] Subscript[d, A]] Sinh[
     Subscript[k, B][e] Subscript[d, B]]] - (Cos[
      Subscript[k, A][e] Subscript[d, A]] Sinh[
      Subscript[k, B][e] Subscript[d, B]] - (
     Subscript[k, A][e]^2 - Subscript[k, B][e]^2)/(
     2 Subscript[k, A][e] Subscript[k, B][e])
      Sin[Subscript[k, A][e] Subscript[d, A]] Cosh[
      Subscript[k, B][e] Subscript[d, B]])*
  ChebyshevU[n - 1, 
   Cos[Subscript[k, A][e] Subscript[d, A]] Cosh[
      Subscript[k, B][e] Subscript[d, B]] - (
     Subscript[k, A][e]^2 - Subscript[k, B][e]^2)/(
     2 Subscript[k, A][e] Subscript[k, B][e])
      Sin[Subscript[k, A][e] Subscript[d, A]] Sinh[
      Subscript[k, B][e] Subscript[d, B]]]);

prec = 10^-2;
start = 0;
end = 5;

Subscript[d, A] = 1;
Subscript[V, 0] = 1;
n = 30;
LIST = Table[{}, {50}];

For[Subscript[d, B] = end, Subscript[d, B] >= start, 
Subscript[d, B] -= prec,
roots = Sort[findAllRoots[Detf[e, n], {e, -1, 0}], Less];
Do[PrependTo[LIST[[i]], {N[Subscript[d, B]], roots[[i]]}], {i, 
Length[roots]}];
]

LIST = DeleteCases[LIST, {}];
ListPlot[LIST, 
AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(d\), \(B\)]\)", "E"}]
```

(sorry about the subscript notation, it looks better in the notebook). This code searches for the roots $E$ for a given $d_B \in [0,5]$ in increments of 0.01 using `findAllRoots`. It's easy to use another algorithm, just replace `findAllRoots[...]` in the `roots = Sort[findAllRoots[Detf[e, n], {e, -1, 0}], Less];` line by your root-searching function of choice. I get the following error message when running this:

> FindRoot::brmp: The root has been bracketed as closely as possible with machine precision but the function value exceeds the absolute tolerance 1.0536712127723497`*^-8.

but I don't know what to do about it. The figure the code produces is this:

[image: Missing zeroes]

You see the gaping blank holes of missing zeroes! (yes - [they are missing](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs100510050731)). Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

---

A solution was provided by Rom38: for each $d_B$, do a set of scans on small $E$ intervals and throw away duplicates in the end. This gave me the sought-after zeroes:

[image: all zeroes]

The bulk of the code is the same, and I replaced the bottleneck by this:

```
For[Subscript[d, B] = end, Subscript[d, B] >= start, 
Subscript[d, B] -= prec,
For[j = -1.1, j < 0, j += prec,
roots = 
Sort[findAllRoots[Detf[e, n], {e, j, j + prec}], Less];
Do[PrependTo[LIST[[i]], {N[Subscript[d, B]], roots[[i]]}], {i, 
Length[roots]}];
 ]
]

LIST = DeleteCases[LIST, {}];
LIST = DeleteDuplicates[LIST];
```

I aborted the calculation before $d_B$ got to zero but it's more than enough to see that it works. Thank you Rom38!

Comment: Did you try to use shifting border limits - it potentially can allow to resolve the lost roots? 
I mean something like series of scans with slightly different star/stop points and further join the results excluding duplicates..

Comment: That did it! I had tried making the intervals shorter but in line with what you suggested I did a series of scans of length 0.01 for each $d_B$. I now find all the zeroes - the gaps are filled up. I will post the graphic above. It takes a long time to produce, but it's accurate. Thank you

Comment: Scanning methods are the typical solution in optics when you have met the physical limit of a resolution..

Answer (score 2):

You were using an older version of the function I posted in the [linked answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16444/245). With the new version, copied from that answer, it's possible to specify the option `PlotPoints` to increase the resolution of the plot grid that's used for bracketing. This in principle allows you really find all roots. The tradeoff is that the speed decreases with increasing `PlotPoints`. Since even the original code in the question runs very long, I only ramped the points up to `500` to show how it improves the plot in principle. **Caution - this takes a few minutes to run:**

```
For[Subscript[d, B] = end, Subscript[d, B] >= start, 
 Subscript[d, B] -= prec, 
 roots = Sort[findAllRoots[Detf[e, n], {e, -1, 0}, PlotPoints -> 500],
    Less];
 Do[PrependTo[LIST[[i]], {N[Subscript[d, B]], roots[[i]]}], {i, 
   Length[roots]}];]

LIST = DeleteCases[LIST, {}];
ListPlot[LIST, 
 AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(d\), \(B\)]\)", "E"}]
```

[image: roots]

As you can see, the number of missing roots is much smaller with this additional option. Now it's up to you to increase it to `1000` if you have the patience.