# Number and location of local minima

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

Take the function

$$f(x) = ax^{2} + bx^{4} - c \cos(x/d),$$

where $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are arbitrary parameters.

For some given choice of the parameters, how do you find the number of local minima of the function and the location of the minima?

Comment: Related: [(5575)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5575), [(92698)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92698)

Comment: Your question may (should?) be put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) or migrated because it seems to be [off-topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), i.e. its about mathematics and not Mathematica. If that's not your intention, please [edit] your question to make it explicitly about Wolfram Mathematica programming. Include a [formatted](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) minimum example of the code you are working on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = 0.01;
b = 0.0001;
c = 10;
d = 3;
sols = NSolve[
    D[a x^2 + b x^4 - c Cos[x/d], x] == 0 && 
    D[a x^2 + b x^4 - c Cos[x/d], {x, 2}] > 0, x, Reals];
{Length[sols], sols}
```

$\{3,\{\{x\to -16.6935\},\{x\to 0.\},\{x\to 16.6935\}\}\}$

The second derivative condition ensures a *minimum*.

```
Plot[a x^2 + b x^4 - c Cos[x/d], {x, -20, 20}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], 
   Point@Transpose[{(x /. sols), {0, 0, 0}}]}]
```

[image]

Notice that your function is symmetric with respect to the interchange $x \leftrightarrow -x$, so you have an odd number of solutions, i.e., one at $x = 0$ and an even number of symmetric solutions.

Comment: Since the OP asked about "minima" the solutions are `sols = NSolve[{f'[x] == 0, f''[x] > 0}, x, Reals]` which gives three minima.

Comment: Ah yes.... I'll edit my solution when I get a chance.  Thanks.

Comment: @BobHanlon, what if the 2nd derivative is also zero vs h.o.t?

Comment: @alancalvitti - I do not know what you mean by "h.o.t." If the second derivative is zero it could be an inflection point rather than a minima or maxima.

Comment: @BobHanlon, higher order terms.