# Labeling solutions of an Eigenvalue equation involving Bessel functions

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, special-functions, physics

I'm solving the Schrödinger equation for a particle in an annular geometry with hard wall boundary conditions and I've reduced it to the following equation:

$$J_m(k\,R_1)\,Y_m(k\,R_2) - J_m(k\,R_2)\,Y_m(k\,R_1) = 0,$$

where $R_1,R_2$ are the outer and inner radii respectively, and $J_m(r)$ and $Y_m(r)$ are the regular and irregular Bessel functions, labelled by integers $m$.

I want to find a way to create a function that is similar to `BesselJZero`, which returns the $n^{th}$ solution ($k_n$) of the above equation labelled by $m$. I tried using `NSolve` but I wasn't really able to construct something that works.

---

Just for future reference. I stumbled upon the following [`BesselZeros` package](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/6777/). Apparently up until v.5.2 of *Mathematica*, they had a package called `BesselZeros` with functions such as `BesselJYJYZeros[m,f,n]` (where `f` = $R_{2}/R_{1}$) which returned the first $n$ zeros of precisely the function I was asking about.

As far as I can tell, this works well for $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ but runs into issues for complex values of the Bessel function index.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've worked with a very similar equation quantization condition. Basically this is a root-finding problem, but since there are many roots and you want exactly the $n^\textrm{th}$, `FindRoot` is not very helpful. The approach which worked for me is to use `NDSolve` along with `Sow` and `Reap`. [This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16439/find-all-roots-of-an-interpolating-function-solution-to-a-differential-equation) spells out the basics.

I'd try something like this:

```
quantcond[m_Integer, k_, R1_, R2_] := BesselJ[m, k R1] BesselY[m, k R2] - BesselJ[m, k R2] BesselY[m, k R1]

quantcondZero[m_?NumericQ, R1_?NumericQ, R2_?NumericQ, n_Integer, opts : OptionsPattern@NDSolve] := Module[
  {r = 0,
   min = 1/(1000 Min[R1, R2]),
   max = n 1000/Min[R1, R2]},

  Reap[
    NDSolve[
     {f'[k] == D[quantcond[m, k, R1, R2], k],
      f[min] == quantcond[m, min, R1, R2],
      WhenEvent[f[k] == 0, Sow[k]; r++],
      WhenEvent[r > n, "StopIntegration"]},
     f,
     {k, min, max},
     opts
    ]
   ][[2, 1]]
]
```

The function `quantcondZero` will return the first *`n`* zeros of the function `quantcond`.

#### Example

```
quantcondZero[1, 20^-3, 30^-3, 9]
```

> ```
> {3160.94, 6293.06, 9431.39, 12571.3, 15711.9, 18852.9, 21994., 25135.2, 28276.5}
> ```

The roots look almost like multiples of π, which is the expected behavior.

#### Notes

1. The main difficulty lies in scaling. Here, assuming that $R_1$ and $R_2$ are roughly the same scale, your zeros appear to scale roughly inversely with the size of $R_1$ and $R_2$, hence the setting for *`min`* and *`max`*, the limits of the integration. Depending on the behavior of the function, these may need to be adjusted to ensure you capture all of the zeros.

Answer (score 8):

I typically solve these problems by harnessing the power of `Plot`. Taking

```
fn[m_, k_, R1_, R2_] := BesselJ[m, k R1] BesselY[m, k R2] - BesselY[m, k R1] BesselJ[m, k R2]
```

we first `Plot` the function as

```
p1 = Plot[fn[1, k, 1, 2], {k, 0, 50}
  , PlotRange -> All
  , MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}
  , MeshStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.02]}
  , Mesh -> {{0.}}]
```

yielding

[image]

We extract the roots and refine them using `FindRoot`:

```
pts = Sort@Cases[Normal@p1, Point[a_] :> First@a, Infinity]
k /. FindRoot[fn[1, k, 1, 2] == 0, {k, #}] & /@ pts
```

[image]

We can wrap this all up into a `Module` with the following code (borrowing [Virgil](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/27697/virgil)'s name from their [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103178/29734)):

```
quantcondZero[m_?NumericQ, R1_?NumericQ, R2_?NumericQ, n_Integer, x_?Positive] := Module[
  {plt, pts}
  , plt = Plot[BesselJ[m, k R1] BesselY[m, k R2] - BesselY[m, k R1] BesselJ[m, k R2]
      , {k, 0, x}, PlotRange -> All
      , MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, Mesh -> {{0.}}]
  ; pts = Sort@Cases[Normal@plt, Point[a_] :> First@a, Infinity]
  ; k /. FindRoot[eqn[1, k, 1, 2] == 0, {k, #}] & /@ pts[[1 ;; Min[n, Length@pts]]]
  ]
```

Because one can't tell *a priori* how far out to plot the function, I have to include it as an argument to the function, and it makes it not completely automated. So, for instance, if we want the first 5 roots with $m=2$, we can start by doing

```
quantcondZero[2, 1, 2, 5, 10]
(* {3.40692, 6.42777, 9.52285} *)
```

It doesn't give us enough, so we try a larger `x`:

```
quantcondZero[2, 1, 2, 5, 20]
(* {3.40692, 6.42777, 9.52285, 12.6404, 15.7673} *)
```

---

**Important note**: this method is not the most robust. If you need a lot of zeroes, it is likely that the zeroes will get so close together that the `Plot` might miss them. You will need to do things like manually increase the number of `PlotPoints` in order to get it to work.

Answer (score 6):

My goal was to give an answer using [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html). In addition, I want to be able to **uniquely identify** the roots by the node number. I believe this is an important part of the original question, because it refers specifically to **"labeling"** the solutions. The method below achieves this unique association of the label `n` with the number of zeros. For a given `n`, it does *not* require finding all roots *up to* `n` and counting them. This is where it differs fundamentally from the other answers.

The main issue is to find the starting points for `FindRoot` reliably without duplicating or skipping roots. For large enough `m`, this can be done very nicely by relying on `BesselJZero`, but this doesn't work for all roots.

Therefore, I decided to modify my answer and not rely on `BesselJZero` at all. The alternative is to use an asymptotic approach based on the WKB approximation. By doing this approximation with a rescaled coordinate $\xi \equiv \log(\rho)$, you get a very accurate formula for the starting points that works for large and small `m`. I compared it to the solution available in the package linked in the question, and found it promising that my function doesn't duplicate roots whereas the library function does so:

```
BesselJYJYZeros[20, .5, 10]

(*
==> {25.4172, 25.4172, 29.9645, 34.0415, 38.1114, 42.5018, \
47.2888, 52.4004, 57.7525, 63.2819}
*)
```

You can see that the first root is duplicated, showing that the search was started with bad initial conditions.

Here is my approach:

```
Clear[annularZero, action, sWKB];

action[m_, k_, ρa_] := 
 Sqrt[k^2 - m^2] - Sqrt[-m^2 + k^2 ρa^2] + 
  m ArcTan[(m (-Sqrt[k^2 - m^2] + Sqrt[-m^2 + k^2 ρa^2]))/(
    m^2 + Sqrt[k^2 - m^2] Sqrt[-m^2 + k^2 ρa^2])]

sWKB[m_, k_?NumericQ, r_] :=
  Re[action[m, k, Max[m/k, r]]];

Options[annularZero] = {"ShowPlot" -> False, 
   WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision};

annularZero[m_, ρa_, n_, OptionsPattern[]] := Module[
   {k, det, start1, start2, refine = False, firstPass, prec, showPlot},
   (* For large m it helps to increase WorkingPrecision if FindRoot \
complains: *)
   prec = OptionValue[WorkingPrecision];
   (* With showPlot True, display the function whose roots we seek: *)
      showPlot = OptionValue["ShowPlot"] =!= False;
   (* Use WKB approximation to find two starting values for exact \
root search. No need for perfection, 
   so suppress warnings: *)
   {start1, start2} = 
    Table[
     Chop[k /.
       Quiet@FindRoot[
         sWKB[m, k, ρa] - Pi (n + δ), {k, 
          m/ρa}]], {δ, {-1/4, 0}}];
   (* Want the n-th exact root of det: *)
   det = SetPrecision[
     BesselJ[m, k ρa] BesselY[m, k] - 
      BesselJ[m, k] BesselY[m, k ρa], prec];
   (* Since det has infinitely many roots, 
   optionally show plot of interval around desired region: *)
   If[showPlot,
    Print[
     Plot[det, {k, Max[0, start1 - 10], start2 + 10}, 
      Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[.02], 
        Point[{{start1, 0}, {start2, 0}}]}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]]];
   (* FindRoot with two starting values to bracket the desired root:*)
      Quiet[
    Check[
     firstPass = Chop[k /. First@FindRoot[det, {k, start1, start2}]], 
     refine = True]];
   (* If previous search issues warnings, 
   try to improve last result using Automatic method: *)
   If [refine, If[showPlot, Print["refining zero"]]; 
    Chop@N[k /. 
       First@FindRoot[det, {k, firstPass}, WorkingPrecision -> prec]],
     firstPass]
   ];
```

For now, I simplified life for myself by requiring that the second argument `ρa` must be **less than 1**. This can always be achieved by rescaling the original problem to appropriate length units. I may drop this restriction once the reliability has been tested some more. Here is the comparison to the test case above:

```
Table[annularZero[20, .5, i], {i, 10}]

(*
==> {25.4172, 29.9645, 34.0415, 38.1114, 42.5018, 47.2888, \
52.4004, 57.7525, 63.2819, 68.9443}
*)
```

Instead of duplicating the first root, I now get a new additional root at the end of the list. The other results are in complete agreement with the old add-on package.

Comment: For some reason, sometimes this function doubles the number of zeros. For example. annularZero[1, 2, 2, 2n+1] = annularZero[1, 2, 2, 2n] where $n\geq1$. But for $\rho_a = 0.1$ and $\rho_b = 2$, it won't do this anymore. I wasn't really able to understand what was causing this behaviour.

Comment: @Aegon, I think I still have a factor wrong somewhere, so the bracketing still isn't quite right - will look at it some more... pretty sure it's fixable.

Comment: @Aegon Looks like the library add-on package also has trouble with duplicate roots. Maybe you can try my new approach and see if it works better now.

Comment: Thanks! This definitely works a lot better and so far seems to avoid duplicating and doesn't miss any roots.