# Help with solving trascendental equations involving Bessel's equations

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

I'm pretty new at using Mathematica, so I sometimes find errors in stuff so simple I can't seem to find where the error is.

I've been trying to solve a trascendental equation that involves a number of Bessel's functions, and I can't seem to find why it doesn't work.

Here it goes.

```
a = 0.889;
b = 2.946;
Er = 2.2;

f[x_, n_] := BesselJ[n, a*x] BesselY[n, b*x] - BesselJ[n, b*x] BesselY[n, a*x];
NSolve[f[x, 0] == 0, x];
```

Has it something to do with it being an infinite number of solutions, or something like that?

Thanks in advance.

PD : I tried giving it an interval as march suggested, but I got an error I don't understand. What does it mean?

> Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact
>   coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact
>   system and numericizing the result. >>

Comment: Yes. You could also use `FindRoot`, but if you specify an interval: `NSolve[f[x, 0] == 0 && x \[Element] Interval[{0, 5}], x]` gives you three solutions.

Comment: Thanks! Tried that and got the three solutions that you said, but it gives me also an error I don't fully understand. I'll edit the question to add that.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Oh, thanks! I didn't know that. I'll do that!

Comment: I can't seem to find the checkmark sign... Where is it? How can I check march's comment?

Comment: `NSolve` gave me only two, not three, solutions in `{0,5}`; you can try also `FindInstance[f[x, 0] == 0 && x \[Element] Interval[{0, 5}], x, 3]`.

Comment: @corey979. Hmmm. `NSolve` gave me three solutions in the interval.  Really, I don't think `NSolve` is the right thing to use here anyway, for exactly these kinds of difficulties. By the way, TheCloak, the error it's spitting out is due to the fact that you have a transcendental equation, and `NSolve` is not in general designed to solve those.  I suggest looking at [this Q&A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103176/labeling-solutions-of-an-eigenvalue-equation-involving-bessel-functions/103183#103183), which I think I will propose as a duplicate.

Comment: @TheCloak The checkmark sign is visible only when actual ansers are posted. There are no checkmark signs for comments.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = 0.889 // Rationalize;
b = 2.946 // Rationalize;
Er = 2.2 // Rationalize;

f[x_, n_] := 
  BesselJ[n, a*x] BesselY[n, b*x] - BesselJ[n, b*x] BesselY[n, a*x];

roots = (x /. Solve[{f[x, 0] == 0, 0 <= x <= 5}, x])[[All, 1, -1]]
```

[image]

```
(*  {1.50177384329388181009156654340, 
     3.04000268689460168628592657359,
     4.57176009090372974335375245063}  *)
```

Plotting `f[x,0]` shows that there are only three roots in the interval so the warning is not important.

```
Plot[f[x, 0], {x, 0, 5},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6],
   Point[{#, 0} & /@ roots]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
a = 0.889;
b = 2.946;
Er = 2.2;

f[x_, n_] := 
  BesselJ[n, a*x] BesselY[n, b*x] - BesselJ[n, b*x] BesselY[n, a*x];
```

With

```
$Version
```

> "10.4.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)"

I obtain only two solutions in the interval $(0,5)$ using `NSolve` - I'm missing the `3.04` solution.

On the other hand, this works well:

```
FindInstance[f[x, 0] == 0 && x \[Element] Interval[{0, 5}], x, 3]
```

> {{x -> {1.50177}}, {x -> {3.04}}, {x -> {4.57176}}}

When I try to find more instances than there are solutions in the interval, I find just the three and receive a warning:

> FindInstance::incs: Warning: FindInstance was unable to prove that the solution set found is complete.

Hence, as a crude way of finding the solutions, one can either keep changing the number of instances to be found until the warning occurs, or just give a number high enough to exceed the number of solutions. E.g., this

```
FindInstance[f[x, 0] == 0 && x \[Element] Interval[{0, 15}], x, 15]
```

finds nine solutions:

> {{x -> {1.50177}}, {x -> {3.04}}, {x -> {4.57176}}, {x -> {6.10143}},
>   {x -> {7.63018}}, {x -> {9.15846}}, {x -> {10.6865}}, {x ->
>   {12.2143}}, {x -> {13.742}}}

[image]

while `NSolve` only 5.