# Solving a Sturm-Liouville problem

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic, eigenvalues

Ello,

I would like to reproduce the analytical solution of the following eigenvalue problem, or at the least  confirm them numerically (especially the eigenvalues):

$$  - \frac{1}{2} y^{\prime \prime} - 6\epsilon \operatorname{sech}^2 \Big( \sqrt{2  \epsilon} ( x-z) \Big) y + \epsilon y =  \lambda y  $$
where $ \epsilon$ is a parameter, $z$ an arbitrary constant and $\lambda$ the sought eigenvalue(s).

I know there are two bound states, going to $0$ as $x \to \pm \infty$, given by the eigenfunctions

$$y_0 (x) = \sqrt{3/4} (2 \epsilon)^{1/4} \operatorname{sech}^2\Big(\sqrt{2 \epsilon}(x-z)  \Big) $$
with eigenvalue $$ \lambda_0 = - 3 \epsilon $$
and
$$y_1(x) = \sqrt{3/2} (2 \epsilon)^{1/4} \frac{\operatorname{sinh} \Big(\sqrt{2 \epsilon}(x-z) \Big)}{\operatorname{cosh}^2\Big(\sqrt{2 \epsilon}(x-z) \Big)} $$
with eigenvalue $$\lambda_1 = 0 $$

I tried to follow the approach presented in the answer to the post [How to solve a Sturm-Liouville problem with Mathematica (or, how to go from the complex to the general *real* solution)?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/152058/how-to-solve-a-sturm-liouville-problem-with-mathematica-or-how-to-go-from-the), starting with

```
   PiecewiseExpand[
   DSolveValue[{-0.5*f''[x] - 6*eps*Sech[Sqrt[2*eps]*(x - z)]^2*f[x] + 
   eps*f[x] - v*f[x] == 0, f[-Infinity] == 0, f[Infinity] == 0}, 
   f[x], x]]
```

I apppreciate how naive and optimistic the boundary condition definition is, but not getting errors I stubbornly proceeded. Nevertheless I get the error

```
Solve::inex: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the system obtained by 
direct rationalization of inexact numbers present in the system. Since many of the methods used by 
Solve require exact input, providing Solve with an exact version of the system may help.

Out= DSolveValue[{eps f[x] - v f[x] - 
6 eps f[x] Sech[Sqrt[2] Sqrt[eps] (x - z)]^2 - 
0.5 (f^′′)[x] == 0, f[-∞] == 0, 
f[∞] == 0}, f[x], x]
```

Do I have to abandon any hope of getting symbolic solutions? Are there any other approaches I could use? I  have Mathematica 11.2.
Any hint would be most appreciated, thanks.

I tried a numerical approach, setting $\epsilon =1, z = 0$, but even then I am not getting the negative eigenvalue at all

```
  {eigN1, funcN1} = 
   With[{eps = 1}, 
   N@DEigensystem[{-0.5*f''[x] - 
   6*eps*Sech[Sqrt[2*eps]*(x - 0)]^2*f[x] + eps*f[x], 
  DirichletCondition[f[x] == 0, True]}, f[x], {x, -2000, 2000}, 
  6]];
  Plot[funcN1, {x, -200, 200}, PlotLegends -> eigN1]
```

**EDIT**

I am considering the given equation to get the method working, as I know its analytical solution.
The eigenvalue equation I am ultimately interested in is

$$   - \frac{1}{2} y^{\prime \prime} - \epsilon^2 \exp{\Big( \frac{\epsilon z}{2} (x^2-1)\Big)} y =  \lambda y  $$

**EDIT FOLLOWING THE COMMENT FROM ALEXEI BOULBITCH**

Thanks for pointing to your work. The "Manipulate" block makes my PC crash, but I extracted the relevant code portion below.
I multiplied the whole equation by $-1$, to get the second derivative positive, I am still not so sure how to deal with the method.
I tried  using the analytical solution  as initial condition (inverted sign with respect to the first eigenfunction I wrote down in the post above), and it seems to work (as it does not evolve much up at the beginning, for relatively short times) but then it diverges (say $t > 1000$, as it should do I think, as the eigenvalue is negative and the eigenfunction is unstable). If use one of our initial conditions, it seems to converge to a different solution (even for long times) (your Gaussian) or issues errors (your third initial  condition). I am trying to thoroughly check all the signs and other typos, but I am wondering if in general your "gradient flow" type method is suitable at all to find an eigenfunction with a negative eigenvalue, as such eigenfunctions are unstable, in my understanding. Below the code using your third boundary condition. The exact eigenfunction is also written after the "solution" command.

```
equation[λ_] := 
 D[u[x, τ], τ] == 
  0.5*D[u[x, τ], {x, 2}] - 
   6*1*Sech[Sqrt[2*1]*(x - 0)]^2*u[x, τ] - 
   1*u[x, τ] + λ *u[x, τ]

solution[λ_, τm_, L_, initialCondition_] := 
 NDSolve[{equation[λ], u[-L, τ] == 0, u[L, τ] == 0, 
   initialCondition}, u[x, τ], {x, -L, L}, {τ, 0, τm}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MinPoints" -> 5 L}}]

u[x, 0] == -Sqrt[3/4]*(2*1)^(1/4)*Sech[Sqrt[2*1]*(x - 0)]^2;
tmax = 2;
λ = -2.99;

Plot[
 Evaluate[
  u[x, τ] /. 
    solution[λ, tmax, 10, 
     u[x, 0] == 0.3*10^-4 (x + 10) (10 - x)^3] /. τ -> 
    tmax ], {x, -10, 10}, PlotTheme -> "Classic", 
 PlotRange -> {{-10.2, 11}, {0, 1.}}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style[x, 16], Style[u[x, Style["t", Italic]], 16]}, 
 TicksStyle -> Directive[12], AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.03], 
 ImageSize -> 400]
```

Comment: I published one alternative method some time ago. Have a look here: A. Boulbitch, Mathematica Journal, 20, 1, (2018) dx.doi.org/tmj.20-8. This method is for a nonlinear equation, however, if you are very slightly below the spectral value and normalize the obtained solution of the nonlinear equation you get the eigenfunction,

Comment: @Alexei Boulbitch, thanks I am reading it.

Comment: @Alexei Boulbitch, I did try your method (attempt described in an edit), I do not see though how it would work close to a negative, unstable, eigenvalue, am I completely mistaken? Thanks

Comment: I will write a detailed answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I promised, I am giving a solution based on the relaxational method. This method was developed to solve nonlinear equations. Details one finds in the paper A. Boulbitch, Mathematica Journal, 20, 1, (2018) dx.doi.org/tmj.20-8. Deriving the eigenvalue and eigenfunction of the ground state of the linear part of the equation is a side effect of the method. This task explicitly has not been described in the paper. My private opinion is that the solution of @bbgodfrey is better. However, this is one alternative way.

Nevertheless, let us first rescale your equation passing to the variable `X=Sqrt[2*eps]*(x-z)` and `m=(eps-lambda)/4eps`. Then your equation takes the simple form

```
D[u[X], {X, 2}] - 2 (m - 3/(2*Cosh[X]^2)) u[X] == 0 // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

This is almost the same equation as in my paper. It only differs by the factor 3/2. The solution must be straightforward.

Step 1: let us form an axillary nonlinear equation and its solution:

```
    equation[m_] := 
     D[u[X, τ], τ] == 
      D[u[X, τ], {X, 2}] - 2 (m - 3/(2*Cosh[X]^2)) u[X, τ] - 
       u[X, τ]^3;



     solution[m_, τm_, L_, initialCondition_] := 
 NDSolve[{equation[m], u[-L, τ] == 0, u[L, τ] == 0, 
   initialCondition}, u[X, τ], {X, -L, L}, {τ, 0, τm}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MinPoints" -> 5 L}}]
```

Step 2: Here we use two ideas. 1) The solution of the dynamic equation

[image]

converges to the solution of the static equation

[image]

and 2) That this static equation exhibits a bifurcation at the point `m=m0`, and in the close vicinity of the bifurcation (m slightly smaller than m0) its solution takes the form

[image]

where A is a numeric coefficient, u0(X) is the ground state eigenfunction and m0 is the corresponding eigenvalue of the static equation.
Assuming that u0(X) is normalized, one easily writes the relation for the norm of the function u(X)

[image]

Then we solve the equation and make a nested list each term of which contains the value m and the norm of the solution and fit it to the formula:

```
     tmaxfn[m_, ϵ_] := 8/((0.5 - m)^2 + ϵ)^(1/2);
ϵ = 10^-6;
listNorm2 = 
  Table[{m, (NIntegrate[
         u[X, τ]^2 /. 
           solution[m, tmaxfn[m, ϵ], 10, 
            u[X, 0] == 0.2 Exp[-X^2]] /. τ -> 
           tmaxfn[m, ϵ], {X, -10, 10}]/20)^(1/2)}, {m, 0.7, 
     0.95, 0.005}] /. {x_, {y_}} -> {x, y};
fit = FindFit[listNorm2, 
  If[m >= m0, 0, A ((m0 - m)^2 + ϵ)^(1/4)], {A, {m0, 0.83}}, 
  m]
    (*  {A -> 0.510035, m0 -> 0.848335}   *)
```

Let us now visually check the solution:

```
    Show[{ListPlot[listNorm2, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotTheme -> "Scientific",
    PlotRange -> {0, 0.2}, Axes -> None, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[{Black, 10}], 
   FrameLabel -> {Style["m", 16], 
     Row[{"||", Style["u", 16, Italic], "||"}]}, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[PointLegend[{Style["numeric solution", 12, 
        FontFamily -> "Times"]}], Scaled[{0.77, 0.77}]]], 
  Plot[If[m > m0, 0, A (m0 - m)^0.5] /. fit, {m, 0.7, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue}, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend[{Style[
        Row[{" fit with \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(m\), \(0\)]\) \
≈ ", NumberForm[fit[[2, 2]], {5, 4}]}], 12, 
        FontFamily -> "Times"]}], Scaled[{0.75, 0.6}]]]}, 
 ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

We see that the fit is very good, except for the points quite close to m=m0. This is to be expected due to the critical slowing down (see the paper). Therefore, we have found the eigenvalue m0=0.8483...

The eigenfunction can be found as the solution at m<m0, say m=0.837 and by its further normalization:

```
 sol = (solution[0.837, tmaxfn[0.837, ϵ], 10, 
      u[X, 0] == 0.2 Exp[-X^2]] /. τ -> 
      tmaxfn[0.837, ϵ])[[1, 1, 2]];
norm = Sqrt[NIntegrate[sol^2, {X, -10, 10}]/20];
Plot[sol/norm, {X, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Let us check that it is normalized:

```
NIntegrate[(sol/norm)^2, {X, -10, 10}]/20

(* 1.  *)
```

More details one finds in the paper mentioned above.

Have fun!

Comment: thanks for this, very much appreciated. I read your paper with care and am looking forward to trying your code, as some trials are did, did not go too well (I also do not understand how the "slowing down phenomenon has to do with the degradation of the fit quality you show). One question, what is the role of the $u(X)^3$ term in the static equation? Really want to try it, but I get an error "NDSolve::underdet: There are more dependent variables, {u[x,\[Tau]]}, than equations." after the "fit" command, I am trying to understand it and then will go on. Thanks a lot again

Comment: I am really a newbie, but could it be the NDSolve::underdet: There are more dependent variables, {u[x,[Tau]]}, than equations error message comes from the presence of both capital and lower case Xs, in the equation definition and later in the NdSolve? If I use lower case "x" in the "equation" definition it all works...

Comment: 1) Critical slowing down means that for m close to m0 the convergence requires more time. So there the time limit should be increased. 2) You should either use all capital Xs or all small. Never mix them up in the same equation. 3)  "NDSolve::underdet: There are more dependent variables, {u[x,[Tau]]}, than equations."  means exactly what it says. I guess you made an error in writing down the equation. Without having looked at your code I cannot say more.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code, after which I got the error. By using small x in the equation definition it works. In your notebook you use small x, maybe some copying and pasting (also the $u(x)^3$ term, which is absent in my equation), it is perfectly OK of course, would not want to be misunderstood I am really grateful, I appreciate the time you spent and learnt a lot thanks

Comment: Right. I mixed up X and x in the code. Now I corrected that. It must work.

Comment: sorry I am probably being really thick here. I do not understand the role of the $u(x)^3$ term. If I understood the method at all, the procedure depends only on the linear part (auxiliary equation (5) in your paper) of a general nonlinear equation, it should work also with a $u(x)^3$, or  without nonlinear term. Without any nonlinear term, as in my equation, I am unable to make it work. The longer the simulation time, the higher the norms get.  Thanks for your understanding and patience, I am missing a point, would be great if you gave me one more hint.

Comment: To understand it, please read attentively the introductory part of the paper. Keep in mind that the method is developed to solve nonlinear equations exhibiting bifurcations. Its application to finding the ground state eigenvalue/eigenfunction is a side effect. Its application is based on one theorem of the bifurcation theory. You will find it in the paper. In general, as I already have written above, the solution of @bbgodfrey is straightforward and, thus, it is much better. However, the method I give can work in difficult cases, in which standard methods do not work.

Comment: I got it thanks a lot, I gave too many things for granted and was lazy...thanks again very interesting

Answer (score 3):

If only a verification of the solutions is desired, then

```
eq = -u''[x]/2 - 6 ϵ Sech[Sqrt[2 ϵ] (x - z)]^2 u[x] + ϵ u[x] == λ u[x]

FullSimplify[eq /. λ -> -3 ϵ /. u -> Function[{x}, Sqrt[3/4] (2 ϵ)^(1/4) 
    Sech[Sqrt[2 ϵ] (x - z)]^2]]
(* True *)

FullSimplify[eq /. λ -> 0 /. u -> Function[{x}, Sqrt[3/2] (2 ϵ)^(1/4) 
    Sinh[Sqrt[2 ϵ] (x - z)] Sech[Sqrt[2 ϵ] (x - z)]^2]]
(* True *)
```

**Addendum: EigenSystem Derivation**

The two eigenvalues and corresponding eigenfunctions given in the question can be derived as follows.  First, simplify the ODE by introducing the independent variable `y = Sqrt[2 ϵ] (x - z)`, which leads to

```
eq1 = w[y] - 6 Sech[y]^2 w[y] - w''[y] == λ1 w[y]
```

where `λ1 = λ/ϵ`.  `eq1` is solved without difficult.

```
s = DSolveValue[eq1, w[y], y]
(* C[1] LegendreP[2, Sqrt[1 - λ1], Tanh[y]] + 
   C[2] LegendreQ[2, Sqrt[1 - λ1], Tanh[y]] *)
```

As `Tanh[y]` approaches `1` or `-1`, `LegendreQ[2, Sqrt[1 - λ1], Tanh[y]]` becomes infinite, so set `C[2] = 0`. `LegendreP[2, Sqrt[1 - λ1], Tanh[y]]` also becomes infinite as `Tanh[y]` approaches `1` or `-1`, except for positive integer values of `Sqrt[1 - λ1]`.  `λ1 = 0` and `λ1 = -3` lead to the expressions in the question, also validated earlier in this answer. `LegendreP[2, Sqrt[1 - λ1], Tanh[y]]` for `λ1 = -8`, `λ1 = -24`, etc., on the other hand, vanish for all `y`.  So, there are no other eigenvalues.  For completeness, here are plots of the eigenfunctions.

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[LegendreP[2, n, Tanh[y]], {n, 1, 5}], {y, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but I have checked even by hand. I would have liked to reproduce those results (even if only numerically), not just verify them. My wording was misleading I will edit. Furthermore, the equation I am interested is another one, which I mention in the post, I have usedone for which known analytical results are available to get the methods right.

Comment: @Smerdjakov  I believe that the addition to my answer comes closer to what you are seeking.  Of course, what I did will not generalize to all EigenSystem ODEs, because `DSolve` cannot solve all linear, second order ODEs.  Numerical  methods must be used for more general problems.

Comment: thanks for this, very useful, appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The question is misleading. It is somewhat a Sturm-Liouville type second order differential equation, but instead of being a usual one this is of the type [NDSolve Delay Differential Equations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDelayDifferentialEquations.html). This methodologies are added lately to the Mathematica built-ins. They can not handle parameters as $z$ that is seemingly continuous varying like $x$. So the $z$ parameter has to go. It can be treated as a table and than interpolated afterwards.

So I can not at first sight follow Your solution and how You got them. But I can do this:

```
DSolve[{y''[x] - 2 (6*eps*Sech[Sqrt[2*eps]*x]^2 + eps - v)*y[x] == 
   0}, y, x]

(*
{{y -> Function[{x}, (E^(2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[eps] x))^(-(1/2) + (
       eps + Sqrt[eps^2 - eps v])/(
       2 eps)) (1 + E^(2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[eps] x))^(
      1/2 (1 + 1/2 (1 - I Sqrt[23]) - (eps + Sqrt[eps^2 - eps v])/
         eps + (24 eps - 24 I Sqrt[23] eps - v + I Sqrt[23] v + 
          48 Sqrt[eps^2 - eps v] - (2 v Sqrt[eps^2 - eps v])/eps)/(
         48 eps - 2 v))) C[
      1] Hypergeometric2F1[1/2 (1 - I Sqrt[23]), (
       24 eps - 24 I Sqrt[23] eps - v + I Sqrt[23] v + 
        48 Sqrt[eps^2 - eps v] - (2 v Sqrt[eps^2 - eps v])/eps)/(
       48 eps - 2 v), (eps + Sqrt[eps^2 - eps v])/
       eps, -E^(2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[eps] x)] + (-1)^(
      1 - (eps + Sqrt[eps^2 - eps v])/
       eps) (-E^(2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[eps] x))^(
      1 - (eps + Sqrt[eps^2 - eps v])/eps) (E^(
       2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[eps] x))^(-(1/2) + (eps + Sqrt[eps^2 - eps v])/(
       2 eps)) (1 + E^(2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[eps] x))^(
      1/2 (1 + 1/2 (1 - I Sqrt[23]) - (eps + Sqrt[eps^2 - eps v])/
         eps + (24 eps - 24 I Sqrt[23] eps - v + I Sqrt[23] v + 
          48 Sqrt[eps^2 - eps v] - (2 v Sqrt[eps^2 - eps v])/eps)/(
         48 eps - 2 v))) C[
      2] Hypergeometric2F1[
       1 + 1/2 (1 - I Sqrt[23]) - (eps + Sqrt[eps^2 - eps v])/eps, 
       1 - (eps + Sqrt[eps^2 - eps v])/eps + (
        24 eps - 24 I Sqrt[23] eps - v + I Sqrt[23] v + 
         48 Sqrt[eps^2 - eps v] - (2 v Sqrt[eps^2 - eps v])/eps)/(
        48 eps - 2 v), 
       2 - (eps + Sqrt[eps^2 - eps v])/eps, -E^(
        2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[eps] x)]]}}
*)
```

$v$ is now a parameter accompanying $eps$. It is continuous. This solution collapses at $_0=−3$ and $_1=0$. So it needs the treatment behind your solutions. Around the two $$ the solution changes the behavior strongly. There might be others.

This is really hard to discuss because of the high dimensionality $,,x,z$.

For $z=1$ and $z=-1$ `DSolve` has no solutions. So `NDSolve` is needed and the problems gets tedious long before a solution can be written. The boundary conditions have to be given again:

```
NDSolve[{y''[x] - 2 (6*eps*Sech[Sqrt[2*eps]*x]^2 + eps - v)*y[x] == 0,
   y[-\[Infinity]] == 0, y[\[Infinity]] == 0}, y, x]
```

It might be better to run with a big number instead of infinity. But then there is only a zero not at vanishing at infinity. But better a solution and shorter runtimes than none.

Comment: I might have well assigned it a wrong classification, sorry for the confusion if that were the case. But I cannot see why it would be a delay ODE. Due to translational invariance, $z$ appears as a parameter, which could well be set to $0$, I believe. Same for $\epsilon$, just a parameter that could be set to unity, I just left just in case it was possible to find symbolic solutions. The two eigenfunctions, and related eigenvalues, I mention were found in literature. Thanks a lot I am going through what you did appreciated.