# Difficulty finding roots of an interpolation function from NDSolve

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

I have been trying to find the point at which one of the solutions of a system of two ODEs crosses zero. I used the method suggested in this answer to a previous question, which seemed to be the most efficient:

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16448/38989

(PS- I had tried FindRoot, but it was not useful as it finds only one root).

My problem is that the solution I am looking at crosses zero and falls very rapidly to large negative numbers. The above code doesn't seem to work in this case. Here is the code I used:

```
DiffEq1 = Derivative[2][h][r] + (2/r)*Derivative[1][h][r] - D[Potential[a, b], a] /. {a -> h[r], b -> s[r]}; 
DiffEq2 = Derivative[2][s][r] + (2/r)*Derivative[1][s][r] - D[Potential[a, b], b] /. {a -> h[r], b -> s[r]}; 

Reap[NDSolve[{DiffEq1 == 0, DiffEq2 == 0, h[10^(-18)] == 225, s[10^(-18)] == 10, 
    Derivative[1][h][10^(-18)] == 0, Derivative[1][s][10^(-18)] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[h[r] == 0, Sow[s[r]]]}, {h, s}, {r, 10^(-18), 1}]]
```

The differential equations have a $2/r$ factor, which is why I am starting from $10^{-18}$. (This singularity is not an actual problem since the initial first derivative is 0).

When I run this, I don't get any solutions at all, even though it does work for some other initial starting points. I know that the solution to h[r] does cross zero at least once, as it starts from a positive value, and it ends up at a very large negative value:

[image: Solution to h[r]]

I am struggling to find the reason for this. Does the Event Locator method have a problem with solutions that blow up and go to large numbers?

Edit: Potential[a,b] is a degree 4 polynomial in a and b. If I put in the numbers, this is what I get:

```
Potential[h_,s_]:= 1.1868147535541435*^8 - (15625*h^2)/4 + (15625*h^4)/524288 - 12768*s^2 + (h^2*s^2)/2 + 0.34340200000000004*s^4
```

Comment: What is `Potential[a, b]`?

Comment: I have edited the question to include this.

Comment: Be sure to look at the actual domain of the resulting solution (Look at the interpolation function display). When I run this it halts at 0.0472 with a step size zero error. If you ignore that error and plot the result past r=0.0472 you are not seeing a solution at all but just what results from extrapolating the interpolation function.  `h` is strictly positive and blows up at 0.0472 so it never gets to your `WhenEvent`

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you said about the domain. I am using NDSolve in the range `{r,10^-18,1}`. Why would it not calculate beyond `r=0.0472` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is worth explaining a little better. Here is what I get running the exact code:

[image]

You can see the error message and the domain say the integration stopped around 0.0473.

The trouble arises here, if you don't notice that  and plot
 over your specified range

```
 Plot[h[r] /. First@sol, {r, 10^-18, 1}]
```

[image]

you get a plot, but its just garbage past the error point. Why this is allowed baffles me. Note if you request a specific value, eg `h[.05] /. First@sol` you get a warning:

> "Input value {0.05`} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used. "

For some reason `Plot` does not give that warning.

Here is the actual solution:

```
 Plot[h[r] /. First@sol, {r, 
    10^-18, (h /. First@sol)["Domain"][[1, 2]]}]
```

which you see is always positive.

[image]

Comment: +1 george. I put a quiet when I saw 10^-18 in the main function. I didn't understand that the extrapolation can be a rubbish.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you have any idea why it can't solve past that point?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I get with MMA10 (Linux).

```
{solh, sols} = {h, s} /. 
 NDSolve[{DiffEq1 == 0, DiffEq2 == 0, h[10^(-18)] == 225, 
 s[10^(-18)] == 10, Derivative[1][h][10^(-18)] == 0, 
 Derivative[1][s][10^(-18)] == 0, 
 WhenEvent[h[r] == 0, Sow[s[r]]]}, {h, s}, {r, 10^(-18), 1}][[1]];

Plot[{solh[x], sols[x]}, {x, 0, .35}]
```

[image]

```
x /. FindRoot[solh[x] == 0, {x, 0.3}]
```

> 0.0472792

You can find more zeros by changing the initial guess.

```
Table[x /. FindRoot[solh[x] == 0, {x, x0}], {x0, 0, 0.1, 0.01}]
```

> {0., 0.0355549, 0.0366415, 0.03612, 0.0380459, 0.0472792, 0.0472792, \
>   0.0472792, 0.0472792, 0.0472792, 0.0472792}

Comment: I get that I can find multiple roots by changing the initial point, but I was looking for a way to get all the roots in a particular range without ambiguity. Although the FindRoot method might work in my particular case, I was curious if there was a more efficient and better way of doing this.