# Creating a For Loop for a equation that has many solutions

Tags: equation-solving

I have two equations like these. I want to create a for loop that gives to me all intersection points of the two equations. How can I do that?

```
 Plot[{x*BesselJ[1, x]*BesselK[0, Sqrt[
     22.295^2 - x^2]]/(BesselJ[0, x]*
      BesselK[1, Sqrt[22.295^2 - x^2]]), Sqrt[22.295^2 - x^2]}, {x, 0,
   23}]
```

[image: Graph for my equations]

Comment: Function `findAllRoots` described in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16439/find-all-roots-of-an-interpolating-function-solution-to-a-differential-equation/16444#16444) answer does the job in OP problem.

Comment: Also this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5663/12

Comment: Use `BesselJZero` to generate starting points for `FindRoot` .

Comment: @Pinti It also returns several "fake roots".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
NSolve[{x*BesselJ[1, x]*
  BesselK[0, 
    Sqrt[22.295^2 - x^2]]/(BesselJ[0, x]*
     BesselK[1, Sqrt[22.295^2 - x^2]]) - Sqrt[22.295^2 - x^2]} == 
0 && 0 < x < 23, x]
```

> {{x -> 2.30141}, {x -> 5.28092}, {x -> 8.27351}, {x -> 14.2381}, {x ->
>       17.1905}, {x -> 20.0892}}

**EDIT**

there is one more root x->11,2619

(see comments below)

Comment: This does not return all roots that the OP's plot is showing.

Comment: @Szabolcs The "extra roots" are the asymtotes of this function

Comment: I meant the root near `11.2619479668904`.

Comment: `Reduce` does seem to work. It gives a warning that it couldn't prove that all roots were returned, but none seem to be missing: `Reduce[x*BesselJ[1, x]*
     BesselK[0, 
       Sqrt[22.295^2 - x^2]]/(BesselJ[0, x]*
        BesselK[1, Sqrt[22.295^2 - x^2]]) - Sqrt[22.295^2 - x^2] == 
   0 && 0 < x < 23, x]`

Comment: I just saw that! why do you think mathematica skipped that one?

Comment: Well, numerical algorithms tend not to be perfect this way. I don't know how NSolve handles this sort of equation.  If I were to use FindRoot, I might just try several starting points for Newton's method, maybe taken from a regular grid.  It is clear that that might easily miss roots. `findAllRoots` (from the first comment) is a bit smarter, and uses `Plot` to detect zero-crossings, then refines those with `FindRoot`.  But then it gets all those "fake roots".  The end result should be filtered.

Comment: The amazing thing about Reduce is that in some cases it actually *guarantees* that the result has all* solutions. I do not understand how it does that, or how it can be done in general, but you can read a bit here: http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/12/18/mathematica-7-johannes-kepler-and-transcendental-roots/  This is a pretty unique ability of Mathematica, as far as I know.