# Eigen values of a third order linear homogenous ODE

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, eigenvalues

From a system of PDEs where i used the following ansatz: $$\theta_w(x,y) = e^{-\beta_h x} f(x) e^{-\beta_c y} g(y)$$.  $F(x) := \int f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ and $G(y) := \int g(y) \, \mathrm{d}y$
So, $$\theta_w(x,y) = e^{-\beta_h x} F'(x) e^{-\beta_c y} G'(y)$$ 
 I have  two linear ODEs of which one i am mentioning here
$$
\lambda_hF'''-2\lambda_h\beta_hF''+((\lambda_h\beta_h-1)\beta_h-\mu)F'+\beta_h^2F=0 $$ with the b.c. $$ F(0)=0 $$ $$ \frac{F''(0)}{F'(0)}=\beta_h $$

$$
\frac{F''(1)}{F'(1)}=\beta_h$$

Here $\mu$ is the separation constant

A general solution of this ODE will be of the form:

$$
F(x) = \sum_k C_k e^{-\delta_k(\mu)x}$$
$k$ attains values $1,2,3$ because of the cubic nature of the characterstic equation.

I need to find the eigenvalues of this ODE. I know i need to consider
$\mu><=$$0$. A second order ODE has a well defined form of its roots
which is not the case here.

I will mention here that i am not too well accustomed to *Mathematica*
But is there any way through which these eigen values could be
determined using Mathematica ? I am at a dead end here.

(Finally i need to repeat the complete procedure for $G$ and then proceed to find $\theta_w$)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Also the boundary condition at 1 is identical on the top and the bottom of the fraction

Comment: I can solve it numerically for a given value of $\beta$ and $\lambda$ (assuming it should be $F''(1)/F'(1)=\beta$). Depending on their values, both positive and negative eigenvalues can exist.

Comment: Also if $\beta =0$ they are given by $\mu_n = - \lambda (\pi n)^2$, but that is probably not a very interesting case, although for positive $\beta$ they stay reasonably close to those.

Comment: Try solving the ODE and two of the three boundary conditions with `DSolve`.  Then apply the third boundary condition to the resulting output to obtain an algebraic equation for the eigenvalues.

Comment: @KraZug you are right. I have edited the bc in my question.A typical value of $\lambda$ can be 0.02 and $\beta$ could be $10$. Can you look into it once

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a package for numerically calculating solutions of eigenvalue problems using the Evans function via the method of compound matrices, which is [hosted on github](https://github.com/SPPearce/CompoundMatrixMethod). See my [answers to other questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=compoundmatrixmethod) or the github for some more details.

First we install the package (only need to do this the first time):

```
Needs["PacletManager`"]
PacletInstall["CompoundMatrixMethod", 
    "Site" -> "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/paclets/Repository/master"]
```

Then we first need to turn the ODEs into a matrix form $\mathbf{y}'=\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{y}$, using my function `ToMatrixSystem`:

```
Needs["CompoundMatrixMethod`"]
sys = ToMatrixSystem[{λ F'''[x] - 2 λ β F''[x] + ((λ β - 1) β - μ) F'[x] + β^2 F[x] == 0}, 
         {F[0] == 0, F''[0] == β F'[0], F''[1] == β F'[1]}, F, {x, 0, 1}, μ]
```

The object `sys` contains the matrix $\mathbf{A}$, as well as similar matrices for the boundary conditions and the range of integration.

Now the function `Evans` will calculate the Evans function (also known as the Miss-Distance function) for any given value of $\mu$ provided that $\lambda$ and $\beta$ are specified; this is an analytic function whose roots coincide with eigenvalues of the original equation.

```
Evans[1, sys /. {λ -> 1, β -> 2}]
(* -0.023299 *)
```

We can also plot this:

```
Plot[Evans[μ, sys /. {λ -> 1, β -> 1}], {μ, -300, 300}, AxesLabel -> {"μ", "E(μ)"}]
```

[image]

For these parameter values you can see there are six eigenvalues within the plot region, the function `findAllRoots` (by user Jens, available from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16439/find-all-roots-of-an-interpolating-function-solution-to-a-differential-equation/16444#16444)) will give you them all:

```
findAllRoots[Evans[μ, sys /. {λ -> 1, β -> 1}], {μ, -300, 300}]
(* {-247.736, -158.907, -89.8156, -40.4541, -10.7982, -0.635232} *)
```

For the values $\lambda=0.02, \beta=10$, it helps to remove the normalisation that is applied by default in `Evans`, and I've also plotted the values given by bbgodfrey's solution:

```
Plot[Evans[μ, sys /. {λ -> 1/50, β -> 10}, NormalizationConstants -> 0], 
    {μ, -21, -2}, Epilog -> 
  Point[{#, 0} & /@ {-20.88, -17.48, -14.36, -11.53, -9.03, -6.92, -5.26, -4.08, -3.16}]]
```

[image]

It looks like there is an infinite set of solutions for negative $\mu$ for this set of parameters. For $\beta=0$ the eigenvalues are $-\lambda (n \pi)^2$, the general behaviour as $\mu->-\infty$ looks the same.

As you vary $\beta$ and $\lambda$ you can see how the function changes and eigenvalues can move and coalesce.

Note there is a discrepancy with bbgodfrey's results, which missed the root at $-3.392$ and gave a spurious one at $-3.165$. That isn't to say that you can't manage to get spurious solutions by applying `FindRoot` to this technique if you aren't careful.

Additionally, as the Evans function is (complex) analytic, you can use the Winding Number to find how many roots are within a contour. I have some functions for this, so you can see that there are only these 9 roots within the circular contour of size 21 located at the origin:

```
PlotEvansCircle[sys /. {λ -> 1/50, β -> 10}, ContourRadius -> 21, 
   nPoints -> 500, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Here the left hand side is a circle in the complex plane, and the right hand side is the Evans function applied to the points on that circle. The winding number is how many times the right hand contour goes round the origin. There is also a `PlotEvansSemiCircle` for seeing if there is a root in the positive half-plane (as that is a common question for instability).

To get the eigenfunctions, replace the right BC with $F'(0)$ to some arbitrary value and use NDSolve. This is at high precision to check the boundary conditions are being met:

```
Block[{β = 10, λ = 1/50},
 μc = μ /. FindRoot[Evans[μ, sys, NormalizationConstants -> 0, 
      WorkingPrecision -> 50], {μ, -3}, WorkingPrecision -> 50, 
     AccuracyGoal -> 15, PrecisionGoal -> 15] // Quiet;
 sol = First[NDSolve[{λ F'''[x] - 2 λ β F''[x] + ((λ β - 1) β - μ) F'[x] + β^2 F[x] == 0, 
   F[0] == 0, F''[0] == β F'[0], F'[0] == 1/10} /. μ -> μc, F, 
   {x, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 50, AccuracyGoal -> 30, PrecisionGoal -> 30]];
 Plot[(F[x]/F[1]) /. sol, {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   "Eigenfunction for μ=" <> ToString@Round[μc, 0.0001] <> ", with BC error: " <> 
    ToString@Round[((F''[1] - β F'[1]) /. sol), 0.0001], 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "F(x) (scaled)"}, PlotRange -> All]
 ]
```

[image: eigenfunction]

The eigenfunctions get increasingly oscillatory as the eigenvalue gets more negative:

```
roots = Reverse@findAllRoots[Evans[μ, sys /. {λ -> 1/50, β -> 10}, 
    NormalizationConstants -> 0], {μ, -200, -2}]
Plot[Evaluate[Table[(F[x]/F[1]) /. 
    NDSolve[{λ F'''[x] - 2 λ β F''[x] + ((λ β - 1) β - μ) F'[x] + β^2 F[x] == 0, 
 F[0] == 0, F''[0] == β F'[0], F'[0] == 1/1000} /. {λ -> 1/50, β -> 10}, 
     F, {x, 0, 1}], {μ, roots}]], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "F(x), scaled"}]
```

[image]

The method will work for higher order systems (up to 10th order generally), and does not require DSolve to be able to solve the underlying ODE.

Comment: I should probably note that I don't currently have support for getting the eigenfunctions out of my package, which it looks like you'll probably need to proceed.

Comment: This was great and very useful. My only doubt was regarding the range of $\mu$ selected, which i guess i need to choose judiciously. Further since the general solution of $F$ is of the form $
F(x) = \sum_k C_k e^{-\delta_k(\mu)x}$, the eigen functions should be of the form $e^{-\delta_k(\mu_n)t}$ The $\delta_k$ is the root of the characteristic equation

Comment: @IndrasisMitra, added how to get the eigenfunctions and some examples. I would say not to accept an answer immediately, and wait to see if any other answers are forthcoming.

Comment: can the increasing oscillatory nature of eigenfunctions as the eigenvalues get more negative be inferred in a way  that $F$ does not converge ?

Comment: also i see that you have numerically solved the ODE with an arbitrary value of $F'(0)$ to find the eigenfuctions. I fail to grasp the logic behind this step

Comment: The arbitrary value of F'(0) becomes a scaling factor, as eigenfunctions by definition have an arbitrary constant remaining in the solution.  Much like how eigenvectors are only defined up to a constant.

Comment: As to the other question about the oscillations,  they look like the product of a sinusoidal term and an exponential term.  I suspect that the analytical solution for $beta=0$ would be informative about this.

Comment: I tried the analytical solution for $\beta_h=0$ but it could not proceed as the BC have $\beta_h$ themselves. What i fail to get is , how to get the eigenfunction itself in an analytical form (as an expression)

Comment: Also i was looking at some other examples you solved with your method here on SE like the one where you solve a 4th order EBVP. In all cases the Eigenvalues do seem to decrase as they move away from the origin which is exactly opposite from my case. Is this unusual ?

Comment: The plot I show is scaled on the value at x=1, else all you see are the largest eigenvalues, so I don't think so. Any scalar multiple of those functions are also solutions, so you need some other restriction to determine their amplitude.

Comment: thanks. Also, you plotted an eigenfunction too. Is it possible to get an expression through mathematica. Probably i should start a new question.

Comment: You can get the interpolation functions of the eigenfunctions that are produced by solving the equation numerically using `NDSolve` (or `NDSolveValue`).

Answer (score 4):

*Error corrected by deleting `Numerator` from definition of `s`.*

This problem can be transformed symbolically to an algebraic equation by the method described in my earlier comment.

```
eq = ll f'''[x] - 2 ll b f''[x] + ((ll b - 1) b - m) f'[x] + b^2 f[x] == 0;
s = Simplify[DSolveValue[{eq, f''[0] == b f'[0], f''[1] == b f'[1]}, f[x], x]
    /. x -> 0 /. C[1] -> 1]
```

The resulting expression in terms of `Root` is too lengthy to be reproduced here and must, in any case, be solved numerically to provide values for `m`.  For the parameters given by the OP in a comment,

```
Table[FindRoot[s /. {ll -> 1/50, b -> 10}, {m, m0}] // Chop // Values, 
    {m0, -21, -1, 1/10}] // Flatten;
Union[%, SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < 10^-4 &)]

(* {-20.8885, -17.4846, -14.3644, -11.5367, -9.03846, -6.92843, 
    -5.26567, -4.08628, -3.39259} *)
```

There appear to be no larger values of `m` for this set of parameters.  There are, of course, many more-negative values, perhaps an infinite number.

Here are a few more cases.  For `{ll -> 1/10, b -> 10}`,

```
(* {-13.9638, -7.91839, -3.94417, -1.94864} *)
```

and for `{ll -> 1/1000, b -> 10}`,

```
(* {-20.5949, -19.94, -19.3031, -18.684, -18.0821, -17.4972, -16.9288, 
    -16.3763, -15.8388, -15.3158, -14.806, -14.3085, -13.822, -13.3451, 
    -12.8764, -12.4145, -11.9582, -11.5069, -11.0604, -10.6193, -10.1852, 
    -9.76044, -9.34825, -8.95222, -8.57622, -8.22411, -7.89954, -7.6058, 
    -7.34579, -7.12193, -6.93623, -6.79024, -6.68516, -6.62179} *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this help. Now i have some idea. Some points i need to clarify. For the case $\lambda_h=0.1$ and $\beta_h=10$, you have posted a set of eigenvalues that come out. You also mention that there could be infinitely many more negative values. Any advice on how many of these eigen values should one consider to generate a solution ? I know the query is not related to *mathematica* here. Thanks again.

Comment: @IndrasisMitra  There is no good way to know without seeing the actual sum you are constructing.  Is it a sum of eigenfunctions for the ODE in your question, or something else?  In general, if the function to be approximated by a sum is reasonable uniform, then probably only a half-dozen or so eigenvalues are needed.

Comment: I have edited my original post to show the type of series i expect. Yes, it is a sum of eigenfunctions from the ODE i posted.

Comment: I'm getting a catastrophic precision loss for `FindRoot` at your largest root for `{ll -> 1/50, b -> 10}`: s /. {ll -> 1/50, b -> 10} /. 
 FindRoot[s /. {ll -> 1/50, b -> 10}, {m, -3}, WorkingPrecision -> 20] gives me no significant digits to display (I don't believe it to be a root).

Comment: @KraZug  I now see that it is not a root.  My error was to use only the `Numerator`, which I plan to correct soon.  Thanks.

Comment: I was more surprised that there was no error from FindRoot actually, as gave no significant digits when you sub it back in.

Comment: @KraZug  Plotting my original expression for `s` a few hours ago suggested that the incorrect root was located at a branch point, which went away with the corrected expression for `s`.  `FindRoot` assumes analyticity, which was violated there.  Nonetheless, I agree that I too would have expected an error message.  By the way, your answer is excellent (+1).

Comment: Ok. It can also happen at points where the ODE has a repeated root, as the general solution breaks down there. Is it worth submitting as a bug the original issue? No warning message from FindRoot is essentially saying that it has happen with the Accuracy and Precision of the result. Thanks for the compliment too, although I wish that answers in general got more votes on this site.

Comment: @KraZug Submitting a bug report might make sense, but the most I would expect to happen is a note in the documentation under "Possible Issues" that this can happen.