# How can we deal with initial value sensitivity of FindRoot?

Tags: equation-solving

Recently, I have tried to find minima of some functions with `FindMinimum`, but those are so flat that the results cannnot be reliable.

So I switched the method to apply `FindRoot` on their derivatives. Although it is so fast way, but potentially it has some problems. As you know, `FindRoot` depends on initial values severely. Unfortunately, I cannot submit my own `.nb` file because it contains data not published yet. Instead I can give a simple example; For

`f = 1/x^4 (x^3 - 3 x^2*y + 6 x*y + 3*x*y^2 + y^3)`
and `g = (x^3 + 3 x^2*y - 6 x*y - 3*x*y^2 + y^3)`,

`FindRoot[{f == 0, g == 0}, {{x, 1}, {y, -0.482}},MaxIterations -> 10000, WorkingPrecision -> 100] // AbsoluteTiming`

results as

> {0.351312, {x -> 0.0123426, y -> -0.0000255474}}

with an error (FindRoot::cvmit).

However if we start this calculation with initial values `{{x, 1}, {y, -0.483}}` , we can get a correct answer:

> {0.0009858, {x ->
> 1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> 00000000000000000000000000000000000,
> y -> -1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000}}

. Only what I did is shifting initial value of `y` with `0.001`.

Please look a figure below. The orange line is `f`, the blue one is `g` evaluated at `x=1` respectively.
Actually, there is an extremum at `y -> -0.414214`, but it is far from initial point a bit.

Is there any way to deal with this kind of problems with `FindRoot`? General solutions are welcomed.

Of course I can use `NSolve`, but it often takes very long time compared to `FindRoot`, and I need only one solution so I don't want to use it.

[image: Fig.1]

Comment: If you can plot the function, have you tried the `findAllRoots` function from here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16439/find-all-roots-of-an-interpolating-function-solution-to-a-differential-equation/16444#16444

Comment: Thank you, but actually I have to find roots of multi (more than 3) variables functions, so maybe I cannot apply this... sorry.

Comment: When you used `NSolve` did you include bounds, e.g., `NSolve[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0, -2 < x < 2, -2 < y < 2}, {x, y}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 100]`?

Comment: @BobHanlon Yes, but I think ```NSolve``` takes so long time even if there are additional conditions. Indeed, I've been advised to use  ```FindRoot``` instead of ```NSolve``` in my past question.