# Using Reduce with a Interpolation function

Tags: equation-solving, interpolation

I am trying to find all the solutions of an equation that contains an interpolation function `int`, where `int=Interpolation[data]` (the interpolation of some data I have).

When I tried to use `Reduce` such as:

`Reduce[int''[x] == 0, {x}]`

I get an error saying "Reduce::inex: Reduce was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present in the system. Since many of the methods used by Reduce require exact input, providing Reduce with an exact version of the system may help.".

The same is true if I use `NSolve` as `NSolve[int''[x] == 0, x]`

**Question:**
How can I use `Reduce` when my input is an interpolation function?

Comment: AFAIK, `Reduce` won't work with interpolated functions. `NSolve` should work like you said, so without seeing the data I can't say why it didn't work. `NSolve` will likely only return a subset of the solutions. `FindRoot` can be used to find all solutions, but you need to know where they are, roughly. See  [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16439/find-all-roots-of-an-interpolating-function-solution-to-a-differential-equation) question on finding all of them automatically.

Comment: Try converting the interpolating function to a `Piecewise` polynomial.

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks! thats a good idea !

Comment: Apart from [converting your interpolant to a piecewise function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59944), you could also use the `MeshFunctions` option of `Plot[]`, or use `NDSolve[]` with `WhenEvent[]` to seek roots.