# Problem finding roots

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to obtain numerically the roots of a function, but Mathematica is not able to obtain them. I used NSolve, FindRoot and even the custom [Jens' findAllRoots function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16439/find-all-roots-of-an-interpolating-function-solution-to-a-differential-equation/16444#16444), but none of them work. Any solution? The code that I used is the following:

```
ClearAll[ff, f, FF, F, kb, T, TL, TR, m, mr, ml, V]

ff[e_, m_?NumberQ, t_?NumberQ] := 1/(1 + Exp[(e - m)/t])(*temperature is expressed in units of T/Subscript[k, B]*)

tt[e_, e0_?NumberQ, w_?NumberQ] := 1/(1 + Exp[-(e - e0)/w])(*transmission probability*)

e0 = 0;
w = .3;
ml = .4;
mr = -.4;
tl = 1;
tr = 1;

kk[e_] = D[tt[e, e0, w]*(ff[e, ml, tl] - ff[e, ml, tl]^2 + 
                         ff[e, mr, tr] - ff[e, mr, tr]^2), e];

NSolve[kk[e]==0,e]
FindRoot[kk[e],{e,0}]
findAllRoots[kk[e], {e, -2, 5}, "ShowPlot" -> False]
```

The outputs show convergence problems. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `FindRoot[kk[e], {e, 1}]  (*  {e -> 0.694818}  *)`  Plotting `ff[e]` helps to find a starting value.

Comment: `NSolve[kk[e] == 0, e, Reals]  (*  {e -> 0.694818}  *)` also works.

Comment: Restricting the arguments of `ff` and `tt` to being numbers is unnecessary since these functions do not use numeric techniques. However, if it were necessary to restrict their arguments, `NumericQ` should be used rather than `NumberQ`. `NumberQ` returns `False` for symbolic numbers such as `Pi` or `E`.

Comment: `NSolve[kk[e] == 0 && -2 < e < 5, e]`, using the limits in your `findAllRoots`, also works.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. All your solutions work nicely. But I cannot understand why the range inside NSolve must be specified (or I have to indicate that the solution is real), if the function is a well-behaved variable. The same occurs with FindRoot. I knew that the zero was located between 0 and 1, and for that reason I started at 0. Why does 1 work, but 0 doesn't? Nevertheless, I appreciate all your help.

Comment: @V.Arjona - "`NSolve` deals primarily with linear and polynomial equations." Your problem is neither and Mathematica generally assumes that all variables can be complex. In this case it needs to be told that the variable is real, either explicitly by specifying the domain or implicitly by using the variable in an inequality. The performance of `FindRoot` is always highly dependent on the starting value.

Comment: There are methods for determining all roots of a transcendental equation over a bounded interval provided there are finitely many roots (and that the equation behaves numerically well). It's one of the methods `NSolve` can try, but only if you specify a bounded interval.  BTW, no one has mentioned it but `NSolve[kk[e] == 0, e]` works fine in V12.2 and returns several infinite families of roots in the complex plane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the transformation
$$e \to \log s$$
we can relatively easy to plot the figure.
And I guess that only one root around $s=2$. ( The `MeshFunctions -> (#2 &)` and `Mesh->{{0}}` can also locate the root, but I don't how to extract the root from the `FullForm` of the plot)

```
ff[e_, m_, t_] := 
 1/(1 + Exp[(e - m)/
      t])(*temperature is expressed in units of T/Subscript[k,B]*)

tt[e_, e0_, w_] := 1/(1 + Exp[-(e - e0)/w])(*transmission probability*)

e0 = 0;
w = .3;
ml = .4;
mr = -.4;
tl = 1;
tr = 1;
kk[e_] = D[
   tt[e, e0, 
     w]*(ff[e, ml, tl] - ff[e, ml, tl]^2 + ff[e, mr, tr] - 
      ff[e, mr, tr]^2), e];
g[s_] := (kk[e] /. e -> Log[s]);
Plot[g[s], {s, 0, 4}, MeshFunctions -> (#2 &), 
 MeshStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Red}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 AxesLabel -> {s, kk}, Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}]
FindRoot[g[s], {s, 2}]
Log[s] /. %
```

> `{s -> 2.00334}`

> `0.694818`

[image]

**Edit**

We can also do this directly by `NMinimize` or `NMaximize` to find a root.

```
Plot[kk[e], {e, -10, 10}, MeshFunctions -> (#2 &), 
 MeshStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Red}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 AxesLabel -> {e, kk}, Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}]
NMinimize[{kk[e]^2, e > 0}, e]
NMinimize[{0, kk[e] == 0, e > 0}, e]
```

> `{1.49378*10^-17, {e -> 0.694818}}`

> `{0., {e -> 0.694818}}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this solution solves the problem. But why did I have those problems using the standard methods of mathematica? Why does it necessary to use this trick?

Comment: @V.Arjona Another way to find a root is using `NMinimize`, see the updated.