# Why can't NSolve solve for the obvious zeros?

Tags: equation-solving, bugs, special-functions

**Bug introduced in 13.2 or earlier and fixed in 14.0**

---

```
a = 0.082551;
b = 12.9307;
r = 944.815;
g[x_] := Hypergeometric1F1[1 - x, 2, (2 a)/(b x) r];
Plot[g[x], {x, -10, 0}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

By means of the `Plot` we can obviously find a zero point. The root is then solved for by `FindRoot`.

```
zero = FindRoot[g[x] == 0, {x, -1}][[1, 2]]
```

> -1.00069

```
Plot[g[x], {x, -10, 0}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Epilog -> Style[Point[{zero, g[zero]}], PointSize[Large], Red]]
```

[image]

Next I try to solve for that root using `NSolve` given the range of independent variables, but why does it result in an empty set?

```
NSolve[g[x] == 0 && -100 < x < 0, x]
```

> { }

Comment: Interestingly, `NSolve` returns unevaluated if you don't include conditions on $x$, which is arguably better than returning an incorrect result. I'd report this to Support.

Comment: The parameters look like 6-digit approximations (i.e. `PrintPrecision` ones). Do you have exact values, or 16-digit approximations?

Comment: @MichaelE2 The parameters in the given example are any decimals I can take. (For preliminary testing)

Comment: So I can get solutions to `NSolve[Hypergeometric1F1[1 - x, 2, c/x] == 0 && ?? < x < -1, {x}]` for `3.6705 < c < 7.0045`, adjusting the lower bound `??` to suit. (For `c = 3.6705` the root is around `-391`; for `c = 4`, it's `-2.`

Comment: Oh, the root goes to $-\infty$ as $c \rightarrow 3.67049\dots$. Duh. I can't explain the upper bound, though.

Comment: This has been reported as a bug.

Comment: Related? Looking for a simpler function instead if the hypergeometric I tried 1/Gamma[x] and found this peculiar behaviour Table[{n, NSolve[1/Gamma[x] == 0 && -n < x < 0, x]}, {n, 0, 
   20}] // Column

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This shows the step that rejects the root (note that `Rationalize` is applied to `g[x]` internally):

```
tr = Trace[
   NSolve[g[x] == 0 && -2 < x < -1, {x}],
   _Select,
   TraceInternal -> True] // Flatten // Last
```

> [image]

This shows that `Hypergeometric1F1` has some round-off error that prevents it from equaling `0`.  (I change the invisible `HoldForm` to the visible `Hold`; it should make the first steps clearer.)

```
tr = tr /. HoldForm -> Hold;
Trace[tr // ReleaseHold,
  TraceDepth -> 3] /. {h_HoldForm :> h, 
  List -> (Column[#, Dividers -> All] &)@*List}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

*Addendum: Hackathon*

Well, just because I get curious how these things work. It won't matter that much when WRI fixes the problem.  The code below addresses two bugs.

First, numerics.  I said above that round-off error caused the root candidate to test as not-a-root.  I now think it's more likely that the hypergeometric function is computed with too much accuracy.  That shouldn't be viewed as a problem, but `NSolve` seems to rely on round-off error being greater than the function value at a root.  If so, then too little round-off error is a problem when you compare the function to zero.  I don't have a way of knowing if this is true.  (One can review arbitrary-precision numbers in the middle sections [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Numbers.html); recall that ``` 0``17. ``` represents a result that differs from zero by less than `10^-17.` and is equal to zero, that is. ``` 0``17. == 0 ``` evaluates to `True`).

Second, plot-based root finding (see for example, `findAllRoots[]` in [Find all roots of an interpolating function (solution to a differential equation)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16439/find-all-roots-of-an-interpolating-function-solution-to-a-differential-equation/16444#16444)) can be subject to the limitations of `Plot`, in particular the `Automatic` choices for `PlotPoints` and `PlotRange`.  In the OP's equation with the bounds `-2 < x < -1`, `NSolve[]` finds an approximation to the root by plotting and refines it with `FindRoot[]`. (Then rejects it due to the numerics issue explained above.)  `NSolve[]` uses the `Automatic` settings for these two options.  For the OP's original problem with the bounds `-100 < x < 0`, the automatic `PlotRange` chosen is entirely negative and does not capture the root.

We address both problems below. For the numerics problem, we look for a zero-crossing in an epsilon neighborhood of the proposed root. The `WorkingPrecision` will be the `Precision` of the argument `Slot[1]`. Since arbitrary-precision numbers have extra digits beyond the `Precision`, we can make a slightly smaller neighborhood than the epsilon corresponding to `Precision[Slot[1]]` to implement a more rigorous test of roots as befits `NSolve[]`. We evaluate the function at the root candidate $r_0$ and $r_0\pm\varepsilon/2$. If the absolute value of the sum of the signs of the function values is less than $3$, then either one of the values is zero or two have have opposite. In either case, we accept $r_0$ (even if the zero value occurs at one of $r_0\pm\varepsilon/2$).

For the plotting problem, we set the option `PlotRange -> All`.  It turns out that `NSolve` does not call `Plot[]`, but the internal version `` Visualization`Core`Plot[] ``, so we set the option for that function. (One can also set `PlotPoints` if that seems necessary; one could add that option to [findAllRoots[]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16439/find-all-roots-of-an-interpolating-function-solution-to-a-differential-equation/16444#16444), too.)

Hacking caveat: By adding a definition to `Select[]`, we create the potential of interfering with something unknown and messing up `NSolve[]`. I checked that the form of `Select[]` defined below is called only once in the OP's `NSolve[]` call.  `Select[]` is used a lot internally, so danger exists that a slightly different problem might have slightly different uses of `Select[]`.  I consider that the code is presented for display purposes, for those who might share my curiosity about internals.  In the meantime, I'd suggest that `findAllRoot[]` is a better alternative.

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Select},
 (* Numerics fix *)
 Unprotect@Select;
 ClearAttributes[Select, ReadProtected];
 DownValues[Select] = Prepend[
   DownValues@Select,
   HoldPattern[Select[e_, Function[Equal[f_, 0]]] /; ! TrueQ[$in]] :> 
    Block[{$in = True},
     Select[e,
      With[{fvals = 
          Function[
            f] /@ (Slot[
              1] (1 + SetPrecision[10^-Precision[Slot[1]], 
                  Infinity]/(2) {-1, 0, 1}))},
        dbPrint[fvals];
        Abs@Total[Sign[fvals]] < 3 (* zero-crossing *)
        ] &
      ]
     ]
   ];
 Protect@Select;
 
 (* Plotting fix *)
 WithCleanup[
  opts = Options@Visualization`Core`Plot;
  SetOptions[Visualization`Core`Plot, {PlotRange -> All}];
  
  (* OP's problem *)
  NSolve[g[x] == 0 && -100 < x < -1, x],
  
  (* clean up *)
  SetOptions[Visualization`Core`Plot, opts]
  ]
 ]
```

> ```
> (*  {{x -> -1.00069}}  *)
> ```

Comment: Good grief. Should I just report the bugs to you? (Adam found it to be exactly as described here. His fix is in my queue to review, and will be looked at no later than tomorrow.)

Comment: Thanks, @DanielLichtblau . Actually, it was Adam's talk at WTC years ago about new rapidly convergent series for calculating special functions to arbitrary precision that gave me the idea.

Answer (score 8):

I could not find why `NSolve` fail. Could be a bug? I tried FunctionExpand but that did not help.

As a workaround, use `Solve`?

```
a=0.082551//Rationalize;
b=12.9307//Rationalize;
r=944.815//Rationalize;
g[x_]:=Hypergeometric1F1[1-x,2,(2 a)/(b x) r];
Solve[g[x]==0&& -2<x<0,x]//N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Why the `Rationalize`?

Comment: @RomkeBontekoe  `Solve` is an exact solver. But `NSolve` is not an exact solver. To avoid numerical problems, better to use exact numbers with `Solve`. The command `Rationalize` converts the numbers to exact form (rational numbers).  If you try the above without doing this first, you will see that `Solve` will fail to find solution, as internally different algorithms or different code paths are used for exact vs. non-exact.

Answer (score 4):

Fixed in Version 14.0

```
a = 0.082551;
b = 12.9307;
r = 944.815;
g[x_] := Hypergeometric1F1[1 - x, 2, (2 a)/(b x) r];
NSolve[g[x] == 0 && -100 < x < 0, x]
```

Gives

```
{{x->-1.00069}}
```

Screen shot:

[image]