# Find the zero crossing in data

Tags: equation-solving, interpolation

I have the following list.
`l = Table[Sin[i], {i, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}] // N`  which gives me the following data,
`{0., 0.8414709848078965, 0.9092974268256817, 0.1411200080598672,`
`-0.7568024953079283, -0.9589242746631385, -0.2794154981989259,`
`0.6569865987187891, 0.9893582466233818, 0.4121184852417566,`
`-0.5440211108893698, -0.9999902065507035, -0.5365729180004349,`
`0.4201670368266409, 0.9906073556948704, 0.6502878401571168`
`-0.2879033166650653, -0.9613974918795568, -0.7509872467716762,`
`0.1498772096629523, 0.9129452507276277, 0.836655638536056,`
`-0.008851309290403876, -0.8462204041751706, -0.9055783620066239,`
`-0.132351750097773}`
Then I plotted the data with `ListLinePlot[l]`. The plot is the following  picture

[image]

Now, if I want to know the value of each zero crossing with the x-axis, can I interpolate over data and use the `FindRoot` function? I tried this method but I was not successful.

I appreciate it if you could help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$Version
"13.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)"
```

```
l = Table[Sin[i], {i, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}];
data = l // N;
plot = ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, 
  Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> Red]
Cases[plot, Point[{root_, 0.}] :> root, -1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to apply this method to any periodic data to find the zero-crossings?

Comment: Unfortunately, the zero values are not printed since I try your idea!

Comment: @Lohrasb  We need to use version 13.3. https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/quick-revision-history/

Comment: It works perfectly with the new version. Thanks a lot!

Comment: With the  code
   `Cases[plot, {root_, 0.} :> root, -1]`
with version 10.2 and even earlier it will work

Answer (score 2):

You could use `FindRoot` as follows

```
l = Table[{i, Sin[i]}, {i, -4 Pi, 4 Pi, Pi/4}] // N;

ff = Interpolation[l, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
   PeriodicInterpolation -> True];
```

Then

```
{ListLinePlot[l,InterpolationOrder -> 3], 
  ListPlot[
   Table[{x /. 
       FindRoot[ff[x] == 0, {x, RandomChoice[First /@ l, 1]}] // 
      First, 0},
    {100}], PlotStyle -> Red]} // Show
```

[image]

See [FindAllCrossing2D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/275/1089) for a generalisation in higher dimensions.

---

To get the values themselves just try

```
Table[x /. FindRoot[ff[x] == 0, {x, RandomChoice[First /@ l, 1]}] // 
   First, {100}]/Pi // Chop // Union // Rationalize // (# Pi) &
```

[image]

Note that thanks to the periodicity it finds other points beyond the range considered :-)

Comment: Thanks, but how can I know what are the values?

Answer (score 1):

I guess we should acknowledge recycling ideas.  For my contribution to this Q&A, I'll cite Jen's 2012 `findAllRoots[]` from [Find all roots of an interpolating function (solution to a differential equation)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16439/find-all-roots-of-an-interpolating-function-solution-to-a-differential-equation/16444#16444), which was written to find all roots of an interpolating function, essentially the very problem in this question.

```
findAllRoots[
 Interpolation[l, x, InterpolationOrder -> 1], {x, 0.999999, 
  Length[l]}, "ShowPlot" -> True]
```

[image]

Or, alternatively:

```
findAllRoots[
 Interpolation[l, x], {x, 1 - 2^32 $MachineEpsilon, Length[l]}, 
 "ShowPlot" -> True]
```

[image]

It is remarkable that such a basic problem as the OP's is still not addressed by a standard Mathematica solver.  Jens' answer is over ten year old!  `NSolve` will use an internal plot-based solver on some equations, using a method similar to @cvgmt's and seen many times on this site.  `NSolve` then polishes the roots with `FindRoot`, since the values from plotting are close but not usually highly accurate.  This step should be considered necessary if interpolating with a smooth spline as in @Chris's answer. For linear interpolation, such as `ListPlot` does in @cvgmt's answer, the plot probably gives an accurate estimate of the roots of the linear interpolant. Linear interpolation is the principal source of error in that method.

P.S. Feel free to vote to close as a duplicate. Given the question, "can I interpolate over data and use the FindRoot function?", this seems the same as the one I linked.