# ListContourPlot Interpolation

Tags: plotting, interpolation, matlab

I plotted a data file with `ListContourPlot` and I have this result:

```
j132 = Import[
"/home/mateus/Desktop/LaminarSeparationBubble/AlamSandham/\
ShootingMethod/Rayleigh/Teste/Dados/New/paraloop_5.dat"];

lista132 = Table[{Abs[j132[[i, 3]]], j132[[i, 4]], j132[[i, 8]]}, {i, 
1,Length[j132]}];

ListContourPlot[lista132, Contours -> 50, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(U\), \(R\)]\)", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(h\), \(R\)]\)", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Omega]\), \(i\)]\)"}, 
 FrameStyle -> FontSize -> 14, ImageSize -> 350]
```

[image]

But, if I plot the same file data with "mesh" function at MATLAB I have this result:

[image]

It's seems that *Mathematica* interpolates some region. Look the region below and above at the first figure.
MATLAB doesn't interpolate. 
Maybe the next figure is more clear.

[image]

So the questions is: How can I obtain the same result of MATLAB using *Mathematica*?

Comment: Could you provide your `j132` data? Have you tried with `ListDensityPlot`?

Comment: Without an example data set, I usually wouldn't upvote this question. However, I believe the topic is interesting and I hope some other answer will pop up. Therefore +1. Feel free to include my test data in your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop ListContourPlot from interpolating beyond the data points](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/151819/stop-listcontourplot-from-interpolating-beyond-the-data-points)

Comment: You need to define a `RegionFunction` fro,m the points to use in `ListContourPlot`.

Comment: @Edmund This is odd because it was the first thing I tried. Defining a region function that based on a `NearestFunction` to the points. Maybe I missed something, but I couldn't get a density plot without the non-convex part.

Comment: @Edmund Found the issue and it makes me think that `RegionFunction` will be hard to use in a very general case, where the region can only be extracted from the data-points.

Answer (score 4):

What you did in Matlab is not to compare what `ListDensityPlot` (which is what you should rather use) does. The white spots inside the plot tell that Matlab is not plotting a polygonized area, but a set of colored points instead.

Some test data that is comparable and consists of `{x,y,value}` entries:

```
data = Function[{x, y, z}, {x, y + x^2, z}] @@@ 
  Flatten[Table[{x, y, Sin[x + y]}, {x, -Pi, Pi, .1}, {y, 0, 2 Pi, .1}], 1];
```

First, let us kind-of recreate what Matlab does

```
Graphics[{ColorData["SunsetColors", #3^2], Point[{#1, #2}]} & @@@ 
  data, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can close the gaps by making the points larger, but in general this is no good solution when your data points are irregular. `ListDensityPlot` gives a smooth area instead that consists of an interpolated region of colored polygons

```
ListDensityPlot[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The problem is that the mesh generation will close regions when they are not convex. This might seem confusing at first, but it comes down to that there is absolutely no way to tell if the upper part is not part of the region or if you just miss some data-points there.
In general, this answer cannot be answered and therefore, Mathematica assumes a convex region and closes it.

However, you might be able to simply hack around this. Let us look at the created mesh

```
ListDensityPlot[data, Mesh -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In this example, the region where points are packed together can be separated from the region with long polygon edges and since I know that this part should not be in the graphics, I can filter out the large polygons

```
DeleteCases[Normal[ListDensityPlot[data]], 
 Polygon[pts_, ___] /; 
  Max[Norm[Subtract @@ #] & /@ Partition[pts, 2, 1]] > .6, Infinity]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With some adaption, this might as well work for your particular data set.

Comment: Could you make this work, too, by supplying a `PlotRegion`? Which you could probably build from a `RegionMember` on the appropriate `MeshRegion`.

Comment: @b3m2a1 [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/175008/187) this approach works very nice. However, if you only have points, you first need to construct the shape of the region and this is not easily possible. For humans, it's easy to look at scattered points and draw a region boundary, for an algorithm it's not so easy. I have seen several implementations of such algorithms in MeshLab, but I'm not sure we can do this in Mathematica out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach, making use of [`RegionFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html) and halirutan's data:

```
ListDensityPlot[
 data2,
 RegionFunction ->
  Function[{x, y, z}, y >= x^2 && y <= (1.9735 π + x^2)]
 ]
```

[image]

For some bizarre reason it doesn't work with a proper `2 π`...

If you want to generalize this to nastier shapes you can use any arbitrary `Region` and then supply the function that `RegionMember` makes, e.g.:

```
regionFunction =
  RegionMember@
   ImplicitRegion[
    y >= x^2 && y <= 1.9735 π + x^2,
    {{x, -3, 3}, {y, 0, 15}}
    ];

ListDensityPlot[
 data2,
 RegionFunction ->
  Function[
   Evaluate[regionFunction[{#, #2}]]
   ]
 ]
```

[image]