# Plotting displacement values over defined region

Tags: plotting, finite-element-method, regions, discrete, solidmechanics

I have a deformed 2D region of triangular `Elements` specified by their `Nodes` in $x$ and $y$ coordinate system. In addition, I have a list of `Displacements` in $y$ direction for each node. I want to ContourPlot the displacements over my deformed region of elements. So far my reasoning was to make a list `Nodes2` where each sublist has in the first two places the node position and the third is displacement. Then I use `ListContourPlot`.

```
Nodes = {{0., 0.}, {10., 0.}, {20., 0.}, {30., 0.}, {-0.101573, 9.81671}, {9.92361, 10.0459}, {19.8914, 10.2668}, {29.7869, 10.5013}, {-0.453558, 19.6276}, {9.57795, 20.086}, {19.5471, 20.5443}, {29.4276, 21.0344}, {-1.06222, 29.4477}, {8.97881, 30.1177}, {18.9679, 30.8116}, {28.8439, 31.5901}, {-1.90436,  39.3141}, {8.12513, 40.1282}, {18.1438, 41.0447}, {28.0142, 42.1991}, {-2.88222, 49.2855}, {7.0891, 50.1568}, {16.9537, 51.1588}, {26.904, 52.9408}};

Elements = {{1, 2, 6}, {6, 5, 1}, {2, 3, 7}, {7, 6, 2}, {3, 4, 8}, {8, 7, 3}, {5, 6, 10}, {10, 9, 5}, {6, 7, 11}, {11, 10, 6}, {7, 8, 12}, {12, 11, 7}, {9, 10, 14}, {14, 13, 9}, {10, 11, 15}, {15, 14, 10}, {11, 12, 16}, {16, 15, 11}, {13, 14, 18}, {18, 17, 13}, {14, 15, 19}, {19, 18, 14}, {15, 16, 20}, {20, 19, 15}, {17, 18, 22}, {22, 21, 17}, {18, 19, 23}, {23, 22, 18}, {19, 20, 24}, {24, 23, 19}};

displacements = {0, 0, 0, 0, -0.0091645, 0.00229398, 0.013342, 0.0250656, -0.0186183, 0.0043011, 0.0272138, 0.0517176, -0.0276138, 0.00588411, 0.0405803, 0.0795059, -0.0342935, 0.00641231, 0.0522328, 0.109954, -0.0357271, 0.00784115, 0.0579424, 0.14704};

stn = Nodes//Length;
Nodes2 = Nodes;
For[i = 1, i <= stn, i++,
 AppendTo[Nodes2[[i]], displacements[[i]]]
 ]
ListContourPlot[Nodes2, Contours -> 20, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 AspectRatio -> 5/3, PlotRange -> All, PlotRange -> Full]
```

The result is as shown in the picture. The left one represents the deformed shape made of triangles and the right one my `ListContourPlot` with highlighted spots where there shouldn't be any color as the region does not exist (refer to the left picture).
I have found a similar problem [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88752/delaunaymesh-in-a-specified-closed-region-creating-a-concave-hull-from-a-set-o/88769#88769), but I don't see how it can be generalized for non `DelaunayMesh` problems (at least with my knowledge). My question is: **How to plot DISCRETE values (in this case displacements) over ONLY a SPECIFIED DISCRETE region?**

[image]

Comment: I get a completely different image from your code and many error messages about invalid access to list elements. Can you revise your example?

Comment: My bad, I had a vector of displacements both in $x$ and $y$ but for the sake of simplicity only included $y$ here. Should be fine now.

Comment: Nice! Now let the answers roll and tell you that you should never ever use `AppendTo` in a `For` loop :)

Comment: :) why is that?

Comment: Very ineffective on large datasets since it copies and reallocates a lot of memory. There are several easier ways to manipulate lists in a more Mathematica-like way: `MapThread[Append, {Nodes, displacements}]` or `Flatten[{Nodes, List /@ displacements}, {{2}, {1, 3}}]`.

Comment: Btw, to already give you a hint what is happening: The problem with your image is, that `ListContourPlot` does not restrict the colors to your regions. It has problems with convex regions and we had a question about the exact same problem recently. Use `Mesh->All` in your `ListContourPlot` and you see that the image goes beyond your cells. If you had a more C-like shape, this would be more visible. Let me try to find the other post about it.

Comment: Here you go: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/162302/187
I would propose to close your question as a duplicate of the other one.

Comment: learning something new every day :) thanks for the AppendTo alternatives, will make sure to use them :) As per ListContourPlot I was aware of the mesh but wanted a way to maybe make a complete region and then define the plot region accordingly. Must say I haven't seen your post from the link you provided before but even now, to be honest, as much as I want to, I don't really understand exactly what the code at the end of the post means.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your cells, you can easily create `MeshRegion`. From this region, you can create a function that tests if a point is inside the region.

What I'm doing is creating your `ListDensityPlot` and in an after step remove all polygons and lines that are not inside your region. I'm not sure how robust this is, but it seems to work

```
ldp = ListContourPlot[MapThread[Append, {Nodes, displacements}], 
   Contours -> 20, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AspectRatio -> 5/3, 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotRange -> Full];
insideQ = RegionMember[MeshRegion[Nodes, Triangle /@ Elements]];

DeleteCases[Normal[ldp], (Line | Polygon)[pts_, ___] /; 
  Not[And @@ (insideQ /@ pts)], Infinity]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For reference, please see my [answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/162302/187). As a side note: the visible white borders have nothing to do with my approach. It is an artifact that is introduced by using `Normal` (which turns a `GraphicsComplex` into a list of graphics primitives). We have several questions and solutions about this here.

You can get rid of them by explicitly including a color for the edges:

```
DeleteCases[
  Normal[ldp], (Line | Polygon)[pts_, ___] /; 
   Not[And @@ (insideQ /@ pts)], 
  Infinity] /. {EdgeForm[], 
   r_?(MemberQ[{RGBColor, Hue, CMYKColor, GrayLevel}, Head[#]] &), 
   i___} :> {EdgeForm[r], r, i}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

See [this post for reference](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2629/187).

Answer (score 3):

You can create an `ElementMesh` and then an `InterpolatingFunction` which you can use for a plot:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
m = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> Nodes, 
   "MeshElements" -> {TriangleElement[Elements]}];
eif = ElementMeshInterpolation[{m}, displacements];


ContourPlot[eif[x, y], Element[{x, y}, m], Contours -> 20, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AspectRatio -> 5/3, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

You could also use the `ElementMeshDeformation` function to create the deformation:

```
ElementMeshDeformation[m, {eif, eif}, 
  "ScalingFactor" -> 1]["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

In this case I used the same deformation in x and y direction.

From version 13.0 onward there is also `VectorDisplacementPLot`:

```
VectorDensityPlot[{eif[x, y], eif[x, y]}, {x, y} \[Element] m]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a completely different approach that circumvents `ListDensityPlot`. I assume you have properly defined your `Nodes`, `Elements`, and `displacements`.

Since you already have nicely constructed cells defined by your "point references" in `Elements`, there is absolutely no reason not to use them. What if we draw a polygon for each cell and color the vertices according to your displacement? The good thing is that inside each polygon, colors are linearly interpolated. That doesn't look as good as in `ListContourPlot`, but the code is very easy to understand so let's give this a try.

A `GraphicsComplex[pts, graphx]` is a way to define points `pts` only once and refer to them by using their position. How handy it is, that you already have exactly this structure. What we need is to turn each `displacement` into a color. Here is a small function that takes an element index and returns a rainbow color:

```
With[{dis = Rescale[displacements]},
 toColor[n_Integer] := List @@ ColorData["Rainbow", dis[[n]]];
 SetAttributes[toColor, {Listable}]
]
```

We need `Listable` because we want to be able to call `toColor[{{1,2,3},...]` and get `{{toColor[1], toColor[2], toColor[3]}, ...}`. That's all. Now look at this

```
Graphics@GraphicsComplex[Nodes, 
  Polygon[Elements, VertexColors -> toColor[Elements]]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Adding lines to the cells is easy too

```
Graphics@GraphicsComplex[Nodes,
  {
   Polygon[Elements, VertexColors -> toColor[Elements]],
   GrayLevel[.2], Line[Elements]
   }
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And maybe a bit of antialiasing if this looks as pixelized on your machine

```
Graphics@GraphicsComplex[Nodes,
  {
   Polygon[Elements, VertexColors -> toColor[Elements]],
   GrayLevel[.2], Opacity[.2], Thick, Line[Elements],
   Thin, Opacity[1], Line[Elements]
   }
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack.

I generate a mesh from the points you have, then subtract it from a rectangle sized as the plot range of `ListContourPlot` to leave a transparent hole and a white mask, then superimposing this mask on the contour plot using `Epilog`:

```
points = MapThread[Join[#1, {#2}] &, {Nodes, displacements}];

mask =
  MeshPrimitives[#, 2] &@
   DiscretizeRegion@
    RegionDifference[
     Rectangle[{-3, -0.5}, {30, 53}],
     MeshRegion[Nodes, Triangle /@ Elements]
    ];

ListContourPlot[
  points, Contours -> 20, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
  AspectRatio -> Automatic,
  Epilog -> {FaceForm[White], EdgeForm[None], mask}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]