# Finding local maxima on a ListPlot graph

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization

Suppose I plot two columns of data from an  ASCII file using the ListPlot function. Now, how can I obtain the coordinates of local maxima of the curve such that the maxima are greater than some lower bound?

Thank you

Comment: Look at `FindPeaks` in the documentation. Or look at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19829/find-the-minima-and-maxima-of-a-list Or try `listy={12,11,4,7,5,5}; lowerbound=3; len=Length[listy]; i=Range[2,len-1]; Join[
If[listy[[1]]>listy[[2]]&&listy[[1]]>lowerbound,{1},{}],
Select[i,listy[[#]]> listy[[#-1]]&&listy[[#]]>listy[[#+1]]&&listy[[#]]>lowerbound&],
If[listy[[len]]> listy[[len-1]]&&listy[[len]]>lowerbound,{len},{}]]` That assumes your lists are sorted on your x coordinates. Test that on every possible input to try to convince yourself that it is correct.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to use FindPeaks but I do not really know how to use it. Since I have to specify sigma, s, and t but I think I just need to specify t which I think specifies the lower bound. I get errors unless I pass values to sigma and s. As you can tell, I know next to nothing in mathematica. I am not sure what Gaussian blurring "sigma" even means. Do you know if there is a more comprehensive documentation out there? I'm not sure if the documentation on the Wolfram website is friendly to a beginner.

Comment: Google wiki gaussian filter returns https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_filter and the second item is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur  Perhaps those and the explanations and pictures will be a more beginner friendly introduction for you

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

SeedRandom[1234];
data = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {20, 2}] // Sort;

Manipulate[
 peaks = data[[FindPeaks[data[[All, 2]],
      sigma, sh, th][[All, 1]]]];
 ListPlot[data, Joined -> True,
  Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[peaks]}],
 {{sigma, 0}, 0, 4, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{sh, 0, "sharpness"}, 0, 4, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{th, 0, "threshold"}, Sequence @@ Flatten[
    {Floor[MinMax[data[[All, 2]]], 0.1], 0.1}],
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]