# How to find the global maximum of a function?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I tried the following but plotting the function clearly reveals that there is a global maximum around $r = 7$  (here $a = 0.53$)

```
FindMaximum [{r^2*(Exp[-(r)/(3 a)]* (27 a^2 - 18 a r + 2 r^2)/(9 a^2))^2 ,
              0 <= r < Infinity}  , {r, 0}]
```

{0.253131, {r -> 0.39222}}

I tried `NMaximum`, `Max`, `MaxValue`, `Maximize`, `FindMaxValue`, `FindMaximum` but nothing works!

*(..I wonder why there are so many maxima finding functions anyway!..)*

Comment: Why don't you do it the calculus way: find those r's that zero the first derivative of the function?

Comment: "(...I wonder why there are so many maxima finding functions anyway!...)" - because some of the functions are intended for local optima, and some of them attempt to find global optima.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find all the local minima/maxima in a range](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5575/how-to-find-all-the-local-minima-maxima-in-a-range)

Answer (score 10):

According to the documentation, don't use floating point numbers when finding global maxima:

```
a = 53/100;
Maximize[{r^2*(Exp[-(r)/(3 a)]*(27 a^2 - 18 a r + 2 r^2)/(9 a^2))^2, 
0 <= r < Infinity}, r] // N

(* {1.73265, {r -> 6.92924}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks! But why is this "//N" important? I am getting some "garbage" if I remove that.

Comment: It's not garbage, it's the exact symbolic solution. The //N converts the exact solution to a floating point number.

Comment: Z I get this - (how is this a "symbolic solution") - {(1/639128961)
 E^(-(200/159)
     Root[-12059037 + 37921500 #1 - 19080000 #1^2 + 2000000 #1^3 &, 
    3]) Root[-12059037 + 37921500 #1 - 19080000 #1^2 + 2000000 #1^3 &,
    3]^2 (75843 - 
    95400 Root[-12059037 + 37921500 #1 - 19080000 #1^2 + 
        2000000 #1^3 &, 3] + 
    20000 Root[-12059037 + 37921500 #1 - 19080000 #1^2 + 
        2000000 #1^3 &, 3]^2)^2, {r -> 
   Root[-12059037 + 37921500 #1 - 19080000 #1^2 + 2000000 #1^3 &, 3]}}

Comment: Also how can I tweak it to tell me all the local maxima and that as a function of "a". Without having to assign any particular value of "a"? (just that a is always some real number)