# Finding the solution for argument of interpolating function for known functional value

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, event-detection

Suppose I want to numerically determine the location of an object falling vertically in a gravitational field from an arbitrary height `h`.  I know that I can use `NDSolve` to get a numerical interpolating function and it's easy enough to plot.  However, I want to find the time when the altitude is zero, i.e., when the object hits the surface of the gravitational body.

I start with something like the following for Earth:

```
sol3[hh_] := Module[{h = hh},
   NDSolve[{r''[t] == -((gg mm)/(re + r[t])^2), r[0] == h, 
      r'[0] == 0} /. {re -> 6.37814 10^6, mm -> 5.9742 10^24, 
      gg -> 6.67430 10^-11}, r, {t, 0, 10000}]
   ];
```

I can plot this and see that the object's altitude reaches zero before `t = 150` using:

```
Plot[Evaluate[r[t] /. sol3[10^5]], {t, 0, 150}, PlotRange -> All]
```

However, I want to know the exact value of `t` when `r[t]` equals to zero.  I am not sure how to procede as I've tried several approaches but to no avail.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "find the time when the altitude is zero" - sounds like a job for `WhenEvent[]`.

Comment: `FindRoot`?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23609/using-findroot-with-an-interpolating-function

Comment: `WhenEvent` example: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42304/finding-the-intersection-of-a-curve-with-an-interpolation-function/42310#42310

Comment: @MichaelE2 - I tried the `FindRoot` option and kept getting errors like "...is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {x}={0.}..."  I haven't tried the `WhenEvent` route yet but can screw around with that a little.

Comment: You'd have to show what you tried, if you want someone to fix the code.  You might be missing a `First` somewhere.

Comment: For instance, `FindRoot[r[t] == 0 /. First@sol3[10^5], {t, 100}]` works for me.

Comment: Yes, yes I was.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@MichaelE2's suggestion was a good one, namely to use `WhenEvent` to handle the root finding.  I couldn't get `FindRoot` to work properly for a solution that depended upon a user's variable argument (i.e., `hh` here) but am guessing that was due to my limited capacities with the code.

The following will output the value of `t` when the object reaches zero altitude:

```
sol4[hh_] := Module[{h = hh},
   Reap[
     NDSolve[{r''[t] == -((gg mm)/(re + r[t])^2), r[0] == h, 
         r'[0] == 0, 
         WhenEvent[r[t] == 0, Sow[t]]} /. {re -> 6.37814 10^6, 
         mm -> 5.9742 10^24, gg -> 6.67430 10^-11}, 
       r, {t, 0, 10000}];
     ][[2, 1]]
   ];
```

So when I enter 100 km for `hh` I get a time of 144.711 seconds, which seems reasonable since we ignore air resistance.

Comment: Additionally, `ParametricNDSolve[]` is convenient for a situation like yours: `With[{re = 6.37814*^6, mm = 5.9742*^24, gg = 6.67430*^-11}, sol3 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{r''[t] == -((gg mm)/(re + r[t])^2), r[0] == h, r'[0] == 0, WhenEvent[r[t] == 0, Sow[t]; "StopIntegration", "DetectionMethod" -> "Interpolation", "LocationMethod" -> "Brent"]}, r, {t, 0, 10000}, h]]`. Then try `Reap[sol3[100000]]`

Comment: `pos[t_] = r[t] /. sol3[10^5]; FindRoot[pos[t] == 0, {t, 140}]` This gives: `{t -> 144.711}`

Answer (score 1):

" I couldn't get FindRoot to work properly ..."
Try this

```
rsol[h_?NumericQ] := 
  r /. First@
NDSolve[{r''[t] == -((gg mm)/(re + r[t])^2), r[0] == h, 
   r'[0] == 0} /. {re -> 6.37814 10^6, mm -> 5.9742 10^24, 
   gg -> 6.67430 10^-11}, r, {t, 0, 10000}] // Quiet

Plot[Evaluate[rsol[10^5][t]], {t, 0, 150}, PlotRange -> All]

FindRoot[rsol[10^5][t] == 0, {t, 140}]

(*   {t -> 144.711}   *)
```

**Edit**  you can also look for h at given t

```
FindRoot[rsol[h][144.7108864471939`] == 0, {h, 90000}, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 6]

(*   {h -> 100000.}   *)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I really wish I had more time to play with Mathematica.  I often have several month droughts while I'm doing my job and then get a few moments every so often to come back and play with it.  So my memory fails me and I feel like I have to re-learn things.