# Fittting data with combination of an unknown number of Gaussians

Tags: fitting

I have data that I want to fit with a constant plus a combination of Gaussians, with their actual number being one parameter of the fit (besides the average and the variance of every one of them).

How can I carry out and test such procedure in *Mathematica*?

If fitting discrete values is not possible, how can implement a series of fits for different number of Gaussians and a selection criteria the best fit?

A representative example of the data:

```
dat = Uncompress@Import["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=VHZ7XJAi"];
ListPlot[dat, PlotRange -> All, PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Please describe your data.

Comment: If the number of Gaussians is a free parameter, wouldn't  the search algorithm will most likely make it diverge?

Comment: It may be helpful to share your code attempts AND representative data, hopefully in a well [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help), so we can quickly see the problem you are facing. Examples of how to share your data [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1351/10397).Please [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) accordingly.

Comment: @rhermans yes, you're right. I know that there are techniques in statistics to avoid such overfitting, I was thinking if there would be something already  implemented in Mathematica.

Comment: @rhermans:  I don't think the number of Gaussians would diverge in the strictest sense; but since each Gaussian has 2 free parameters, a sum of $(n-1)/2$ Gaussians plus a constant will be able to fit a generic set of $n$ data points perfectly.

Comment: I don't think that there's any support for fitting to discrete parameters in Mathematica (though I could be wrong.)  You might consider doing a series of fits to 1, 2, 3, ... Gaussians (which Mathematica can do) and then applying the [Aikaike information criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion) or a similar criterion to pick the best one.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert, don't $n+1$ Gaussians always fit better than $n$ Gaussians? You need to apply some kind of constrain.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert thanks, I was thinking about something like that, but I didn't know about Akaike information criterion.

Comment: @rhermans:  Not if you run out of data points to fit.  For example, you could fit $n$ data points $(x_i, y_i)$ perfectly with $n$ Gaussians by letting them have infinitesimally small width, centering the $i$th Gaussian on $x_i$, and setting its height to be $y_i$.  Adding another Gaussian on top of this wouldn't increase the goodness of the fit.  Allowing the widths of the Gaussians to vary would presumably reduce the number required (though I'm not 100% about the estimate I gave above.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert you are correct. Thanks.

Comment: thanks all for your insights. I see now that the problem is more hard than I was expecting and I have first to understand the statistics behind it before trying to implement in Mathematica. Should I delete the question?

Comment: I also wanted to add that the experimental function `FindFormula` may well be able to do this in some future iteration, depending on how Wolfram develops it.  As of now (v10.2), it appears to be limited to a small number of target functions

Comment: @rhemans the fake data you used are representative of my situation and your answer is definitely useful. I don't have the data close at hand at the moment but I'll add them asap.

Comment: These [answers](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26336/how-to-perform-a-multi-peak-fitting/26338) may be helpful.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### Solution

Following @MichaelSeifert's advice, here is a working solution.

First define a compact expression for a Gaussian

```
g[x_, xo_, σ_, a_] :=  a Exp[-((x - xo)^2/(2 σ^2))] /(σ Sqrt[2 π])
```

To get

```
g[x, xo, σ, Ao]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Creates a list of variables for the $k^{\text{th}}$ term.

```
kvar[k_Integer] := 
 ToExpression@
  Map[StringJoin[#, ToString[k]] &, {"x", "σ", "a"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Generate a model equation to fit $n$ Gaussians using [`Sequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence.html) to place the output of `kvar` as arguments for `g`

```
gmodel[n_Integer] := Sum[
  g[x, Sequence @@ kvar[i]]
  , {i, 1, n}
  ]
```

Generate a list of parameters for the $n$ Gaussian model.

```
gpars[n_Integer] := Flatten@Array[kvar, n]
```

When evaluated these functions look like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Find fit with minimal [*Akaike Information Criterion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion) ( *AIC* ) by calculating a series of fits with 1, 2, ...`maxn` Gaussian, and selecting the fit with the smallest "*AIC*" as defined in the [`NonlinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html) documentation.

```
fitg[data_, maxn_Integer] := MinimalBy[
   Table[
    {#, #["AIC"]}& @ NonlinearModelFit[data, gmodel[n], gpars[n], x]
    , {n, maxn}
    ], Last][[1, 1]]
```

Usage: `fitg[data, maxn]` where `maxn` is the maximum allowed number of Gaussians.

Possibly `fitg[data, Length[data]]`

### Test

Example of data

```
dat = Uncompress@Import["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=VHZ7XJAi"]
```

Find fit with up to 6 Gaussians and plot

```
Show[
 ListPlot[dat, PlotStyle -> Red],
 Plot[Evaluate[Normal[fitg[dat, 6]]], {x, -1, 2}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
fitg[dat, 6]["ParameterTable"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In this case, only three Gaussians were necessary.

Comment: This may need more work if you need to get clever with initial guesses, but as you have not shared your data....

Comment: Very nice.  I'm not sure I could have done it quite so well myself.

Comment: @rhermans thank you for this instructive answer :)

Comment: Please notice that there are things to improve upon here. See [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94294/10397) about why to use indexed variables instead of `ToExpression` . I should have done `kvar[k_Integer] := Through[{xo, σ, a}[k]]` instead.