# What are the requirements for a well behaved indexed variable? Subscript, ToExpression, Downvalue?

Tags: core-language, symbols, index, downvalues, indexed-variable

On writing [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94154/fittting-data-with-combination-of-an-unknown-number-of-gaussians/94158#answer-94158) I needed to call a function, ([`NonlinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html)) with an unknown number of parameters.

We have learned that we should not use [`Subscript`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript.html) for indexing variables because statements such as  [image: Mathematica graphics]  are actually an assignment to `Subscript` not to `x`.

So my solution was to construct a [`String`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/String.html) and then use [`ToExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression.html)

```
kvar[k_Integer] := 
 ToExpression@
  Map[StringJoin[#, ToString[k]] &, {"x", "σ", "a"}]
```

Giving

```
kvar[3]
```

> {x3, σ3, a3}

That is nice as each variable is an actual `AtomQ` and `Symbol` , but generating them from Strings seems not elegant to me.

Another solution would have been to use [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html)

```
kvar[k_Integer] := Through[{x, σ, a}[k]]
```

Giving

```
kvar[3]
```

> {x[3], σ[3], a[3]}

Which is not a `Symbol` nor `?AtomQ`, yet it works just fine for that task in hand. I'm unsure of when this solution could become a problem.

I'm aware of the existence of `Notation` and `Symbolize`, but I'm not sure if that is a nice "good practices" solution.

My questions are:

**What is the recommended and most elegant form of indexed variables?**

**What are the requirements for well behaved variables?**

**Is it ever relevant if the `Head` is `Symbol` or if its `?AtomQ`?**

Comment: Have you looked at `Indexed`?

Comment: @rcollyer `Indexed[x, 3] = 4` gives *Set::write: Tag Indexed in Indexed[x,3] is Protected. >>* How do you propose to use it as indexed variables?

Comment: Sorry. It's intent is slightly different than what you asked for. It represents a symbolic indexed variable, so it would not have a value, itself. I was wondering if its use would serve your purposes, per its [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed.html).

Comment: `We have learned that we should not use Subscript for indexing variables` ... You shouldn't have any problem, provided you don't mix subscripted $x_2$ and non-subscripted $x$ at the same time.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

#### General usage

Here is what I think

- Using strings and subsequently `ToString` - `ToExpression` just to generate variable names is pretty much unacceptable, or at the very least should be the last thing you try. I don't know of a single case where this couldn't be replaced with a better solution
- Using subscripts is also pretty bad and should be avoided, except for purely presentation purposes - as you noted
- For cases when you need to use many generated variables, indexed variables are usually the best way to go. They usually take the form

  ```
  head[index]
  ```

  and can be used im most places where usual variables can be used, particularly in equations or other expressions of symbolic (inert) nature. You need a bit more care with indexed variables, than plain symbols, in particular it is best to ensure that the `index` is either numeric or, if an expression, should be inert in the sense of evaluation (keep the same value always, or no value).
- Sometimes, you can also use the symbols generated by using `Unique[...]`. Usually, they are used as temporary anonymous placeholders in some intermediate transformations, but then you will have to make sure they are destroyed after you no longer need them.

#### Assignments and state

A very important aspect here is whether the variables are intended to be inert symbolic entities, or you plan to store some values in them. Here are a few things to keep in mind:

- Values stored in variables will be stored in different types of rules for symbol variables and indexed variables:

  - For symbol-based variables, these will be in `OwnValues`
  - For indexed variables, these will be in `DownValues`, or sometimes `SubValues`, if you use nested indices.
- Only symbols allow part assignments. So, for example, you can do

  ```
  a = Range[10];
  a[[5]] = 100;
  ```

  but you can't do

  ```
  a[1]=Range[10]; (* Ok by itself *)
  a[1][[5]] = 100 (* Won't work *)
  ```

  This can be a big deal, for some applications
- Only symbols can serve as local variables / constants in `Module`, `Block`, `With`, `Function`, `Pattern`, etc.
- For the case of many variables, indexed variables may be easier to manage, since you have to clear only one symbol.
- To selectively clear a given indexed variable, you have to use `Unset`, not `Clear`:

  ```
   a[1]=.
  ```
- Indexed variables can not be used inside `Compile`, although it may *appear* that they can.
- If you must do assignments to many (indexed) variables, I'd consider using an `Association` instead. This may make it easier from the resource management point of view, since you can store an association in a single variable. An additional bonus is that then, part assignments to particular indexed variables are allowed:

  ```
  assoc = <|a -> {1, 2, 3}, b -> {4, 5, 6}|>;
  assoc[[Key[a], 2]] = 10;
  assoc

  (* <|a -> {1, 10, 3}, b -> {4, 5, 6}|> *)
  ```

#### Notes

As far as I can recall now, being `AtomQ` is not a requirement for most uses for variables. Being a plain `Symbol` is required in some cases, like for local variables in scoping constructs,  or part assignments - as I explained above.

In general, my experience is that most of uses for indexed variables in pure programming context are more or less equivalent to using a hash table. In the context of symbolic manipulations, indexed variables can be quite useful in many ways - they can represent, for example, coefficients for powers in a polynomial, and many other things.

For anything involving programming / transformations, I'd stay away from `Subscript`, `` Notation` ``, `Symbolize`, and all other things that can mix evaluation and presentation aspects. Using them in code is just an invitation for trouble. If you want to format an expression in some way, write special functions which would do that, as a separate stage.

Comment: There is at least one exception I know: `With[{x[1] = 3}, x[1] + x[1] ]` and I was sure I have seen some built-in function like `Integrate` complaining and throwing mysterious errors when using indexed variables, but I cannot recall what exactly the problem was. Then you are stuck with one of the not so favorable solutions.

Comment: @halirutan The `With` example you gave doesn't work for me, gives an error. For `Integrate`, in principle indexed variables should work - if they don't in some cases, I'd say it is a bug.

Comment: Your thorough analysis is much appreciated and its seems from it that  *symbol-based variables* do have at least some advantage. Considering that `Unique` and `Symbol[str]` are basically transforming a `String` into a `Symbol`, is there a deeper reason you reject `ToExpression` so emphatically, other than how not-elegant it looks?

Comment: @rhermans `Unique` works also with no arguments or with a symbol argument, so is not tied to strings. As to `ToString` - `ToExpression` cycles, there are several reasons to avoid them. The general one is that they lead us outside of the symbolic world, and involve parsing, which is bad both for performance reasons and also just because one should avoid parsing as much as possible (for example, it may be unsafe).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Yes, this is what I meant. While you can use indexed variables with `Module` or `Block` (with the restrictions that you have to declare and assign separately), it is simply impossible to do it using `With`. This is what I was referring to since your bullet point about *local variables* seems to indicate that indexed variables cannot be used in `Module`.

Comment: @halirutan I meant a different thing. I meant that you can't use indexed variables as local variables in declarations: `Modile[{a[1]},...]` won't work, as well as `Block`, `With` etc - so, precisely what you noted.

Comment: I think one of the main disadvantages of using `ToExpression` for such purposes is that your code typically will break when putting it into a package (or make use of namespaces (`Contexts`) in any way). The problem is that `ToExpression` generates the new symbols in the current `$Context`, whatever that happens to be -- or a symbol with the same name somewhere in the current `$ContextPath` will be "abused". My experience is that 90% of the problems when turning code into a decent package comes from `ToExpression` (or `Symbol`).

Comment: @AlbertRetey I fully agree, this is an excellent point! This is just one of the evil things that `ToExpression` can bring. But it can, for example, also be that the symbols that `ToExpression` is trying to create, exist in one of the contexts currently on the `$ContextPath`, and have assigned values. Then, again, there will be trouble - and this can be non-obvious.

Comment: Some functions like `Subscript` just cause confusion! I don't see how this function can be useful in some situations! :) I am a beginner and one of my bad pitfalls when I started using *Mathematica* was with this function! :) Maybe it is just good for final formatting an expression!

Comment: Leonid, I missed this question until recently and I am rather perplexed by your opening point: *Using strings and subsequently `ToString` - `ToExpression` just to generate variable names is pretty much unacceptable, or at the very least should be the last thing you try. I don't know of a single case where this couldn't be replaced with a better solution*.  How else do you create bona-fide Symbols?  And surely sometimes those *are* necessary.  halirutan gave the example of `With`, then [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7214/121) issue came up again today, etc.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I just meant that this needs to be reduced to only the cases where this is really needed. Just using `ToExpression` (or `Symbol`) is fine when that is really necessary. But `ToString` followed by `ToExpression` means that you basically leave the symbolic world for strings and then return back, via parsing / symbol construction. In lots of cases, this is not really necessary and can be replaced with something that would not require the serialization / parsing stage. That's all I meant here, really.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Thanks.  +1 now that we cleared that up. :^)

Answer (score 8):

Using `DownValues` enables you to format the display in the subscripted form without using `Notation` and `Symbolize`

```
(Format[#[n_]] := Subscript[#, n]) & /@ {x, σ, a};

kvar[k_] := Through[{x, σ, a}[k]]

kvar[3]
```

[image]

```
kvar[n]
```

[image]

If you will never use a symbolic index then you can restrict the argument of `kvar` to `Integer` as you did originally.

Answer (score 8):

## What are the requirements for well behaved variables?

Functions are not variables, although in most cases, the kernel treats undefined variables and functions identically.  Sometimes it doesn't.  After all, there *are* places in mathematics where the difference between a number and a function is important.

One extreme and undocumented example is `Dt[]`, the total derivative function.  There,`f[1]` is very much different from `f1`.  `f[1]` is a number, the value of `f` at 1, constant by definition of a mathematical function of one variable, while `f1` is not assumed to be constant unless an explicit declaration is made.

```
f[1]          f[1]

Head[f[1]]    f

AtomQ[f[1]]   False

Dt[f[x], x]   f'[x]

Dt[f[y], x]   Dt[y, x] f'[y]

Dt[f[1], x]   0

Dt[f1, x]     Dt[f1, x]

D[f[1], x]    0
```

## What is the recommended and most elegant form of indexed variables?

A very simple method is to make this definition for each indexed variable:

```
x[i_Integer] := x[i] = With[{u = Unique[x]}, Format[u] = Subscript[x, i]; u]
```

Or,

```
 defineIndexedVariable[x_Symbol] := (
    x[i_Integer] := x[i] = With[{u = Unique[x]}, Format[u] = Subscript[x, i]; u]
)
```

It allows negative subscripts, doesn't use `Symbol`, and `Unique[x]` handles `Context` properly, but `InputForm[Array[x,5]]` prints (say) `{x$2136, x$2152, x$2163, x$2164, x$2165}`.  There is no temptation to sometimes write `x[1]` and sometimes write `x$2136`.

Another more complicated method of constructing symbols on the fly is well, not very elegant, and is an example of how complicated things can suddenly collapse into simplicity, but it does avoid repeated string operations and problems with `$Context`. It allows us to write `v[1]` and have it print as `Subscript[v, 1]` (which displays $\text{v}_1$), and have `{InputForm[v[1]], Head[v[1]], AtomQ[v[1]]}` evaluate to `{v⎵1, Symbol, True}`.  `InputForm[Array[v,5]]` prints `{v⎵1, v⎵2, v⎵3, v⎵4, v⎵5}`, and we can sometimes write `v[1]` and sometimes `v⎵1`.

Simply paste this function into your notebook and evaluate it for each indexed symbol.  Each nonnegative integer subscript will evaluate the symbol's function exactly once.  The first version evaluates Context[FUN]<>SymbolName[FUN] every time a new subscript is encountered.

```
defineIndexedVariable[FUN_Symbol] := 
FUN[ix_Integer /; ix ≥ 0] := With[{
   v=Symbol[Context[FUN]<>SymbolName[FUN]<>"⎵"<>ToString[ix]]
},
   Format[v] = Subscript[FUN,ix];
   FUN[ix] = v
]
```

For one symbol, optimize it by hand and specify context explicitly everywhere:

```
FUN`FUN[ix_Integer /; ix ≥ 0] := With[{
   v=Symbol["FUN`FUN⎵"<>ToString[ix]]
},
   Format[v] = Subscript[FUN`FUN,ix];
   FUN`FUN[ix] = v
]
```

Or get the same optimization with this version:

```
defineIndexedVariable[FUN_Symbol] := With[{
   prefix = Context[FUN] <> SymbolName[FUN] <> "⎵"
},
   FUN[ix_Integer /; ix >= 0] := With[{
        v = Symbol[prefix <> ToString[ix]]
    },
        Format[v] = Subscript[FUN, ix];
        FUN[ix] = v
    ]
]
```

The `Context[FUN]` prefix ensures that all of the new symbols will be
in the same context as the function definition.  The `FUN[ix] =` memoizes the function so `Symbol` is called only once for each distinct index, and the `Format[v]` definition is made only once.  The absence of a semicolon after the `FUN[ix] = v` is absolutely essential.

After `defineIndexedVariable[v]`, we get (`OutputForm` on a text terminal)

```
                v
  v[1]           1

  Head[v[1]]    Symbol

  AtomQ[v[1]]   True

  Dt[v[x], x]   v'[x]

  Dt[v[y], x]   Dt[y, x] v'[y]

                Dt[v , x]
  Dt[v[1], x]       1

  Dt[v1, x]     Dt[v1, x]

  D[v[1], x]    0
```

`Information["v"]`:

```
Global`v

v[1] = v⎵1

v[ix$_Integer/;ix$>=0]:=With[{v$=Symbol["Global`v⎵"<>ToString[ix$]]},Format[v$]=Subscript[v,ix$];v[ix$]=v$]
```

Using the standard front end, ??v does not show`v⎵1`.  But `InputForm[Array[x,5]]` prints `{v⎵1, v⎵2, v⎵3, v⎵4, v⎵5}`

Code that printed the above tables:

```
Function[x,{Table["   ",{Length[x]}],HoldForm/@Unevaluated[x],x}, HoldAll][{v[1],InputForm[v[1]],Head[v[1]],AtomQ[v[1]],Dt[v[x],x],Dt[v[y],x],Dt[v[1],x],Dt[v1,x],D[v[1],x]}]//Transpose//TableForm//Print
```

Comment: I'd like to point out a limitation of this method: it still requires the indexed variable to **evaluate** to a symbol so it'll almost always have trouble when evaluation order matters. For example, you still can't define `Function[x[1], x[1]]` after `defineIndexedVariable[v]`.

Answer (score 1):

A kind of recommended form for the indexed variables would be to use `Symbolize` function from the Notation package:

```
Get["Notation`"]
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[\(a \_ 1\)]]
```

after that you can treat a with superscript 1 as a usual symbol. In particular `AtomQ` will give True; you can assign a value to it using `Set`; and `Clear[Subscript]` will not clear your definitions. Also see `FullForm` to convince yourself that it is now a solid symbol.

Note: it will only work if your output settings are Standard

Comment: I would argue that "most recommended" is limited to cases where presentation is more important than code reliability and reusability...

Comment: This is quite reliable. Even though I personally prefer 1D notations. This could considerably increase readability of the code.

Comment: Well, I think it depends on the frontend and the functionality to turn boxes into expressions. Messing with these makes me feel uncomfortable as it makes code too difficult to understand for me, especially when errors occur. But true, it might well work reliable if used correctly and in the scope it is meant to...

Comment: This symbol also have a long alias: `a\[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]1` which has no boxes

Comment: That's what I tried to express: there is much going on under the hood and things become more complicated than they need to. My experience is that code doesn't become more reliable if it is more complicated then necessary. I think it is absolutely OK to use the Notation package if you have need for it but just wouldn't call it "most recommended" for all use cases...

Comment: You just type expression and on the way to the kernel it gets replaced by this monster and then back on the way back. The same as with any other 2D expression. Anyway I edited "Most recommended" as I personally would rather do a[1] just because that's faster.

Answer (score 1):

## A package supporting fairly elegant subscripted symbols, where a subscript can be any invariant atom.

```
In[2]:= newSubscriptedSymbol[x]

Out[2]= x

In[3]:= x[1]

Out[3]= x
         1

In[4]:= newSubscriptedSymbol[y]

Out[4]= y

In[5]:= x[y[Pi]]

Out[5]= x
         y
          Pi

In[6]:= subscriptInformation[x]
         x
x[1]      1     x$142

         x
x[y  ]    y
   Pi      Pi   x$144

In[7]:= subscriptInformation[y]
        y
y[Pi]    Pi   y$143

In[8]:= ??x$144
Global`x$144

Attributes[x$144] = {Protected}

Format[x$144] = Subscript[x, y$143]

MakeBoxes[x$144, FormatType_] ^= Format[Subscript[x, y$143], FormatType]

In[9]:= ??y$143
Global`y$143

Attributes[y$143] = {Protected}

Format[y$143] = Subscript[y, Pi]

MakeBoxes[y$143, FormatType_] ^= Format[Subscript[y, Pi], FormatType]

In[10]:=
```

The above from a text terminal in OutputForm.  Also tested in the front end, where it looks nicer.

```
BeginPackage["newSubscriptedSymbol`"]

newSubscriptedSymbol::usage = "newSubscriptedSymbol[x] defines x[atom] to return a unique protected symbol for each unique atom, that formats as Subscript[x,atom].\n\n"<>
                              "subscriptInformation[x] prints a table of the subscript atom, the formatted symbol, and the unformatted unique symbol."

subscriptInformation::usage = "subscriptInformation[newSubscriptedSymbol[x]] prints a table of the subscript atom, the formatted symbol, and the unformatted unique symbol."

Begin["`Private`"]

newSubscriptedSymbol[x_Symbol] := (
   newSubscriptedSymbol[x] ^= x;
   subscriptInformation[x] := Print[TableForm[Cases[DownValues[x],Verbatim[RuleDelayed][Verbatim[HoldPattern][Verbatim[x][a_]],s_Symbol]->{HoldForm[x[a]], s, InputForm[s]},{1}]]];
   x::notprotected = "newSubscriptedSymbol["<>SymbolName[x]<>"][``]: `` is a symbol, but it is not protected.";
   x[sym_Symbol /; Not[MemberQ[Attributes[sym],Protected]] ] := (Message[x::notprotected,sym,sym]; $Failed);
   x[atom_?AtomQ] := With[{u=Unique[x]},
      Format[u] = Subscript[x,atom];
      Unprotect[x]; x[atom] = u; Protect[x]; Protect[u]; u
   ];
   x::usage = SymbolName[x]<>"[atom] returns a unique protected symbol which formats as Subscript["<>SymbolName[x]<>",atom].\n\n"<>
             "subscriptInformation["<>SymbolName[x]<>"] prints a table of the subscript atom, the formatted symbol, and the unformatted unique symbol.";
   x[___] := (Message[x::usage]; $Failed);
   SetAttributes[x,{ReadProtected,Protected}];
   x
)

newSubscriptedSymbol[___] := (Message[newSubscriptedSymbol::usage]; $Failed)

Protect[newSubscriptedSymbol]

End[]

EndPackage[]
```