# Defining indefinitely many functions

Tags: functions, core-language, custom-notation

Is it possible to define a class of indefinitely many functions `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, ... such that `f1[x]` becomes `x + 1`, `f2[x]` becomes `x + 2`, `f3[x]` becomes `x + 3` and so on.

I want `f25[100]` to produce 125, and `f255555555[333]` to produce 255555888.

I am aware of the following: If I define

```
f[n_][x_] := n + x
```

then `f[1][x]` becomes `x + 1`, `f[2][x]` becomes `x + 2` and so on. 
But, `f[1]` is longer and looks messier than `f1`.

I want my functions names to be `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, ... not `f[1]`, `f[2]`, `f[3]` ....

Comment: "But, f[1] is longer and looks messier than f1." — This is absolutely a terrible justification for doing this and I really hope beginners reading this don't get into such a habit. Not worth wasting time to save 2 characters, IMO.

Comment: Are you interested only in integers or also in Rationals, Reals and Complexes?. A symbolic extension would be also a nice touch. Something like `fail[x]` becoming `x + ail`

Comment: You have demonstrated that you know the correct method for doing what you are interested in doing. Leave it at that and move on.

Comment: Use `Format[f[n_][x_]] := Subscript[f, n][x];` to "prettify" the display.

Comment: @TheToad I agree, it's bad for most intents and purposes, but personally I'd also sometimes like to do something similar. The problem with `f[1]` over `f1` is that `f1` is a symbol, while `f[1]` is a `DownValue` of the symbol `f`. One can do `f1[[3]]=c` but not `f[1][[3]]=c`. +1 to the Q, I've learned about `$NewSymbol` today thanks to it.

Comment: Me be relavant http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94294/10397

Answer (score 16):

Agree with other answers, this is a bad idea (why, precisely do you want to do this?), but in the spirit of encouraging unmaintainable write-once read-never code, here's my entry into the freak show:

```
$NewSymbol = If[StringMatchQ[#, "f" ~~ NumberString], 
                ToExpression[# <> "[x_]=x+" <> StringDrop[#, 1]]] &;

Remove["f*"];

f123[10] + f15[2]

(* 150 *)
```

All sorts of agathokakological connotations and incantations within.

In the words of the G-Man, "Prepare for unforeseen consequences" with any of the answers....

Comment: +1 for showing us `$NewSymbol`

Comment: +1 for showing us "agathokakological" :^)

Answer (score 12):

Just to be clear, I think this is a terrible idea but nevertheless, a question has been posed for which there is a simple answer:

```
ClearAll@fn
SetAttributes[fn, HoldAll]
fn[h_[x_]] /; StringMatchQ[SymbolName@h, "f" ~~ DigitCharacter ..] := 
     First@StringCases[SymbolName@h, 
                       "f" ~~ d : DigitCharacter .. :> x + ToExpression@d]
fn[x___] := x

$Pre = fn
```

Now `f1234[5678]` will behave as you wanted.

Extending this to handle cases when `f1234` already has an existing definition or replacing `f1234[x]` anywhere within an expression is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 6):

In the interest of illustrating why what you've requested might be a bad idea, here's the simplest way I can think of to achieve your goal (there may be a better way):

```
Do[(ToExpression["f" <> ToString[#]][x_] := x + #) &@ic, {ic, 1, 5}]
?f1
?f5
```

[image: output]

It's much messier than the two characters you'd like to save and harder to index programatically, so I'd stick to `f[n][x]`.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the desired look using the [Notation Package](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/guide/NotationPackage.html).

```
<< Notation`

Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[RowBox[{"f", " ", RowBox[{"n_", "[", "x_", "]"}]}]] 
  \[DoubleLongRightArrow] 
  ParsedBoxWrapper[RowBox[{RowBox[{"f", "[", "n_", "]"}], "[", "x_", "]"}]]]
```

which is displayed as

[image: fnx]

when the Notation Palette is used to create the second part of the above code and `\[InvisibleSpace]` (or <kbd>Esc</kbd>is<kbd>Esc</kbd>) is used between `f` and `n_`.

With

```
f[n_][x_] := x + n
```

now

```
f 25[100]
```

or

```
f\[InvisibleSpace]25[100]
```

will both result in
`125`
while the last input is displayed as

[image: f25[100]]

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, this is a bad idea. However, if you only care about the appearance of `f`, then you could so something like this:

```
f // ClearAll;

intF = RowBox[ { RowBox[ { "f", "[", #1, "]" } ], "[", #2, "]" } ] &;
dspF = RowBox[ { "f", #1, "[", #2, "]" } ] &;

f /: MakeBoxes[ f[ n_ ][ x_ ], form_ ] :=
  With[ { ns = ToString @ n, xs = ToString @ x, if = intF, df = dspF },
      TemplateBox[ { ns, xs }, "f",
          InterpretationFunction :> if,
          DisplayFunction :> df
      ]
  ];
```

All this really does is change the appearance of `f[n][x]`. So now you get results that look like this:

[image]

However, it could get tedious to copy and paste the boxed version whenever you want your input to be displayed this way. As an alternative (which I think looks nicer too), you can use `SubscriptBox` instead:

```
f // ClearAll;

intF = RowBox[ { "f", "[", #1, "]" } ] &;
dspF = SubscriptBox[ "f", #1 ] &;

f /: Subscript[ f, n_ ] := f @ n;

f /: MakeBoxes[ f[ n_ ], form_ ] :=
  With[ { ns = ToString @ n, if = intF, df = dspF },
      TemplateBox[ { ns }, "f",
          InterpretationFunction :> if,
          DisplayFunction :> df
      ]
  ];
```

[image]