# Easier way to calculate Taylor remainder in 2nd order series

Tags: matrix, series-expansion

At the moment I have implemented the code for a Taylor 2nd order series for the function in three variables:

$x_3^3+\frac{x_1-x_2}{x_1+x_2}$

The code builds on following expression:

[image]

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Remove["Global`*"]

thetacalc[xtem_, utem_, nn_] := {

n = nn;
xx = Table[Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, n}];
uu = Table[Subscript[u, i], {i, 1, n}];

f1[x_] := ((x[[1]] - x[[2]])/(x[[1]] + x[[2]])) + (x[[3]])^3;
hh = Simplify[D[f1[xx + θ*uu], {xx, 2}]] // MatrixForm;

f2[f_, x_, u_] := 
f + Sum[uu[[j]]*D[f, {xx[[j]]}], {j, 1, n}] + 
1/2*Sum[Sum[uu[[i]]*uu[[j]]*hh[[1, i, j]], {j, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}];

sol2 = FullSimplify[f2[f1[xx], xx, uu]];
uu = utem;
xx = xtem;
subst = 
Flatten[{Table[Subscript[x, i] -> xx[[i]], {i, 1, n}], 
Table[Subscript[u, i] -> uu[[i]], {i, 1, n}]}];
subst2 = Flatten[{Table[Subscript[x, i] -> xx[[i]], {i, 1, n}]}];
diff = f1[xx + uu] - sol2 /. subst;
{sei = NSolve[diff == 0, θ, Reals], diff, FullSimplify[hh] /. subst2, sein = FullSimplify[hh] /. Flatten[{subst, sei}], Eigenvalues[sein[[1]]]}

}

thetacalc[{10, 5, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, 3]
```

The output *(theta, difference-function, H-Matrix [unevaluated],  [evaluated], Eigenvalues)* for x and u as given in thetacalc:

$\tiny 
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 \{\{\theta \to 0.326189\}\} & \frac{10}{(\theta +15)^3}-\frac{1}{360} & \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -\frac{4 \left(\theta  u_2+5\right)}{\left(\theta  \left(u_1+u_2\right)+15\right){}^3} & \frac{2 \left(\theta  u_1-\theta  u_2+5\right)}{\left(\theta  \left(u_1+u_2\right)+15\right){}^3} & 0 \\
 \frac{2 \left(\theta  u_1-\theta  u_2+5\right)}{\left(\theta  \left(u_1+u_2\right)+15\right){}^3} & \frac{4 \left(\theta  u_1+10\right)}{\left(\theta  \left(u_1+u_2\right)+15\right){}^3} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 6 \left(\theta  u_3+1\right) \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -0.00555556 & 0.00295899 & 0 \\
 0.00295899 & 0.0114735 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 6. \\
\end{array}
\right) & \{6.,0.011973,-0.00605506\} \\
\end{array}$

The remainder will be adjusted with a theta between (0,1) from the mean value theorem to equal the original function (at point x with direction vector).
A theta is given if the direction vector u is unequal to null-vector.

I am wondering if one could do this simpler as to avoid manual term calculation like the Hesse-matrix (in my code: hh) or even multiple sums.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: A side note, try avoiding the use of `Subscript` for variables, when you do `Subscript[x, i]=1` you are actually saying `Set` a downvalue to  `Subscript` not to `x`.

Comment: Is is then not at all recommended to use indexed variables like above? For visibility I would like to still use them for not having to use every letter on my keyboard. Could you give me an alternative? Thanks

Comment: Have a read in [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94294/10397).

Answer (score 3):

Probably:

```
p = {x, y, z};
ff[x_, y_, z_] := (x - y)/(x + y) + z^3
hhh = D[ff[x, y, z], {p, 2}] // Simplify
h1 = hhh /. MapThread[Rule, {p, p + t { u1, u2, u3}}] /. 
               Thread[p :> {10, 5, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can get the same result you got with your code with the following (please note that most of the code is just formatting,not sure why you may want that on a function):

```
calc[ff_, p0_, u0_] := Module[{p = {x, y, z}, u = {u1, u2, u3}, c1, c2, t, diff, tval, mt},
  mt = Flatten@MapThread[Rule, {{p, u}, {p0, u0}}, 2];
  c1 = D[ff@p, {p, 1}] // Simplify;
  c2 = D[ff[p + t u], {p, 2}] // Simplify;
  diff = (ff[p + u] - ff[p] - u.c1 - 1/2 u.c2.u) /. mt;
  tval = First@NSolve[diff == 0, Reals];

  (*Output Formatting follows*)
  {tval /. t -> \[FormalT],
   diff /. t -> \[FormalT],
   c2 /. Thread[p :> p0] /. t -> \[FormalT] // MatrixForm,
   c2 /. mt /. tval // MatrixForm,
   Eigenvalues[c2] /. mt /. tval}]
```

Usage

```
f[{x_, y_, z_}] := (x - y)/(x + y) + z^3
calc[f, {10, 5, 1}, {1, 0, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You may want to use formal symbols for `{x, y, z, u1,u2, u3}` to avoid variable scoping issues. Or use `Unique[ ]` if you don't need to display the unevaluated forms nicely

Comment: This is great work for getting a more concise code/module. A higher order generalization would be easier to implement in here as well. Building on this module on could also extend it for optimization.