# I want to plot a list of points with specified t and x[t] coordinates

Tags: plotting

I have this code:

```
Subscript[t, 0] = 0  ;
x[Subscript[t, 0]] = 1  ;
h = 0.2;
For[l = 0, l <= 2, Subscript[t, l + 1] = Subscript[t, l] + h; 
  Print["t[", l, "]= ", N[Subscript[t, l], 2]]; l++];
For[r = 0, r <= 2, 
  x[Subscript[t, r + 1]] = 
   x[Subscript[t, 
     r]] + (Subscript[t, r + 1] - Subscript[t, 
       r])*(x[Subscript[t, r]] + Subscript[t, r]^2); 
  Print["x[t", r, "]= ", N[x[Subscript[t, r]], 2]]; r++];
```

[image: and output is:]

I want to draw  plot  a list of points with specified ti and x[ti] coordinates.

```
ListPlot[Table[{Subscript[t, i], x[Subscript[t, i]]}, {t, 0, 2, 1}], 
 Filling -> Axis]
```

Comment: `ListPlot[Table[{Subscript[t, i], x[Subscript[t, i]]}, {i, 0, 2, 1}], 
 Filling -> Axis]` works. Typo (`i` runs through 0 to 2, not `t`)?

Comment: You should avoid using [`Subscript`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript.html) while defining symbols (variables). `Subscript[x, 1]` is not a symbol, but a compound expression, you expect to do $x_1=2$ but you are actually doing `Set[Subscript[x, 1], 2]` which is to assign a [Downvalue](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102/10397) to `Subscript` and not an Ownvalue to an indexed `x` as you may intend. Read how to [properly define indexed variables here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94298/10397).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Always** avoid using subscripts, they just confuse things.  Instead of defining `Subscript[t,0]=0`, define `t[0]=0`.  Finally, `Do` loops are easier to read and write than `For` loops, which generally come from other programming languages.

Does this do what you were going for?

```
t[0] = 0;
x[0] = 1;
h = 0.2;
Do[
 t[n + 1] = t[n] + h;
 x[n + 1] = x[n] + (t[n + 1] - t[n]) (x[n] + t[n]^2);
 , {n, 0, 3}]
```

To see what you've assigned to `t` and `x`, use this:

```
?x
?t
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[Table[{t[n], x[n]}, {n, 0, 4}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest separating the substance of your computation from the labels/formats. I also suggest searching this site on reasons for avoiding for loops.
For example,

```
fun[n_, h_] := 
 NestList[{#[[1]] + h, #[[2]] + h (#[[2]] + #[[1]]^2)} &, {0, 1}, n]
```

codes your function (barring any error on my part).
Then,

```
TableForm[fun[5,0.2], 
 TableHeadings -> {Range[0, 5], {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(t\), \(n\)]\)",
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(n\)]\)"}}]
ListPlot[fun[5,0.2]]
```

yields:

[image]