# I want to compute the derivative of Black and Scholes option

Tags: finance

Good evening to everybody, my question is about computing the derivative of a Black and Scholes option and to draw it.

### My code is

```
f\[ScriptCapitalD][μ_, σ_, t_] = LogNormalDistribution[μ t, σ Sqrt[t]];

PriceAtEpoch[S0_, μ_, σ_, t_] = S0 Mean[f\[ScriptCapitalD][μ, σ, t]]

PriceAtEpoch[Subscript[S, 0], μ, σ, t + 1] == 
 PriceAtEpoch[Subscript[S, 0], μ, σ, t] Exp[r]

{sol} = Solve[ForAll[{t, Subscript[S, 0]}, %], μ, Reals]

BlackScholesOptionPrice = 
 Assuming[Subscript[S, 0] > 0 && r > 0 && σ > 0 && t > 0 && \[ScriptCapitalK] > 0, 
  Exp[-r t] Expectation[optVal[\[ScriptF] Subscript[S, 0], 
      \[ScriptCapitalK]], \[ScriptF] \[Distributed] 
      f\[ScriptCapitalD][μ /. sol, σ, t]] // FullSimplify]
```

---

So how to compute the derivative (for example with respect to the volatility) for the call option?

---

Thank you for your feedback. I have tried to copy what is written in the book but it didn't work (see below the code)

```
{In[2]:= f = 1/(s_t b (2 pi)^.5) Exp [ - ((Log (s_t) - a^2)/(2 b^2))]


In[9]:= ((0.7071067811865475` E^(-((-a^2 + Log s_t)/(
  2 b^2))))/(b pi^0.5` s_t))

domain [f] = {s_t, 0, ∞} && {a ∈ Reals, b > 0}
 

Out[9]= (0.707107 E^(-((-a^2 + Log s_t)/(2 b^2))))/(b pi^0.5 s_t)

During evaluation of In[9]:= Rule::rhs: Pattern s_t appears on the right-hand side of rule domain[(0.707107 E^(-((-Power[<<2>>]+<<1>>)/(2 b^2))))/(b pi^0.5 s_t)]->{s_t,0,∞}&&{a∈Reals,b>0}. >>

Out[10]= {s_t, 0, ∞} && {a ∈ Reals, b > 0}

In[11]:= V_t = If[s_t > k, s_t - k, 0]

Out[11]= If[s_t > k, s_t - k, 0]

In[12]:= V = \[DoubleStruckE]^(-rT) Expect [V_t, f]

Out[12]= \[DoubleStruckE]^-rT Expect[V_t, (
  0.707107 E^(-((-a^2 + Log s_t)/(2 b^2))))/(b pi^0.5 s_t)]

In[15]:= Value = 
 V /. {a → Log [p] + (r - (σ^2)/2) T, 
   b → σ (T)^.5}

During evaluation of In[15]:= ReplaceAll::reps: {a→T (r-σ^2/2)+Log[p],b→T^0.5 σ} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>

During evaluation of In[15]:= Set::wrsym: Symbol Value is Protected. >>

Out[15]= \[DoubleStruckE]^-rT Expect[V_t, (
   0.707107 E^(-((-a^2 + Log s_t)/(2 b^2))))/(
   b pi^0.5 s_t)] /. {a → T (r - σ^2/2) + Log[p], 
  b → T^0.5 σ}

In[16]:= Value /. {p → 104, k → 100, 
  r → .05, σ → .44, 
  T → 66/365}

During evaluation of In[16]:= ReplaceAll::reps: {p→104,k→100,r→0.05,σ→0.44,T→66/365} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>

Out[16]= Value /. {p → 104, k → 100, 
  r → 0.05, σ → 0.44, 
  T → 66/365}
```

My question is still the same: I want to plot the first derivative of a call/put option.

### Edit

Once again as, because of my inexperience, I have troubles with the code.

I want to compute the derivative of a Black and Scholes option and to plot it. After some iteration here is the code:

---

```
In[10]:= s = LogNormalDistribution[μ, σ]

Out[10]= LogNormalDistribution[μ, σ]

In[11]:= f = 
 1/(s * b (2 pi)^(1/2)) Expectation[ - ((Log (s) - a^2)/(2 b^2))]


During evaluation of In[11]:= Expectation::argmu: Expectation called with 1 argument; 2 or more arguments are expected. >>

Out[11]= Expectation[-((-a^2 + 
   Log LogNormalDistribution[μ, σ])/(
  2 b^2))]/(Sqrt[2] b Sqrt[pi] LogNormalDistribution[μ, σ])

In[12]:= ((0.7071067811865475` E^(-((-a^2 + Log s_t)/(
  2 b^2))))/(b pi^0.5` s_t))

domain [f] = {s, 0, ∞} && {a ∈ Reals, b > 0}
 

Out[12]= (0.707107 E^(-((-a^2 + Log s_t)/(2 b^2))))/(b pi^0.5 s_t)

Out[13]= {LogNormalDistribution[μ, σ], 
  0, ∞} && {a ∈ Reals, b > 0}

In[14]:= V_t = If[s_t > k, s_t - k, 0]

Out[14]= If[s_t > k, s_t - k, 0]

In[15]:= V = \[DoubleStruckE]^(-rT) Expect [V, f]

During evaluation of In[15]:= $RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of \[DoubleStruckE]^-rT. >>

Out[15]= Hold[V = \[DoubleStruckE]^-rT Expect[V, f]]

In[16]:= Value = 
 V /. {a → Log [p] + (r - (σ^2)/2) T, 
   b → σ (T)^.5}

During evaluation of In[16]:= $RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 
  1024 exceeded during evaluation of \[DoubleStruckE]^-rT. >>

Out[16]= Hold[
 Value = V /. {a → Log[p] + (r - σ^2/2) T, 
    b → σ T^0.5}]

In[17]:= Value /. {p → 104, k → 100, 
  r → .05, σ → .44, 
  T → 66/365}

During evaluation of In[17]:= ReplaceAll::reps: {p→104,k→100,r→0.05,σ→0.44,T→66/365} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>

Out[17]= Value /. {p → 104, k → 100, 
  r → 0.05, σ → 0.44, 
  T → 66/365}
```

---

As you see it doesn't work. Is anybody able to tell me what I should do?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: You should not enter 1/2 (which is exact and symbolic) as .5 (which is a machine number). That is not appropriate if you are seeking exact symbolic solutions.

Comment: Don't use underscores in variable names, don't use built-in symbols like Value as variable names, use Rule (entered as `->`) not RightArrow for rules.

Comment: You should avoid using [`Subscript`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript.html) while defining symbols (variables). `Subscript[x, 1]` is not a symbol, but a compound expression, you expect to do $x_1=2$ but you are actually doing `Set[Subscript[x, 1], 2]` which is to assign a [Downvalue](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102/10397) to `Subscript` and not an Ownvalue to an indexed `x` as you may intend. Read how to [properly define indexed variables here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94298/10397).

Comment: https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/STACK/bc-black-scholes.m may or may not be helpful. Quick question: first derivative with respect to which variable (or do you mean the full first derivative, not a partial derivative)?

Answer (score 4):

There are some obvious problems with your formulation .. the main one being that you define `BlackScholesOptionPrice` in terms of a function called `optVal[]` ... and you have not defined the latter. The second major issue is that you are just taking the expectation of a Lognormal random variable, whereas an option is the expectation of a censored Lognormal rv (censored below:  leaving the upside gain).

There is an example in our Springer book, "*Mathematical Statistics with Mathematica*" at pp.70-71, setting up a Black-Scholes model in *Mathematica* from first principles, using the method you want. You can easily modify the example to use inbuilt functions such as `Expectation` that are now available in current versions, which should also work fine. You can download a free copy of the original printed book as a PDF file (or just Chapter 2) over here:

http://www.mathstatica.com/book/bookcontents.html

At the end of the example, it is also noted how to take the derivative that you seek.

---

**Here is a worked example**

Stock pries $S_T$ follow a Brownian motion. As per equation 2.38 above, the distribution model is:

$$\log  S_T\sim N\left(a,b^2\right)  \quad \quad \text{where} \quad 
\begin{align}
 a &= log{S(0)} + \left(r-\frac{\sigma ^2}{2}\right) T \\
 b &=\sigma  \sqrt{T} \\
\end{align}
$$

To keep notation simple, let $S = S_T$.

The value of the option at expiry VT, with a strike of $k$, is:

```
VT = If[S > k, S-k, 0];
```

The value of a call option TODAY is $V0 = e^{-r t} E[\text{VT}]$:

```
V0 = Exp[-r T] Expectation[VT,Distributed[S,LogNormalDistribution[a,b]], Assumptions->k>0]
```

Finally, substitute in for $a$ and $b$, and we have:

```
 optionValue = V0 /. {a->Log[p] + (r-\[Sigma]^2/2) T, b->\[Sigma] Sqrt[T]};
```

All done.

The derivative wrt volatility is:

```
 D[optionValue, \[Sigma]] // Simplify
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried to copy what is mentioned in the book but it didn't work

Comment: You can adopt the method used in the book, replacing say the `Expect` function (from the _mathStatica_ add-on package used in the book) with _Mathematica_'s `Expectation` function (as you were using in your original code ... together with the `LogNormalDistribution`. You just have to define which variable has a LogNormalDistribution, and you are good to go.

Comment: Sorry for my stupid questions. Can you please let me know how I can do that?

Comment: I have added a worked example: just copy and paste

Comment: Thank you Rose. I appreciate your patience! I have plotted the derivative vs the volatility and I see that the shape is strange as it is a bell curve. I was expecting, instead, a sigmoidal function (strictly increasing and with a flex point). I am not convinced of the results. My code is {Manipulate[
 Plot[(E^(-((
    T^2 (2 r + \[Sigma]^2)^2 + 4 Log[k]^2 - 8 Log[k] Log[p] + 
     4 Log[p]^2)/(8 T \[Sigma]^2))) k^(1/2 + r/\[Sigma]^2) p^(
   1/2 - r/\[Sigma]^2) Sqrt[T])/Sqrt[2 \[Pi]], {\[Sigma], 0, 50}], {k,
   0.01, 100}, {p, 0.01, 100}, {T, 0.01, 20}, {r, -0.01, 0.1}]}