# Measuring Temp on a cubical using heat equation with Neumann and Dirichlet boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve 3D heat equation to understand how the temperature varies with time on cubical. i have mixed boundary conditions:
Dirichlet on the bottom surface (constant Temp)
Neumann on all the other surfaces (convection and radiation)

Im using the 3D heat equation, but first i tried to solve for the 1D:

```
op = Derivative[1, 0][u][t, x] - Derivative[0, 2][u][t, x]
BC1 = DirichletCondition[u[t, x] == 873 - Exp[-100 t], x == 0];
BC2 = NeumannValue[-((h*100)/(k 0.56)) - (0.7 sig (100)^4)/(k 0.56) - 
Exp[-100 t], x == 0.3];
uifHeat = 
NDSolveValue[{op == BC2, BC1, u[0, x] == 298}, 
u, {t, 0, 100}, {x, 0, 0.3}];
Plot3D[Evaluate[u[x, t] /. %], {t, 0, 3600}, {x, 0, 0.25}, 
PlotRange -> All]
```

But then i got the next error:

```
The PDE is convection dominated and the result may not be stable. \
Adding artificial diffusion may help
```

I tried the suggested solution - Exp[-100 t] but it didn't help. 
Then i tried to solve it in 3D:

```
k = 25.5;(*W/(m K)*)
sig = 5.67*10^-8;(*W/(m^2 K^4)*)
h = 6.98;(*W/(m^2K)*)
Reg= ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 0.4 && 0 <= y <= 1.4 && 0 <= z <= 0.3, {x, y, z}];
op = Derivative[1,0,0,0][u][t,x,y,z]-Laplacian[u[t,x, y, z], {x, y, z}]
BC1 = DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y, z] == 873, 
z == 0 && 0 <= y <= 1.4 && 0 <= x <= 0.4];
BC2= {NeumannValue[-((h*100)/(k 0.56)) - (0.7 sig (100)^4)/(
 k 0.56), z == 0.3 && 0 <= y <= 1.4 && 0 <= x <= 0.4], 
NeumannValue[-((h*100)/(k 0.56)) - (0.7 sig (100)^4)/(k 0.56),
  x == 0 && 0 <= y <= 1.4 && 0 <= z <= 0.3], 
NeumannValue[-((h*100)/(k 0.56)) - (0.7 sig (100)^4)/(k 0.56),
  x == 0.4 && 0 <= y <= 1.4 && 0 <= z <= 0.3], 
NeumannValue[-((h*100)/(k 0.56)) - (0.7 sig (100)^4)/(k 0.56),
  y == 0 && 0 <= x <= 0.4 && 0 <= z <= 0.3], 
NeumannValue[-((h*100)/(k 0.56)) - (0.7 sig (100)^4)/(k 0.56),
 y == 1.4 && 0 <= x <= 0.4 && 0 <= z <= 0.3]};
uifHeat = NDSolveValue[{op == BC2, BC1, u[0, x, y, z] == 298}, 
u, {t, 0, 100}, {x, y, z} ∈ Reg];
Animate[Plot3D[uifHeat[t, x, y, 0], {x, y, z} ∈ uifHeat["ElementMesh"], 
PlotRange -> {0, 160}], {{t, 10}, 0, 40, 2}, 
SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

This time i got the error:

```
"PDE parsing error of \
{{u$46316-u$46317-u$46318-u$46319-NeumannValue[-49.1575,z==0.3&&0<=y<=\
1.4&&0<=x<=0.4],u$46316-u$46317-u$46318-u$46319-NeumannValue[-49.1575,\
x==0&&0<=y<=1.4&&0<=z<=0.3],u$46316-u$46317-u$46318-u$46319-\
NeumannValue[-49.1575,x==0.4&&0<=y<=1.4&&0<=z<=0.3],u$46316-u$46317-u$\
    46318-u$46319-NeumannValue[-49.1575,y==0&&0<=x<=0.4&&0<=z<=0.3],u$\
    46316-u$46317-u$46318-u$46319-NeumannValue[-49.1575,y==1.4&&0<=x<=0.4&&\
0<=z<=0.3]}}. Inconsistent equation dimensions"
```

I can't figure what is the problem

Comment: Greetings! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: You should avoid using [`Subscript`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript.html) while defining symbols (variables). `Subscript[x, 1]` is not a symbol, but a compound expression where `Subscript` is an operator without built-in meaning. You expect to do $x_1=2$ but you are actually doing `Set[Subscript[x, 1], 2]` which is to assign a [Downvalue](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102/10397) to the oprator `Subscript` and not an Ownvalue to an indexed `x` as you may intend. Read how to [properly define indexed variables here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94298/10397)

Comment: Sorry for all the mistakes i fixed it i hope. it's my first time. thank you for your fast response and your desire to help

Comment: Concerning your first lock of code `Plot3D[Evaluate[u[x, t] /. %], {t, 0, 3600}, {x, 0, 0.25}` should be `Plot3D[Evaluate[%[x,t]], {t, 0, 100}, {x, 0, 0.25},` . Then it works despite the message "...convection dominated...". Concerning the second block, there are still problems ...

Comment: Concerning the second block, you can't use as Neumann condition BC2 a `List` of `NeumannValue[...]`. BC2 must be a single `NeumannValue[]`, in your case `BC2 = NeumannValue[-((h*100)/(k 0.56)) - (0.7 sig (100)^4)/(k 0.56), 
(z == 0.3 && 0 <= y <= 1.4 && 0 <= x <= 0.4) || (x == 0 && 
     0 <= y <= 1.4 && 0 <= z <= 0.3) || (x == 0.4 && 0 <= y <= 1.4 && 
     0 <= z <= 0.3) || (y == 0 && 0 <= x <= 0.4 && 
     0 <= z <= 0.3) || (y == 1.4 && 0 <= x <= 0.4 && 0 <= z <= 0.3)]` Then NDSolve works and gives a `InterpolatingFunction[...]`

Comment: Concerning the end of the second block : `Animate[Plot3D ...` . What you want to do is not clear : `Plot3D` is for plotting 2 dimensionnal functions, but `{x,y,z} element of ...` determine a tree dimensionnal space. One thing more : implement `Animate` only when your Plot will be OK.

Comment: Thank you andre, you helped me a lot. I use animate to check how the temperature changes with time on different planes, if you know a better way please share.

Comment: To see the function, I suggest you do for example for the plan at z=0.15 : `Labeled[Plot3D[uifHeat[#, x, y, 0.15], {x, 0, 0.4}, {y, 0, 1.4}], "t=" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[0, 100, 20]` . I don't know what you are waiting for physically.

Comment: 3D representation of isotherms 860K and 865K : `Labeled[ContourPlot3D[
    uifHeat[#, x, y, z], {x, 0, 0.4}, {y, 0, 1.4}, {z, 0, 0.3}, 
    Contours -> {860, 865}], "t=" <> ToString[#]] & /@ 
 Range[0, 100, 20]` .Computing time = several minutes