# Creating sublists

Tags: list-manipulation

I got this example in Mathematica references.

```
v = ToExpression["a" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[1,44]
```

Could someone explain to me the function of the term #? There is another way to get the same result?

And how could I relate v list with another list of 44 lists in it one by one?

```
lists={{3},{54},...,{46}}
```

The result would be something like:

```
a1=3
a2=54
...
a44=46
```

Comment: Funtion and Slot.

Comment: represents the first argument supplied to a pure function

Comment: Things are not so easy when  `a1`, `a2`... have `OwnValues`, why not use `a[1]`?

Comment: For `#`, search [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616).

Comment: Also related: [(94294)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94294/what-are-the-requirements-for-a-well-behaved-indexed-variable-subscript-toexpr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it help?

```
a = RandomInteger[9, 44]
(Evaluate[Symbol["a" <> ToString[#]]] = a[[#]]) & /@ Range[44]

{a[[3]], a3}
{a[[11]], a11}
```

> {0, 9, 7, 5, 9, 6, 6, 6, 1, 4, 4, 9, 3, 6, 1, 8, 2, 9, 8, 6, 1, 1, 1, 
>   4, 7, 9, 6, 9, 0, 5, 7, 5, 8, 2, 4, 1, 1, 4, 3, 0, 4, 7, 6, 0}
>
> {7, 7}
>
> {4, 4}

Comment: I don't get it. Is it not working? Can you put a small example of your input and output.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Check the modified answer.