# How to map a function over a dimension in a matrix?

Tags: map

I have a function `g[x,r]` yielding a `3x1` vector, where `x` is a `9x1` vector and `r` is a `3x1` vector.

Now I define multiple `r` by:

```
R = Array[Subscript[r, ##] &, {3, N}]
```

Now I want to construct

```
G[x_,R_] := {g[x,r_1],g[x,r_2],g[x,r_3],...,g[x,r_N]}
```

Where `r_i` is the ith column vector of `R`, and `G` should be a `3Nx1` vector. I reckon I would have to use `Map` or `Outer`, but cannot see how.

Comment: First, notice that the character "_" in Mathematica is the function [`Blank`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html) which is a pattern object that can stand for any Wolfram Language expression.

Comment: You should avoid using [`Subscript`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript.html) while defining symbols (variables). `Subscript[x, 1]` is not a symbol, but a compound expression where `Subscript` is an operator without built-in meaning. You expect to do $x_1=2$ but you are actually doing `Set[Subscript[x, 1], 2]` which is to assign a [Downvalue](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102/10397) to the oprator `Subscript` and not an Ownvalue to an indexed `x` as you may intend. Read how to [properly define indexed variables here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94298/10397)

Comment: With respect to *"map a function over a dimension"*, probably you should look at [`MapAt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html)

Answer (score 2):

Switch your indices on the array command so you have 3x1 row vectors

```
    rr = Array[f[##] &, {10, 3}];
    rr // MatrixForm
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 f(1,1) & f(1,2) & f(1,3) \\
 f(2,1) & f(2,2) & f(2,3) \\
 f(3,1) & f(3,2) & f(3,3) \\
 f(4,1) & f(4,2) & f(4,3) \\
 f(5,1) & f(5,2) & f(5,3) \\
 f(6,1) & f(6,2) & f(6,3) \\
 f(7,1) & f(7,2) & f(7,3) \\
 f(8,1) & f(8,2) & f(8,3) \\
 f(9,1) & f(9,2) & f(9,3) \\
 f(10,1) & f(10,2) & f(10,3) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Then just run Map[ ] over it and Flatten[ ] the results

```
    g[x, y_] := {1, 2, 3}
    Map[g[x, #] &, rr] // Flatten
```

$$\{1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3\}$$

Comment: You can also use `g[x, #] & /@ Transpose[R]` with OP's definition of `R`. `Transpose` does the flipping.