# Explanation of the following code which taken from mathworld

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, polynomials, mathworld

Can anyone explain to me how does this code function?

```
AdomianPolynomials[u_, F_, o_] := CoefficientList[
   ExpandAll[
    Series[
     F[
      Sum[λ^k u[k], {k, o}]
      ],
     {λ, 0, o}
     ]
    ], λ]
```

The original code was get from noteboook of this website http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AdomianPolynomial.html

Comment: Hi and Welcome! Make the most of Mma.SE by taking the [tour] now. It will help us to help you if you write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned. Why not choosing a meaningful name?

Comment: There are **[things to do after your question is answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** the best one. Participation is essential for the site, please come back to do your part tomorrow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Sum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html), evaluates the sum  $\sum_{k=0}^{o}{\lambda^k\,u(k)}$

```
With[{o = 3},
 Sum[λ^k u[k], {k, o}]
 ]
```

> ```
> λ u[1] + λ^2 u[2] + λ^3 u[3]
> ```

[`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series.html), generates a power series expansion for $F(\sum_{k=0}^{o}{\lambda^k\,u(k)})$ about the point $0$ to order $(\lambda-0)^o$.

```
With[{o = 3},
 Series[F[Sum[λ^k u[k], {k, o}]], {λ, 0, o}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[`CoefficientList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientList.html), gives a list of coefficients of powers of $\lambda$ in the previos expression, starting with power 0.

[`ExpandAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpandAll.html), expands out all products and integer powers in any part of the expression in the argument.

```
With[{o = 3},
 CoefficientList[
  ExpandAll[
   Series[F[Sum[λ^k u[k], {k, o}]], {λ, 0, 
     o}]], λ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Follow the links for the documentation.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the explanation and reply. Sorry for the late reply.  Let's say if i has a function of F(u)=u^3, and given that u= Summation of Subscript[u, n] from n=0 to 5, my code will be

Comment: In theory, i know that it will become --- (subscript[u,0])^3+3 [Subscript[u, 0]]^2 Subscript[u, 1]+ 3 [Subscript[u, 0]]^2 Subscript[u, 2]+3 Subscript[u, 0] {Subscript[u, 1]}^2

Comment: First, you should avoid using [`Subscript`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript.html) while defining symbols/variables ([Read here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94298/10397)). Second, I don't understand what you are saying/asking. If my answer resolves your original question, [read this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) if you have other different questions, you should ask a new question and [not move the goalpost](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1808/10397). In any case, have you tried yourself? you should show due diligence!

Comment: sorry for that, i had pressed wrongly and it submitted the incomplete sentences. I will try to retype it in a complete form. and with the coding.