# How to recall set variables in simple Product[] and Sum[] functions?

Tags: functions, numerics, variable-definitions

I'm new to *Mathematica* but have been trying to write a code that will define new variables based off of variables preset by a user.

I'm allowing them to define a variable `pij` where $i=3,...,(n-1)$ (where $n$ is also specified by the user) and $j=0,1,2,3$.

i.e, 
$p23=1/5$, $p42=4$ etc;

I would like to define a new variable,

```
p20 = Sum[Product[pij, {i, 2, (n - 1), 1}], {j, 1, 3, 1}]
```

where it would recall the variables set beforehand to perform the sum and product calculations. Any tips?

Comment: You can define functions that remember their values. See, for example http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html

Comment: Welcome! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: There are **[things to do after your question is answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** the best one. Participation is essential for the site, please come back to do your part tomorrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you are after indexed variables. You may want to see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/10397) and follow the link for [general discussion about "indexed variables"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94294/10397).

Basically instead of using a *Ownvalues* for a collection of different symbols you use *Downvalues* for a single symbol. In practice that implies that your $p23=1/5$ translates to `p[2,3]=1/5` instead of `p23=1/5`.

For example:

```
p[2, 3] = 1/5;
p[4, 2] = 4;
p[2, 2] = π;
p[3, 1] = x;

p[2, 0] = Sum[Product[p[i, j], {i, 2, 4, 1}], {j, 1, 3, 1}]
```

> ```
> 4 π p[3, 2] + x p[2, 1] p[4, 1] + 1/5 p[3, 3] p[4, 3]
> ```

For an advanced understanding you could read [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102/10397) (thanks to comment by  @jjc385), the documentation for [Symbol Handling](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SymbolHandling.html) and for [Manipulating Value Lists](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ManipulatingValueLists.html) and try to familiarize yourself with the differences between *OwnValues*, *DownValues* and *UpValues*.

Comment: Perhaps useful to OP:  [A fairly readable explanation of OwnValues and DownValues](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102/11035).

Comment: Thank you! Just made the appropriate additions to my code and it has worked perfectly! I'll do my reading, appreciate it alot!

Comment: @Nyika  I'm happy to help, and glad you appreciate it. There is a way to return the favour, not to me, but to the community. As you receive give back, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes. Did something cool or pedagogical? Share what you have learned! And next time, as I wrote in the other comment, do wait a day before accepting answers to encourage other people with better ideas to write their own approach and solution to your problem..