# VectorPlot3D of the Electric Field E as Determined from the Potential V

Tags: plotting, output-formatting, traditional-form

I am new to *Mathematica* and I am trying to create the electric field $F$ from the electric potential $V$ (using arbitrary distances) and then plot the subsequent vector graph to show that the electric field is always pointing away from the point source.

So far I have:

```
Clear["Global`*"]

(* Creating the Vector Potential V using the Blank operator *)

V[p_, r_] = q/Times[4*Pi*ϵ*Norm[r - p]];
V[{Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[y, 1], Subscript[z, 1]}, {x, y, z}] // 
  TraditionalForm;

(* Creating the Electric Field F using the derivative of the Vector \
Field V *)

F[{x1_, y1_, z1_}] = -D[V[{x1, y1, z1}, {x, y, z}], {{x, y, z}}] /. 
    Derivative[1][Abs][x_] :> x/Sqrt[x^2] // TraditionalForm;

(* Setting the charge q and the constant ϵ *)

q = 1; ϵ = 1;

(* Creating the VectorPlot3D *)

v = VectorPlot3D[F[{1, 1, 1}], {x, -6, 6}, {y, 0, 4}, {z, -4, 4}, 
  VectorStyle -> "Arrow3D", VectorPoints -> 5, 
  VectorScale -> {0.3, Scaled[0.3]}]
```

**But when I run this I don't get any graph.**

I've even found an example on [Mathematica](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v8/ref/VectorPlot3D.html) that doesn't work when I try to run it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Just remove `// TraditionalForm` from the definition of `F`.  (`TradtionalForm` is meant for output only, not for something that will be used later in a computation.)

Comment: @rhermans I know how the site works. I just don't ask questions very often, so no need to log in.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution:

**Do not mix functions that are meant for display with your mathematical definitions.**

### Explanation

One must leave [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm.html), [`Subscript`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript.html) [`TableForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TableForm.html) and other forms of [Formatted Output](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FormattedOutput.html) for display only and avoid them for programming mathematical definitions.

The [`TraditionalForm` Reference Information](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TraditionalFormReferenceInformation.html) documentation explains:

> [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm.html) differs from [`StandardForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StandardForm.html), the default format for
>   input and output. It is important to understand that `TraditionalForm`
>   expressions cannot always be provided as unambiguous input to the
>   Wolfram System. Therefore, while `StandardForm` is an input format and
>   an output format, `TraditionalForm` is primarily intended as an output
>   format.

Furthermore, one should also avoid using [`Subscript`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript.html) while defining symbols (variables). `Subscript[x, 1]` is not a symbol, but a composite expression where `Subscript` is an operator without built-in meaning. For instance, one could expect to do $x_1=2$, but you are actually doing `Set[Subscript[x, 1], 2]` which is to assign a [Downvalue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102/10397) to the oprator `Subscript` and not an *Ownvalue* to an indexed `x` as you may intend. Read how to [properly define indexed variables here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94298/10397)

### Your code for programming the maths

```
V[p_, r_] = q/Times[4 π ϵ Norm[r - p]];
F[{x1_, y1_, z1_}] = -D[V[{x1, y1, z1}, {x, y, z}], {{x, y, z}}] /. Derivative[1][Abs][x_] :> x/Sqrt[x^2];

With[{q = 1, ϵ = 1},
 v = VectorPlot3D[
   F[{1, 1, 1}]
   , {x, -6, 6}
   , {y, 0, 4}
   , {z, -4, 4}
   , VectorStyle -> "Arrow3D"
   , VectorPoints -> 5
   , VectorScale -> {0.3, Scaled[0.3]}
   ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Your code for display only

```
TraditionalForm[
 V[{Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[y, 1], Subscript[z, 1]}, {x, y, z}]]
```

[image]

```
TraditionalForm[
 F[{Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[y, 1], Subscript[z, 1]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect!