# How do I get Mathematica to recognize this simplification? (ReplaceAll pattern rule)

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement, summation, rule

I want *Mathematica* to understand this
$$(\sum_{k=0}^n a_k)(\sum_{j=0}^n b_j)  = (\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^n a_k b_j)$$
I have tried this

```
exprr1 = Sum[Subscript[a, k], {k, 0, n}] * 
Sum[Subscript[b, j], {j, 0, n}]

rules = {Sum[Subscript[a, k], {k, 0, n}]*
Sum[Subscript[b, j], {j, 0, n}] :> 
Sum[Subscript[a, k]*Subscript[b, j], {k, 0, n}, {j, 0, n}]}

exprr1 /. rules
```

**Now this works. The problem is that when I try**

```
rules = {Sum[Subscript[d, k], {k, 0, n}]*
Sum[Subscript[e, j], {j, 0, n}] :> 
Sum[Subscript[d, k]*Subscript[e, j], {k, 0, n}, {j, 0, n}]}
```

This does not work.

**I want Mathematica to understand that no matter what the variable in the summation, and no matter what the index variable, the simplification/rules should work.**

How do I do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour] so you learn the basic rules of the site. Once you gain enough reputation by making [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) you will be able to vote up and down both questions and answers. Thanks for accepting my answer, but in the future may be a good idea to wait 24hours for other answers before [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the best one for you. Read [*"What to do when someone answers"*](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers),

Comment: I don't understand why you would consider the right-hand side of the equation a simplification.  The left-side takes $2(n+1)+1$ operations and the right-hand side would take $(n+1)^3$ operations.  What am I missing?

Comment: @JimB , I wanted to know how I would make Mathematica recognize things or put things in the way I want it too. You are right, it is not necessarily a simplification in this case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Answer

You should use [`Blank`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html), a pattern object that can stand for any Wolfram Language expression, usually written as `_`. [Learn about Patterns here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Patterns.html).

```
rules2 = {
  Times[
    Sum[
     Subscript[d_, k_]
     , {k_, m_, n_}
     ],
    Sum[
     Subscript[e_, j_]
     , {j_, m_, n_}
     ]
    ]
   :>
   Sum[
    Times[
     Subscript[d, k],
     Subscript[e, j]
     ]
    , {k, m, n}
    , {j, m, n}
    ]
  }

exprr1 /. rules2
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Try to think about the patterns in [`FullForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html). Indentation is only for readability.

### Side note about using `Subscript`

By the way, not the source of your problem, but you should avoid using [`Subscript`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript.html) while defining symbols (variables) for anything other than nice display. `Subscript[x, 1]` is not a symbol, but a composite expression where `Subscript` is an operator without built-in meaning. You expect to do $x_1=2$ but you are actually doing `Set[Subscript[x, 1], 2]` which is to assign a [Downvalue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102/10397) to the oprator `Subscript` and not an Ownvalue to an indexed `x` as you may intend. Read how to [properly define indexed variables here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94298/10397).

To see other basic syntax issues please do [read this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/10397).