# If I have numbered elements, I there a simple way to put them in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, sets

I've defined manually 32 elements as `w1`, `w2`, `w3`,..., `w32`. Is there a simple way to put them in a list rather that write `B={w1, w2, ..., w32}`? Like a *list making function* that understands some indexes? (here, each `wi` is itself a list, `i=1,...,32` )

Comment: Use [`indexed variables`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html).  `B = Array[w, 32]`

Comment: @BobHanlon So I have to relabel the elements as `w[1]`, `w[2]`, etc. ?

Comment: you could use    Table[Symbol["w" <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, 32}]

Comment: Yes. Use `Edit | Find | Replace All`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Names[x]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Names.html) to get all the symbols that match the string or pattern argument.

If you want the names

```
B = Names["w*"]
```

or if you want the content you can use [`Symbol`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Symbol.html) or [`ToExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression.html)

```
B = ToExpression /@ Names["w*"]
```

But ultimately the  answer is to use indexed variables as noted by *Bob Hanlon*.

Read [**the documentation**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html) and this [**Q&A**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94294/10397) that comments of the use of string-based variables names, as the comment by RMMA.