# Naming indexed output streams

Tags: streams, indexed-variable

I need to write into multiple files in a [`Do`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do.html) loop. 
Hence, I tried to open multiple streams:

```
Do[  Symbol[StringJoin["S", ToString[i]] ] = 
  OpenAppend[StringJoin["sf", ToString[i]], 
   FormatType -> OutputForm       ], {i, 1, 10}]
```

But this gives errors like:

> ```
> Set::write: Tag Symbol in Symbol[S1] is Protected.
> Set::write: Tag Symbol in Symbol[S2] is Protected.
> ```

What is the correct way to name the indexed output streams in a `Do` loop ?

Comment: Probably you should read this question:" [What are the requirements for a well behaved indexed variable?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94294/10397)"

Comment: Also, check `Attributes[Set]`, it includes `HoldFirst`, so the left hand side of `=` (`Set`) is held.

Comment: By the way, welcome to Mma.SE!  start by **taking the [tour] now**. It **helps us to help you** when you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3). You can always [edit](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) if improvable, to show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: @rhermans Thanks  for your reply ... Instead of joining strings now I am naming the output streams with subscripts -- Subscript[ S , i ]  and it's working !!

Comment: You should avoid using [`Subscript`](https://goo.gl/sa5ME8) while defining symbols (variables). `Subscript[x, 1]` is not a symbol, but a composite expression where `Subscript` is an operator without built-in meaning. You expect to do $x_1=2$ but you are actually doing `Set[Subscript[x, 1], 2]` which is to assign a [Downvalue](https://goo.gl/c5z1S2) to the oprator `Subscript` and not an Ownvalue to an indexed `x` as you may intend. Read how to [properly define indexed variables here](https://goo.gl/yj1VuQ)

Comment: I can do it in multiple ways now:  indexed variables like S[i] are working for naming the output streams.   Also,    the same can be achieved with SetAttributes which I am explaining in my answer below.

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Array[
  (filehandle[#] = OpenAppend[StringTemplate["File``.txt"][#]]) &
  , 10];

?filehandle
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Close /@ Array[filehandle, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using SetAttributes firstly I defined func:

```
SetAttributes[func, HoldFirst]
func[s_, i_] := ( 
  s = OpenAppend[StringJoin["data", ToString[i], ".dat"], 
    FormatType -> OutputForm]  )
```

Then finally data can be written into files data1.dat and data2.dat as:

```
Do[Write[func[s, i], i, "\t", i + 10], {i, 1, 2}]
```

Comment: Why do you want to do `s = OpenAppend[...` ?

Comment: @rhermans : since I am using s in Write command within Do loop ... Will be good to  see alternative ; but this works fine for this toy example ....

Comment: I don't think it makes sense, you are assigning the output of `OpenAppend` to the variable `s`, and then overwriting that value at each iteration.