# How to automatically define a time dependent array of a given dimension in mathematica

Tags: differential-equations

I am looking for a way to generate time-dependent arrays of variable dimensions in Mathematica. For example, if I want an array with 15 variables

```
x={x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x4[t], x5[t], x6[t], x7[t], x8[t], x9[t], 
 x10[t], x11[t], x12[t], x13[t], x14[t], x15[t]}.
```

or

```
y={{y11[t],y12[t]},{y21[t],y22[t]}}
```

is thr a way to automate this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Array[Symbol["x" <> ToString @ #][t] &, 15]
```

> {x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x4[t], x5[t], x6[t], x7[t], x8[t], x9[t], 
>    x10[t], x11[t], x12[t], x13[t], x14[t], x15[t]}

```
Array[Symbol[StringJoin["y", ToString /@ {##}]][t] &, {2, 2}]
```

> {{y11[t], y12[t]}, {y21[t], y22[t]}}

As rhermans pointed out, a better approach  is

```
Array[x[##][t], 15]
```

> {x[1][t], x[2][t], x[3][t], x[4][t], x[5][t], x[6][t], x[7][t], 
>    x[8][t], x[9][t], x[10][t], x[11][t], x[12][t], x[13][t], x[14][t], 
>    x[15][t]}

and

```
Array[y[##][t], {2,2}]
```

> {{y[1, 1][t], y[1, 2][t]}, {y[2, 1][t], y[2, 2][t]}}

If you want `x[1]` to appear as `x1`, say, you can use `Format`:

```
Format[x[a_]] := Symbol["x" <> ToString[a]]
Array[x[##][t] &, {5}]
```

> {x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x4[t], x5[t]}

or

```
Format[y[a__]] := Subscript[y, a]
Array[y[##][t] &, {2, 2}] // TeXForm
```

> $ \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  y_{1,1}(t) & y_{1,2}(t) \\
>  y_{2,1}(t) & y_{2,2}(t) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: So you disagree with @LeonidShifrin  that says *"Using strings and subsequently `ToString` - `ToExpression` [or `Symbol`] just to generate variable names is pretty much unacceptable, or at the very least should be the last thing you try. I don't know of a single case where this couldn't be replaced with a better solution"* in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94294/10397) ?

Comment: @rhermans, very good point:)  `Array[x[##][t] &, 15]` would also look much cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94294/10397) I would go for

```
Through@Array[x, 15][t]
```

and

```
Through@Flatten[Array[y, {2, 2}]][t]
```

or

```
Array[x[#][t] &, 15]
```

and

```
Array[y[#1, #2][t] &, {2, 2}]
```

or as suggested by @kglr, very elegant.

```
Array[y[##][t] &, {2, 2}]
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer without using strings, you can change the structure slightly:

```
x[n_] := Array[x[#, t] &, n]
```

Now you have:

```
x[5]
{x[1, t], x[2, t], x[3, t], x[4, t], x[5, t]}
```

This has the advantage that you can refer to the whole collection of functions using x (with one argument) and can refer to each individual function using x[i,t] (with two arguments). For the 2D case:

```
y[n_] := Array[y[#1, #2, t] &, {n, n}]
```