# I want to write $ k = \{k1,k2,k3,...,kn\} $. How could I do this?

Tags: list-manipulation

When I write `k = {k1, k2, k3, k4, k5}`, it is ok. But I Want a general form, like `k = {k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, ..., kn}` how could I do this?

Comment: `Array[Symbol@StringJoin["k", ToString@#] &, 5]`

Comment: It would be more flexible to use an [`indexed variable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html):

`Clear[k];

kk = Array[k, 5]`

Comment: What are trying to achieve?

Comment: Have a look on this question about [requirements for a well behaved indexed variable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94294/10397)