# How to fit multiple Gaussian peaks to data

Tags: list-manipulation, probability-or-statistics, data, data-structures

How would I fit [this data](http://pastebin.com/aEJAdUuX) with Gaussian Peaks? I have tried various codes but none have even worked. Note: If I do Log[data], the peaks are more visible

(I have tried the method from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26336/how-to-perform-a-multi-peak-fitting?rq=1) but it got many errors)

Comment: @shrx It did not work, I literally copied and pasted the code and made sure my data was correct format. It works for fake data though which was a smaller size

Comment: Please post your code and an example of your data - what errors did you get?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0G4Nrfci This is my code which worked (the data is faked), but as soon as I replace 'data' with real data from here http://pastebin.com/aEJAdUuX, it shows many errors. Just copy and paste my code and you will see

Comment: Your data is very noisy, and I don't see any gaussian peaks other than the large spike near the end of the data. How many peaks do you expect to be there?

Comment: @shrx I don't know how many peaks there are, I'm trying to find that out. Though they are definitely Gaussian

Comment: @shrx I'm willing to try anything at this point, nothing is working (well that's the only code I found which doesn't have many initial assumptions)

Comment: @shrx oh right, the data should be Log[data], the peaks are more visible that way

Comment: What are these data from, if I may ask?

Comment: @OleksandrR. physics experiment

Comment: How descriptive...

Comment: @OleksandrR.it's a cyclotron experiment, the detector measures the number of particles every cycle

Answer (score 6):

Your provided data is very noisy. You can get more information from it if you filter it first.
I will apply a [`LowpassFilter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LowpassFilter.html) and a logarithmic transform on the $y$ values, and scale down the $x$ values. This usually helps the fitting algorithm.

```
datat = Transpose[{#[[All, 1]]/1500, 
     Log10[LowpassFilter[#[[All, 2]], .1]]} &@data];
ListPlot[datat, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now, you can perform the multi-peak fitting process from the [linked discussion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26336/how-to-perform-a-multi-peak-fitting).

It's up to you to decide which peaks are signal and which are artifacts. I am providing here the solution with 4 peaks.

```
With[{n = 4}, 
 resfunc = 
  peakfunc[A[#], μ[#], σ[#], x] & /@ Range[n] /. 
   model[datat, n][[2]]]
(* copied from @Silvia's answer with slight modifications *)
Show@{Plot[Evaluate[resfunc], {x, -5, 10}, 
   PlotStyle -> ({Directive[Dashed, Thick, 
         ColorData["DarkRainbow"][#]]} & /@ 
      Rescale[Range[Length[resfunc]]]), PlotRange -> All, 
   Frame -> True, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 700], 
  Plot[Evaluate[Total@resfunc], {x, -5, 10}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red, Opacity[.5]], PlotRange -> All, 
   Frame -> True, Axes -> False], 
  Graphics[{PointSize[.003], Gray, Line@datat}]}
```

[image: 4-peak fitting result]

You will of course have to scale the fitted functions back to the original data, but this should be trivial.

Comment: there is supposed to be a lot more peaks. have a look at Logarithm of the data and Joined->True. I think silvia's code cannot handle many peaks