# Approximate strictly positive solution to a linear set of equations?

Tags: function-construction, mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra

Consider a positive matrix `M` and a positive vector `b`, e.g.

```
nn = 1000;
M  = Table[RandomReal[{0, 100}], {i, 1, nn}, {j, 1, nn}];
b  = Table[RandomReal[{0, 100}], {i, 1, nn}];
```

I would like to find a positive vector `X`

```
X  = Array[x,nn];
```

(each `x[i]>0`) such that given

```
expr = M.X-b;
```

the quantity `expr.expr` is minimized. Is it possible to do that in Mathematica efficiently (so that it finishes within a few seconds/minutes)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you could use the non-negative least-squares algorithm (NNLS) of Lawson and Hanson, discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26336/how-to-perform-a-multi-peak-fitting/26338#26338). See the links in the comments.

NNLS was ported to Mathematica by Michael Woodhams, and used here as `NNLS[M,b]`. I am running Mma 11.3.0 for 64-bit Linux.

```
nn = 1000;
SeedRandom[10];
M = Table[RandomReal[{0, 100}], {i, 1, nn}, {j, 1, nn}];
b = Table[RandomReal[{0, 100}], {i, 1, nn}];
ls = NNLS[M,b];
```

Timing was about 10 seconds for `nn=1000`.

[image: non-negative least-squares solution]

Comment: This is brilliant! Can be found here: http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2003/Oct/msg00053.html

Answer (score 9):

You can use the new in M12 function [`QuadraticOptimization`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QuadraticOptimization), which minimizes functions of the form:

$$\frac{1}{2} x . q. x + c . x$$

subject to linear constraints on $x$. So, the first step is to figure out what $q$ and $c$ are for your example. To do this we expand your `expr`, but before doing so, note that for a vector `u` and a matrix `M` we have:

$$u.M=M^T.u$$

Then, we can expand `expr` yielding:

$$(M.X-b).(M.X-b) = X.M^T.M.X-2 b.M.X+b.b$$

Hence we have:

```
q := 2 Transpose[M] . M
c := -2 b . M
```

Let's do a small example and compare to @Roman's answer. Setup:

```
nn = 10;
SeedRandom[10];
M = Table[RandomReal[{0, 100}], {i, 1, nn}, {j, 1, nn}];
b = Table[RandomReal[{0, 100}], {i, 1, nn}];
X = Array[x, nn];
expr = M . X - b;
```

Comparison:

```
r1 = X /. Last @ Minimize[{expr.expr, X > 0}, X]
r2 = QuadraticOptimization[{q, c}, {IdentityMatrix[nn], ConstantArray[0, nn]}]
```

> {0.221992, 0.188374, 0.131969, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.0849646, 0.028771}
>
> {0.221992, 0.188374, 0.131969, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.0849646, 0.028771}

where I used constraints that ensured that each vector element is nonnegative. For your larger example:

```
nn = 1000;
SeedRandom[1];
M = Table[RandomReal[{0, 100}], {i, 1, nn}, {j, 1, nn}];
b = Table[RandomReal[{0, 100}], {i, 1, nn}];

res = QuadraticOptimization[{q, c}, {IdentityMatrix[nn], ConstantArray[0, nn]}]; //AbsoluteTiming
res[[;;20]]
```

> {1.48153, Null}
>
> {0., 0., 0., 0.015694, 0., 0.00561439, 0., 0.0157487, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}

So, it finishes on the order of a couple seconds, as requested.

Comment: Wow, this is great! Unfortunately, I am on MA 11.3 right now. Any chance you could give me a hint on how to write a custom code similar to what `QuadraticOptimization` is doing?

Comment: Carl I was naïvely assuming that internally, my solution's `Minimize` would be auto-mapped onto `QuadraticOptimization` for fastest execution. Seeing that it's not so is a bit disappointing!

Comment: @Kagaratsch You could use `CloudEvaluate`, e.g., define ``qo[a__] := CloudEvaluate[System`QuadraticOptimization[a]]`` and then use `qo`. I think `FindMinimum` has an undocmented "QuadraticOptimization" method you could try instead if you don't want to or are unable to use the cloud.

Comment: @CarlWoll The cloud returns `$Failed`, but for `FindMinimum` you probably mean `FindMinimum[{expr.expr, Thread[X > 0]}, X, 
 Method -> "QuadraticProgramming"]`? This works fairly quickly for `nn=10` and `nn=100`, but for `nn=1000` it still never seems to finish...

Answer (score 2):

**THIS IS AN EXTENDED COMMENT RATHER THAN AN ANSWER.**

It is inefficient to use `Table` to generate random numbers.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

nn = 1000;

SeedRandom[10];
t1 = AbsoluteTiming[
   {M1 = Table[RandomReal[{0, 100}], {i, 1, nn}, {j, 1, nn}],
     b1 = Table[RandomReal[{0, 100}], {i, 1, nn}]};][[1]]

(* 0.202688 *)

SeedRandom[10];
t2 = AbsoluteTiming[
   {M2 = RandomReal[{0, 100}, {nn, nn}],
     b2 = RandomReal[{0, 100}, nn]};][[1]]

(* 0.005653 *)
```

The values are identical

```
{M1 === M2, b1 === b2, t1/t2}

(* {True, True, 35.8549} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Minimize[{expr.expr, Thread[X > 0]}, X]
```

Comment: This runs for a looong time and never seems to finish...

Comment: Yes it's a tough problem. Runs fine for `nn=100`.