# How to obtain all minima?

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

If you `Solve` an equation, you obtain *all* solutions.

But If you `NMinimize` a function, you only get one minimum.

The question is: is there a way to obtain all minima of a given function?

Example:

```
Solve[((x - 2) (x + 2))^2 == 0, x]
Print["____________"]
NMinimize[((x - 2) (x + 2))^2, x]
NMinimize[ {((x - 2) (x + 2))^2, x >= 0}, x]
```

yields

```
{{x -> -2}, {x -> -2}, {x -> 2}, {x -> 2}}
____________
{0., {x -> -2.}}
{0., {x -> 2.}}
```

You can see that for `Solve` you obtain all solutions, even with their multiplicity, but in the minimization, you only obtain one solution.

Comment: `NMinimize` does not perform a global optimization, and will return only one (quite possibly local) minimum. You can try `Minimze` which will return a global minimum for polynomial functions, but not other (local) ones.

Comment: related: [How to find all the local minima/maxima in a range](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5575/5478). About infinite domain, `Solve` for `f' == 0 && f'' >0`.

Comment: @Kuba: *Nice* answer in that link, thanks for posting, had not seen it before.