# How can I use the command `Minimize` of this trigonometric function?

Tags: numerics

I want to find the minimum of the function $\sin^6 x  + \cos^6 x$. I tried

```
Minimize[{Sin[x]^6 + Cos[x]^6, 0 <= x <= 2 Pi}, x]
```

I got

> {Cos[2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]]^6 + 
>         Sin[2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]]^6, {x -> -2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]}}
>       NMinimize[{Sin[x]^6 + Cos[x]^6, 0 <= x <= 2 Pi}, x]

And I tried

```
NMinimize[{Sin[x]^6 + Cos[x]^6, 0 <= x <= 2 Pi}, x]
```

I got

> {0.25, {x -> 3.92699}}

How can I use the command `minnimize`?

Comment: The minimum is the least value of your function, which `Minimize` gives you.  Otherwise, if you want all minima, this seems a duplicate of [How to find all the local minima/maxima in a range](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5575) or [How to obtain all minima?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44689)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version
```

> "10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014)"

```
f[x_] = Sin[x]^6 + Cos[x]^6;

sol = FullSimplify[Minimize[
   {f[x], 0 <= x <= 2 Pi}, x]]
```

> {1/4, {x -> (7*Pi)/4}}

However, this is just one of the four minima. To find all four:

```
pts = {x, f[x]} /. Solve[
    {f'[x] == 0, f''[x] > 0, 0 <= x <= 2 Pi}, x] //
  FullSimplify
```

> {{Pi/4, 1/4}, {(7*Pi)/4, 1/4}, {(5*Pi)/4, 1/4}, {(3*Pi)/4, 1/4}}

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6],
   Point[pts]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The problem you face here is that your function has several minima in the range you specified:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want them all, you can use `Reduce`, but for this, you need the approach you learned in school: calculate the derivative of your function and calculate where it is zero. Then use the second derivative and check whether it is >0 to indicate that you want a minimum. And now the code is straight forward:

```
f = Sin[x]^6 + Cos[x]^6;
df = D[Sin[x]^6 + Cos[x]^6, x];
ddf = D[df, x];

sol = Reduce[df == 0 && ddf > 0 && 0 <= x <= 2 Pi, x]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

To display the solutions, you can convert them to points and show everything in a single graphics:

```
points = Point[{x, f} /. #] & /@ Flatten[{ToRules[sol]}];
Show[
 Plot[f, {x, 0, 2 Pi}],
 Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.02], points}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Minimize returns a symbolic result as it is designed to do. It is working correctly.

To force the return of a numeric result you must "encourage" Minimize to do so. This makes it call NMinimize instead. A simply way is to multiply any portion by 1. to make it floating point. The decimal point is important.

```
Minimize[{1.Sin[x]^6 + Cos[x]^6, 0 <= x <= 2 \[Pi]}, x]
```