# How to find local minima of data using PeakDetect

Tags: mathematical-optimization, peak-detection

One of the great new function in v10 is `PeakDetect`.

It can detect peaks (local maxima) according to desired sharpness as shown in this example:

```
data = Table[{x, (Sin[10 x] + 2) Exp[-x^2]}, {x, -4, 4, .01}];
peaks = Pick[data, PeakDetect[data[[;; , 2]], .01, .0005], 1];
ListPlot[{data, peaks}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Directive[Red, PointSize[0.02]]}]
```

[image]

The question is how to find valleys (local minima) of the such data using this new function?

Comment: Apply it to $-f$?

Comment: @MarkMcClure Just saw your comment after I posted it. Yes, that is the first thing I though about also.

Comment: @MarkMcClure great trick. thanks to you and to Nasser.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As has been observed

[image]

```
data = Table[{x, (Sin[10 x] + 2) Exp[-x^2]}, {x, -4, 4, .01}];
peaks = Pick[data, PeakDetect[data[[;; , 2]], .01, .0005], 1];
troughs = Pick[data, PeakDetect[-data[[;; , 2]], .01, .0005], 1];
ListPlot[{data, peaks, troughs}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Directive[Red, PointSize[0.02]], 
   Directive[Green, PointSize[0.02]]}]
```

Comment: It would be nice to have a method to find local minima *and* maxima in one go. For large data, this doubles the time, somewhat unnecessarily.

Comment: @IstvánZachar  yes  you are right. I will think about . It approaches 2 years since the answer. MMa has changed, I have changed but not in a desirable direction. I would very much value a better answer than mine. If you post one "comment me" in.

Answer (score 9):

Not an answer, more of a extended comment. (Since the question requires the use of `PeakDetect`.)

Some (more than half actually) of the local extrema are missed. This becomes obvious using Log plots (modifying the code of ubpdqn):

```
data = Table[{x, (Sin[10 x] + 2) Exp[-x^2]}, {x, -4, 4, .01}];
peaks = Pick[data, PeakDetect[data[[;; , 2]], .01, .0005], 1];
troughs = Pick[data, PeakDetect[-data[[;; , 2]], .01, .0005], 1];
opts = {PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Directive[Red, PointSize[0.02]], 
     Directive[Green, PointSize[0.02]]}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
   ImageSize -> Medium};
Grid[{{ListPlot[{data, peaks, troughs}, opts], 
   ListLogPlot[{data, peaks, troughs}, opts]}}]
```

[image]

I tried few times to get better results by tweaking the `PeakDetect` parameters without success.

Using [Quantile regression fitting](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2015/09/27/finding-local-extrema-in-noisy-data-using-quantile-regression/) to find the local extrema gives better results:

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/Applications/QuantileRegressionForLocalExtrema.m"]

Block[{data = data, qfuncs, showFunc},
 {qfuncs, extrema} = QRFindExtrema[data, 40, 2, 12, {0.5}];
 showFunc[listPlotFunc_] :=
  listPlotFunc[Join[{data}, extrema], 
   PlotStyle -> {{}, {PointSize[Medium], Green}, {PointSize[Medium], 
      Red}}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotRange -> All, 
   ImageSize -> Medium];
 Grid[{{showFunc[ListPlot], showFunc[ListLogPlot]}}]
 ]
```

[image]

Here is a related discussion: ["Finding very weak peaks"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113094/finding-very-weak-peaks).

Answer (score 7):

```
data = Table[{x, -(Sin[10 x] + 2) Exp[-x^2]}, {x, -4, 4, .01}];
peaks = Pick[data, PeakDetect[data[[;; , 2]], .01, .0005], 1];
ListPlot[{data, peaks}, PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Directive[Red, PointSize[0.02]]}];
Rotate[%, 180 Degree]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or as Pickett mentioned below, just add - to data as in

```
data = Table[{x, (Sin[10 x] + 2) Exp[-x^2]}, {x, -4, 4, .01}];
peaks = Pick[data, PeakDetect[-data[[;; , 2]], .01, .0005], 1];
ListPlot[{data, peaks}, PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Directive[Red, PointSize[0.02]]}]
```

Comment: It's easier to just add `-` in front of `data[[;;,2]]`. This way you don't have to rotate the graph.

Comment: @Nasser, it would better if you ListPlot[{-data,-peaks},....]

Comment: @Pickett, sure that is better so no rotation is needed. Thanks.