# FindPeaks of elevation data

Tags: plotting, peak-detection

I've been reading many posts about how to use FindPeaks.   I am working with some GPX data and was looking to plot an elevation profile with points at the peaks and troughs, potentially with those locations shown as a text object.   I was not able to use the information to get this to work, so hoping for some help.   I've posted the .csv file here
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WjqlH-LV8333DSr9_YBsrQtn3vxZ7zjk/view?usp=sharing

FYI, these are distances and elevations between Antelope Wells New Mexico and Hachita  New Mexico.   Best case scenario would be a ListLinePlot with labelled points at the SIGNIFICANT peaks and troughs.

Any hints/advice/help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You can first smooth your data using a filter and then call "FindPeaks". Here is an example:

```
d = Import["d:/downloads/data.csv"];
da = d[[All, 2]];
da = LowpassFilter[da, 0.1];

peaks = FindPeaks[da][[All, 1]];
ListPlot[d, Epilog -> {Red, Point[d[[peaks]]]}]
```

[image]

For troughs you do the same with inverted data.

Answer (score 2):

```
peaks = Pick[data, PeakDetect[data[[All, 2]], 2, .05], 1]
trs = Pick[data, PeakDetect[-data[[All, 2]], 2, .05], 1]
ListPlot[{data, peaks, trs}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, {AbsolutePointSize[5], 
    Red}, {AbsolutePointSize[5], Darker@Green}}]
```

[image]

I have used the method presented in [54757](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54757/how-to-find-local-minima-of-data-using-peakdetect).