# find all global minima (there is more than one global minimum)

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have a function with two **global** minima, I would like mathmatica to find both of them. for example I have the function:

[image]

and I'm trying to find both global minima using:

```
FindMinimum[{-5 x^4 + 5 x^6 + x^2}, {x}]
```

this only find one minimum:

> {-0.130734, {x -> 0.737666}}

how do I find both?

**I don't care if you use Nminimize, FindMinimum, or any other function as long as you find both minima**

Comment: FindMinimum finds only one minimum.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5575/131

Comment: and Nminimize does find the global minimum, It says so in the function details: "NMinimize always attempts to find a global minimum of f subject to the constraints given."

Comment: ... it always attempts, but not necessarily manages. Do you only have polynomial functions?

Comment: @YvesKlett It's actually trigonometric functions, but I tried to simplify my question...

Answer (score 6):

```
findGlobalMin[func_, x_Symbol] := Module[
  {min = MinValue[func, x] // Simplify},
  {min, Select[
    Solve[{
       D[func, x] == 0,
       D[func, {x, 2}] > 0},
      x] // Simplify,
    (func /. #) == min &]}]

f[x_] = -5 x^4 + 5 x^6 + x^2;

findGlobalMin[f[x], x]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can do the example emulating  pen/pencil and paper,e.g.:

```
y[x_] := x^4 - x^2
c = x /. Solve[D[y[x], x] == 0, x]
r = D[y[x], {x, 2}];
ans = Pick[c, (r > 0 /. x -> #) & /@ c]
Plot[y[x], {x, -1.5, 1.5}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{#, y@#} & /@ ans]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm looking for the **global** minima. not all minima.

Comment: @AdiRo in this (special case and without a domain specified:assumed $-\infty$ to$\infty$) these are global minima. But I take your point that this may have been a MWE and not your desired response. I may leave the answer as, perhaps, others might find useful.

Comment: @ubpdqn I edited the question to make It clear