# List Manipulation- Find corresponding values

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have the next list :

```
  {{0.1, -15.3512}, {0.2, -115.194}, {0.3, -133.702}, {0.4, -140.201}, \
  {0.5, -143.232}, {0.6, -144.903}, {0.7, -145.935}, {0.8, -146.63}, \{0.9, 
  -147.132}, {1., -147.518}, {1.1, -147.828}, {1.2, -148.089}, \{1.3, 
  -148.318}, {1.4, -148.523}, {1.5, -148.716}, {1.6, -148.893}, \{1.7, 
  -149.054}, {1.8, -149.223}, {1.9, -149.379}, {2., -149.528}, \{2.1, 
  -149.671}, {2.2, -149.804}, {2.3, -149.929}, {2.4, -150.043}, \{2.5, 
  -150.143}, {2.6, -150.225}, {2.7, -150.287}, {2.8, -150.324}, \{2.9, 
  -150.329}, {3., -150.298}, {3.1, -150.224}, {3.2, -150.098}, \{3.3, 
  -149.911}, {3.4, -149.653}, {3.5, -149.315}, {3.6, -148.88}, \{3.7, 
  -148.344}, {3.8, -147.686}, {3.9, -146.889}, {4., -145.937}, \
  {4.1, -144.816}, {4.2, -143.509}, {4.3, -141.997}, {4.4, -140.263}, \{4.5, 
 -138.307}, {4.6, -136.061}, {4.7, -133.564}, {4.8, -130.786}, \{4.9, 
 -127.716}, {5., -124.349}, {5.1, -120.684}, {5.2, -116.715}, \{5.3, 
  -112.457}, {5.4, -107.914}, {5.5, -103.102}, {5.6, -98.0415}, \{5.7, 
  -92.7544}, {5.8, -87.273}, {5.9, -81.6295}, {6., -75.8572}, \{6.1, 
  -69.9991}, {6.2, -64.092}, {6.3, -58.1799}, {6.4, -52.3046}, \{6.5, 
  -46.5078}, {6.6, -40.827}, {6.7, -35.3016}, {6.8, -29.9653}, \{6.9, 
  -24.8465}, {7., -19.9717}, {7.1, -15.3617}, {7.2, -11.0341}, \{7.3, 
   -6.99813}, {7.4, -3.26171}, {7.5, 0.172043}, {7.6, 
   3.30803}, {7.7, 6.14966}, {7.8, 8.70572}, {7.9, 10.9888}, {8., 
   13.0129}, {8.1, 14.7937}, {8.2, 16.3474}, {8.3, 17.6906}, {8.4, 
   18.8424}, {8.5, 19.8199}, {8.6, 20.6402}, {8.7, 21.3201}, {8.8, 
   21.8738}, {8.9, 22.317}, {9., 22.664}, {9.1, 22.926}, {9.2, 
   23.1148}, {9.3, 23.2406}, {9.4, 23.3121}, {9.5, 23.3539}, {9.6, 
   23.3247}, {9.7, 23.2789}, {9.8, 23.2081}, {9.9, 23.1102}, {10., 
   22.9953}, {10.1, 22.866}, {10.2, 22.7242}, {10.3, 22.5727}, {10.4, 
   22.4149}, {10.5, 22.2485}, {10.6, 22.0785}, {10.7, 21.9067}, {10.8, 
   21.7264}, {10.9, 21.5564}, {11., 21.3797}, {11.1, 21.2037}, {11.2, 
   21.0281}, {11.3, 20.8535}, {11.4, 20.6802}, {11.5, 20.5083}, {11.6, 
   20.3377}, {11.7, 20.1697}, {11.8, 20.0034}, {11.9, 19.8403}, {12., 
   19.6767}, {12.1, 19.5166}, {12.2, 19.3587}, {12.3, 19.2031}, {12.4, 
   19.0497}, {12.5, 18.8984}, {12.6, 18.7495}, {12.7, 18.6027}, {12.8, 
   18.4579}, {12.9, 18.3154}, {13., 18.1752}, {13.1, 18.0366}, {13.2, 
   17.9005}, {13.3, 17.7661}, {13.4, 17.6336}, {13.5, 17.5031}, {13.6, 
   17.3746}, {13.7, 17.2478}, {13.8, 17.1229}, {13.9, 16.9998}, {14., 
   16.8767}, {14.1, 16.7583}, {14.2, 16.6403}, {14.3, 16.524}, {14.4, 
   16.4095}, {14.5, 16.2964}, {14.6, 16.1848}, {14.7, 16.0747}, {14.8, 
   15.966}, {14.9, 15.8598}, {15., 15.7531}, {15.1, 15.6488}, {15.2, 
   15.5469}, {15.3, 15.444}, {15.4, 15.3437}, {15.5, 15.2446}, {15.6, 
   15.147}, {15.7, 15.0505}, {15.8, 14.9559}, {15.9, 14.8611}, {16., 
   14.7681}, {16.1, 14.6765}, {16.2, 14.5858}, {16.3, 14.4975}, {16.4, 
   14.4087}, {16.5, 14.3205}, {16.6, 14.2342}, {16.7, 14.149}, {16.8, 
   14.0647}, {16.9, 13.9818}, {17., 13.8992}, {17.1, 13.818}, {17.2, 
   13.7375}, {17.3, 13.6581}, {17.4, 13.5793}, {17.5, 13.5035}, {17.6, 
   13.4251}, {17.7, 13.3493}, {17.8, 13.2737}, {17.9, 13.2001}, {18., 
   13.1268}, {18.1, 13.0542}, {18.2, 12.9826}, {18.3, 12.9122}, {18.4, 
   12.8414}, {18.5, 12.7719}, {18.6, 12.7034}, {18.7, 12.6354}, {18.8, 
   12.5681}, {18.9, 12.5015}, {19., 12.4358}, {19.1, 12.3707}, {19.2, 
   12.306}, {19.3, 12.2422}, {19.4, 12.1791}, {19.5, 12.1167}, {19.6, 
   12.0548}, {19.7, 11.9935}, {19.8, 11.9326}, {19.9, 11.873}, {20., 
   11.8137}}
```

Which in turn can be plot, and I obtained this:

[image: total potential]

where y-coordinate is energy, and x-axis is distance. I have to find a value of distance for a given value of energy, and,  as can be seen , for a given energy there can be several distances. For instance , I use an energy of y=18, which has, in fact, three corresponding distances, but I only can find one. I use interpolation first in the table and then use Solve but , I just obtained one value that is irrelevant for other calculations:

```
  itb = Interpolation[tbff];
  Solve[itb[z]==z]

  {*z=0.0854959*}
```

Can anybody help me ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
FindMinimum[(itb[z] - z)^2, {z, 5}]
```

> {5.41175*10^-22, {z -> 7.76178}}

```
FindMinimum[(itb[z] - z)^2, {z, 15}]
```

> {3.95819*10^-26, {z -> 15.3718}}

Helpful to plot function-arg i.e.

`Plot[itb[z] - z, {z, 0, 18}]` yielding

[image]

---

**Update**: Realized upon rereading that you may be asking
 for the solution to  the interesting problem of trying to find all
the values that match *something* within your data range, not
just spot finding where $f(z)===z$.

There's actually a nice strategy we can borrow from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5591/51526)

```
findSomeVals[f_, min_, max_] := 
  Reap[soln = 
     y[x] /. First[
       NDSolve[{y'[x] == Evaluate[D[f[x], x]], y[min] == (f[min])}, 
        y[x], {x, min, max}, 
        Method -> {"EventLocator", "Event" -> y'[x], 
          "EventAction" :> Sow[{x, y[x]}]}]]][[2, 1]];

findLocsForValZ[xx_, 
  interpFunc_] := (z /. Flatten[#[[2]]]) & /@ 
   Select[ FindMinimum[(interpFunc[z] - xx)^2 && 
        z >= interpFunc[[1, 1, 1]] && 
        z <= interpFunc[[1, 1, 2]], {z, #[[1]]}] & /@ 
     findSomeVals[(interpFunc[#] - xx /. z -> #)^2 &, 
      interpFunc[[1, 1, 1]], interpFunc[[1, 1, 2]]], 
    Abs[#[[1]]] < 10^-4 &] // 
  Union[#, SameTest -> (0 === Chop[#1 - #2, 10^-6] &)] &
```

Usage:

```
findLocsForValZ[z,itb]  (* to find z where f[z]===z *)
```

> {7.76178, 15.3718}

```
findLocsForValZ[14,itb] (* to find z where f[z]===14 *)
```

> {8.05379, 16.878}

```
findLocsForValZ[23.2,itb] (* to find z where f[z]===23.2 *)
```

> {9.26228, 9.80928}

Is that suspicious? Ie. to find such close args to get itb[z]==23.2?
Let's take a look:

```
Plot[itb[z] - 23.2, {z, itb[[1, 1, 1]], itb[[1, 1, 2]]}, 
 PlotPoints -> 400, PlotRange -> {-1/2, 1/2}]
```

yields:

[image: sharpChange]

Indeed, finding these values `{9.26228, 9.80928}` where f[z] was equiv to 23.2 was interpolated from the following progression within the original data:

> { ... , {9.2, 23.1148}, {9.3, 23.2406}, {9.4, 23.3121}, {9.5, 23.3539}, {9.6,
>      23.3247}, {9.7, 23.2789}, {9.8, 23.2081}, {9.9, 23.1102}, ...}

### ----

Fun example:

```
itpSin = Interpolation[Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, -6.5 \[Pi], 6.5 \[Pi], 1/10}]];
findLocsForValZ[0, itpSin]/\[Pi] // Chop[#, 10^-6] & // Rationalize
```

> {-6., -5., -4., -3., -2., -1., 0, 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.}

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will try to analize your code because I have to use it later for another calculation :D

Answer (score 2):

Let us denote the energy `e`. Try this:

```
dist[e_] := 
 Map[Part[tbff, #][[1]] &, (Position[tbff, #] & /@ 
     Nearest[Transpose[tbff][[2]], e, 2] /. {{x_, 2}} -> x)]
```

It gives you the list of x coordinates of the points most close to to the energy `e`.  Then, say,

```
dist[18.3]

(* {12.9, 13.}  *)
```

and

```
dist[-71]

(*  {6.1, 6.}  *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

If the underlying function got sampled sufficiently fine, so that each interval between x-values contains at most one y-root, one can use

```
data = Developer`ToPackedArray@{{0.1, -15.3512}, {0.2, -115.194}, {0.3, -133.702}, {0.4, -140.201}, {0.5, -143.232}, {0.6, -144.903}, {0.7, -145.935}, {0.8, -146.63}, {0.9, -147.132}, {1., -147.518}, {1.1, -147.828}, {1.2, -148.089}, {1.3, -148.318}, {1.4, -148.523}, {1.5, -148.716}, {1.6, -148.893}, {1.7, -149.054}, {1.8, -149.223}, {1.9, -149.379}, {2., -149.528}, {2.1, -149.671}, {2.2, -149.804}, {2.3, -149.929}, {2.4, -150.043}, {2.5, -150.143}, {2.6, -150.225}, {2.7, -150.287}, {2.8, -150.324}, {2.9, -150.329}, {3., -150.298}, {3.1, -150.224}, {3.2, -150.098}, {3.3, -149.911}, {3.4, -149.653}, {3.5, -149.315}, {3.6, -148.88}, {3.7, -148.344}, {3.8, -147.686}, {3.9, -146.889}, {4., -145.937}, {4.1, -144.816}, {4.2, -143.509}, {4.3, -141.997}, {4.4, -140.263}, {4.5, -138.307}, {4.6, -136.061}, {4.7, -133.564}, {4.8, -130.786}, {4.9, -127.716}, {5., -124.349}, {5.1, -120.684}, {5.2, -116.715}, {5.3, -112.457}, {5.4, -107.914}, {5.5, -103.102}, {5.6, -98.0415}, {5.7, -92.7544}, {5.8, -87.273}, {5.9, -81.6295}, {6., -75.8572}, {6.1, -69.9991}, {6.2, -64.092}, {6.3, -58.1799}, {6.4, -52.3046}, {6.5, -46.5078}, {6.6, -40.827}, {6.7, -35.3016}, {6.8, -29.9653}, {6.9, -24.8465}, {7., -19.9717}, {7.1, -15.3617}, {7.2, -11.0341}, {7.3, -6.99813}, {7.4, -3.26171}, {7.5, 0.172043}, {7.6, 3.30803}, {7.7, 6.14966}, {7.8, 8.70572}, {7.9, 10.9888}, {8., 13.0129}, {8.1, 14.7937}, {8.2, 16.3474}, {8.3, 17.6906}, {8.4, 18.8424}, {8.5, 19.8199}, {8.6, 20.6402}, {8.7, 21.3201}, {8.8, 21.8738}, {8.9, 22.317}, {9., 22.664}, {9.1, 22.926}, {9.2, 23.1148}, {9.3, 23.2406}, {9.4, 23.3121}, {9.5, 23.3539}, {9.6, 23.3247}, {9.7, 23.2789}, {9.8, 23.2081}, {9.9, 23.1102}, {10., 22.9953}, {10.1, 22.866}, {10.2, 22.7242}, {10.3, 22.5727}, {10.4, 22.4149}, {10.5, 22.2485}, {10.6, 22.0785}, {10.7, 21.9067}, {10.8, 21.7264}, {10.9, 21.5564}, {11., 21.3797}, {11.1, 21.2037}, {11.2, 21.0281}, {11.3, 20.8535}, {11.4, 20.6802}, {11.5, 20.5083}, {11.6, 20.3377}, {11.7, 20.1697}, {11.8, 20.0034}, {11.9, 19.8403}, {12., 19.6767}, {12.1, 19.5166}, {12.2, 19.3587}, {12.3, 19.2031}, {12.4, 19.0497}, {12.5, 18.8984}, {12.6, 18.7495}, {12.7, 18.6027}, {12.8, 18.4579}, {12.9, 18.3154}, {13., 18.1752}, {13.1, 18.0366}, {13.2, 17.9005}, {13.3, 17.7661}, {13.4, 17.6336}, {13.5, 17.5031}, {13.6, 17.3746}, {13.7, 17.2478}, {13.8, 17.1229}, {13.9, 16.9998}, {14., 16.8767}, {14.1, 16.7583}, {14.2, 16.6403}, {14.3, 16.524}, {14.4, 16.4095}, {14.5, 16.2964}, {14.6, 16.1848}, {14.7, 16.0747}, {14.8, 15.966}, {14.9, 15.8598}, {15., 15.7531}, {15.1, 15.6488}, {15.2, 15.5469}, {15.3, 15.444}, {15.4, 15.3437}, {15.5, 15.2446}, {15.6, 15.147}, {15.7, 15.0505}, {15.8, 14.9559}, {15.9, 14.8611}, {16., 14.7681}, {16.1, 14.6765}, {16.2, 14.5858}, {16.3, 14.4975}, {16.4, 14.4087}, {16.5, 14.3205}, {16.6, 14.2342}, {16.7, 14.149}, {16.8, 14.0647}, {16.9, 13.9818}, {17., 13.8992}, {17.1, 13.818}, {17.2, 13.7375}, {17.3, 13.6581}, {17.4, 13.5793}, {17.5, 13.5035}, {17.6, 13.4251}, {17.7, 13.3493}, {17.8, 13.2737}, {17.9, 13.2001}, {18., 13.1268}, {18.1, 13.0542}, {18.2, 12.9826}, {18.3, 12.9122}, {18.4, 12.8414}, {18.5, 12.7719}, {18.6, 12.7034}, {18.7, 12.6354}, {18.8, 12.5681}, {18.9, 12.5015}, {19., 12.4358}, {19.1, 12.3707}, {19.2, 12.306}, {19.3, 12.2422}, {19.4, 12.1791}, {19.5, 12.1167}, {19.6, 12.0548}, {19.7, 11.9935}, {19.8, 11.9326}, {19.9, 11.873}, {20., 11.8137}};

itb = Interpolation[data];
pos = Join[Flatten[Position[Abs[Differences[Sign[data[[All,2]] - y]]], 2]], {1, -1}];
y = 18.;
roots = DeleteDuplicates[Table[t /. FindRoot[itb[t] == y, {t, data[[p, 1]]}], {p, pos}]]

(* {8.32535, 13.1267, 0.0812768} *)
```

Note that this throws several errors as you extrapolated from a `InterpolationFunction`, something that is quite questionable...