# Find the maximum value of a numerical solution

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization

I have a numerical solution and I want to find the maximum value of the solution.

```
a = Rationalize[0.33390683175743086];
b = -0.15;
d = 5;
a1 = 
  u[y_] := 
    (Tanh[a*(y - d)] + Tanh[a*d])/(1 + Tanh[a*d]) + 
      b*Sqrt[3]*y/d*Exp[-1.5*(y/d)^2 + 0.5];
α = 0.04;
ω = Rationalize[0.0060230765816024628] + Rationalize[0.0097304407482613764]*I;
sol = 
  NDSolve[
    {(u[y] - ω/α)*(ϕ''[y] - α^2*ϕ[y]) - u''[y]*ϕ[y] == 0, 
     ϕ[80] == 1, ϕ'[80] == -I*α}, ϕ, {y, 0, 80}][[1, 1, 2]]
ϕ[y_] := sol[y]
```

So `ϕ` is the solution of my problem. I difined a new function called `uu` which is the negative of the derivative of `ϕ`:

```
uu[y_] := -ϕ'[y];
```

When I plot `Abs[uu[y]]` I have this:

[image]

Now the question is how to determine the maximum value of `|uu|`?
Looking the figure it seems that the value is around for `|uu| = 2.6`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use arbitrary precision rather than machine precision in [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html) by setting the [`WorkingPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html). This then requires that all numeric values have at least that precision. Consequently, [`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) or set to exact numbers all of your constants. To `Rationalize` long decimals you need to use a smaller tolerance. `0` will always work.

```
a = Rationalize[0.33390683175743086, 0];
b = -3/20;
d = 5;
a1 = u[y_] := (Tanh[a*(y - d)] + Tanh[a*d])/(1 + Tanh[a*d]) + 
    b*Sqrt[3]*y/d*Exp[-3/2*(y/d)^2 + 1/2];
α = 1/25;
ω = Rationalize[0.0060230765816024628 + 0.0097304407482613764*I, 0];

Clear[ϕ];

sol = NDSolve[{(u[y] - ω/α)*(ϕ''[
           y] - α^2*ϕ[y]) - u''[y]*ϕ[y] == 0, ϕ[80] == 
      1, ϕ'[80] == -I*α}, ϕ, {y, 0, 80}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 15][[1, 1, 2]];

ϕ[y_] := sol[y]

uu[y_] := -ϕ'[y]

Plot[Abs[uu[y]], {y, 0, 80}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
Maximize[{Abs[uu[y]], 0 < y < 80}, y]

(* {2.63046649575507, {y -> 5.00764789850856}} *)
```

**EDIT:** Alternatively, rather than setting the `WorkingPrecision` in `NDSolve`; instead of using `Maximize` use [`NMaximize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMaximize.html) and set its `WorkingPrecision`.

```
NMaximize[{Abs[uu[y]], 0 < y < 80}, y, WorkingPrecision -> 15]

(* {2.63046694880644, {y -> 5.00764953131638}} *)
```

There is a slight difference in the result.

Also note that just setting the `WorkingPrecision` in `Maximize` does not work.

Comment: Thanks @BobHanlon. Solved. If you could explain me: Why I need to use arbitrary precision rather than machine precision in `NDSolve`?

Comment: Remove the option for `WorkingPrecision` and reevaluate; you will get an error message: "NMaximize::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations." Such problems are frequently due to loss of precision using machine precision. Arbitrary precision tracks and controls precision during calculations. The trade-off is that arbitrary precision is slower. Consequently, it is often only used if necessary.

Answer (score 5):

Another answer copied from [Daniel Lichtblau's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5591/18767). I updated it to use `WhenEvent` instead of `EventLocator`. The idea is to integrate the derivative of the function and use `WhenEvent` to detect extrema.

```
f[y_?NumericQ] = Abs[uu[y]]
vals = Reap[
    soln = y[x] /. First[
      NDSolve[{
        y'[x] == Evaluate[f'[x]],
        y[10] == (f[10]), 
        WhenEvent[y'[x] == 0, Sow[{x, y[x]}]]}, y[x], {x, .5, 30}]]][[2, 1]]
```

Then plot the function with the points stored in `vals`:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 30}, Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Red, Point[vals]}]
```

[image]

It then suffices to select the point of `vals` with the largest second value (`Last[SortBy[vals, Last]]`).

Answer (score 3):

One can extract the interpolated values from the InterpolatingFunction object, so here is another possibility. I've rewritten your ODE slightly:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[
    {(u[y] - ω/α)*(ϕ''[y] - α^2*ϕ[y]) - u''[y]*ϕ[y] == 0, ϕ[80] == 1, ϕ'[80] == -I*α},
    ϕ,
    {y, 0, 80}
];
sol //OutputForm
```

> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 80.}}, <>]

Then, the approximate maximum can be found from:

```
Max @ Abs @ (sol')["ValuesOnGrid"]
```

> 2.63037

This value will be slightly lower than the real maximum because the maximum probably occurs between grid points.

Comment: That could be well combined with Henrik's answer :)

Comment: One could also consider using `PeakDetect[]` on the results of `"Grid"` and `"ValuesOnGrid"`.

Answer (score 2):

```
vv[y_] := ϕ'[y] Conjugate[ϕ'[y]];
min = FindMaximum[{vv[t], 0. <= t <= 80}, {t, 2.6}]
Sqrt[min[[1]]]
```

> {6.91936, {t -> 5.00765}}
>
> 2.63047

Comment: But in this case I have to give an aproximation for "t" and the function `FindMaximum` gives then a local maximum.
Is there a way to catch the global maximum without give an aproximation for 't'?