# How do I separate all local maxima and local minima of my function?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting

[This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5575/8822) (and the [first answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5591/8822) in particular), teaches us how to find all the local maxima and minima of a function.

My question is: how can I separate the maxima from the minima? My goal is to find the curve that fits all the local maxima

Using the code from the cited answer:

```
GetRLine3[MMStdata_, IO_: 1][x_: x] := 
  ListInterpolation[#, InterpolationOrder -> IO, Method -> "Spline"][
     x] & /@ (({{#[[1]]}, #[[2]]}) & /@ # & /@ MMStdata);
data = Transpose[{# + RandomReal[]*0.1 & /@ Range[-10, 30, 0.4], 
    Tanh[#] + (Sech[2 x - 0.5]/1.5 + 1.5) /. x -> # & /@ 
     Range[-4, 4, 0.08]}];

xLimits = {Min@#1, Max@#1} & @@ Transpose[data];
f = First[100*D[GetRLine3[{data}, 3][x], x]];

vals = Reap[
    soln = y[x] /. 
      First[NDSolve[{y'[x] == Evaluate[D[f, x]], 
         y[-9.9] == (f /. x -> -9.9)}, y[x], {x, -9.9, 30}, 
        Method -> {"EventLocator", "Event" -> y'[x], 
          "EventAction" :> Sow[{x, y[x]}]}]]][[2, 1]];
```

I tried to modify it using `WhenEvent`, instead:

```
vals = Reap[
    soln = y[x] /. 
      First[NDSolve[y'[x] == Evaluate[D[f, x]], y[-9.9] == (f /. x -> -9.9),
         WhenEvent[y'[x] == 0 && y''[x] <= 0, Sow[{x, y[x]}], 
         y[x], {x, -9.9,30}]]]][[2, 1]];
```

I used it because I need the maxima, therefore the point with a negative second derivative, but I only get a long sequence of errors.

Comment: Is it better now @MarcoB?

Comment: Much better. Thank you! I reverted my downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event `y'[x] < 0` is what you want to look for, since at a maximum the slope goes from positive to negative. So, correcting some syntax errors and using the suggested event gives:

```
max = Reap[
    NDSolve[
        {
        y'[x] == D[f,x],
        y[-9.9]==(f/.x->-9.9),
        WhenEvent[y'[x]<0,Sow[{x,y[x]}]]
        },
        y[x],
        {x,-9.9,30}
    ]
][[2, 1]]
```

> {{-8.86017, 0.0621429}, {-8.0376, 0.0738668}, {-7.24695, 0.118799}, {-6.565, 
>     0.17745}, {-5.67063, 0.256033}, {-4.82042, 0.285138}, {-4.01709, 
>     0.417515}, {-3.25848, 0.57663}, {-1.67717, 1.14838}, {-0.473554, 
>     1.90089}, {0.255471, 2.30037}, {1.12508, 3.47191}, {2.27665, 
>     5.53463}, {3.20095, 7.50788}, {4.65821, 13.0315}, {5.47844, 
>     14.8531}, {6.28744, 20.8996}, {7.20715, 28.8187}, {8.27185, 
>     37.4885}, {9.29902, 31.5518}, {10.2004, 33.2045}, {11.0185, 
>     25.9951}, {14.0835, -1.66968}, {15.39, -1.58448}, {16.4007, -1.11386}, {18.3452, -0.35453}, {19.1145, -0.297394}, {19.9694, -0.13902}, {21.1993, 
>   -0.116217}, {22.026, -0.0657477}, {23.8522, -0.0300916}, {25.6248, 
>   -0.0160541}, {26.6953, -0.0104677}, {27.5689, -0.00694611}, {29.1361, 
>   -0.00292188}}

Visualization:

```
Plot[f, {x, -9.9, 30}, Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[max]}]
```

[image]