# How to find all local maxima in a given domain?

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization

I wish to locate all local maxima of the function $$f(x,y)=1 + Sinc[8*(x - 1)]*Sinc[10*(y - 1)]$$ on the domain $$\{(x,y):0\leq x\leq 2,0\leq y\leq 2\}.$$
The code only shows one of them:

```
FindMaximum[{1 + Sinc[8*(x - 1)]*Sinc[10*(y - 1)], 
  0 <= x <= 2.2 && 0 <= y <= 2.2}, {x, y}]
```

The following is [my dream](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5575/how-to-find-all-the-local-minima-maxima-in-a-range) (but only for one variable function) in which the locations are also marked.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

Try `NSolve` to find all of the extrema:

```
gln = D[1 + Sinc[8*(x - 1)]*Sinc[10*(y - 1)], {{x, y}}];
gln = Map[# == 0 &, gln {(x - 1)^2, (y - 1)^2} // Simplify] (* equation without singularity x=y=1*)
```

`NSolve` is able to solve these equations in the given range `0<x,y<2`

```
extrema =NSolve[{gln, 0 <= x <= 2 && 0 <= y <= 2} // Flatten, {x, y}] //Normal;
extrema = Select[extrema, Length[#] == 2 &] (* only solution points {x,y}*)

Show[{Plot3D[1 + Sinc[8*(x - 1)]*Sinc[10*(y - 1)], {x, 0, 2.2}, {y, 0, 2.2},PlotStyle-> Opacity[.25], PlotRange -> All,MeshFunctions -> (#3 &), Mesh -> 50]
, Graphics3D[{Red,Point[{x, y, 1 + Sinc[8*(x - 1)]*Sinc[10*(y - 1)]} /. extrema]}]}]
```

[image]

Looking at the second derivatives filters out the maxima…

Comment: Looking at the second derivatives filters out the maxima…and so **what are your conclusions?**

Comment: @Artes My answer shows a way to find all extrema in the given range, not more!

Comment: You have to find local maxima, not extrema or critical points.